# what does the term OP stand for?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Stack Overflow Glossary - Dictionary of Commonly-Used Terms](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40353/stack-overflow-glossary-dictionary-of-commonly-used-terms)

........(no body) ..........