# What does OP mean?

Tags: discussion, original-poster

On Stack Exchange sites, I keep seeing answerers use "OP" to refer to the person who asked a question. I can't seem to find any enlightenment online as to what it means.

Comment: duplicate of: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69894/what-does-the-term-op-stand-for http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40353/stack-exchange-glossary-dictionary-of-commonly-used-terms

Comment: FYI, google is good at classifying acronyms (eg, using the exact title of this question [what does OP mean](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=what+does+OP+mean&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=ip2vVdWrBsnzUI3ZhLgJ))

Answer (score 171, accepted):

The characters "OP" stand for "Original Poster", the person originally asking the question.

Comment: Also, somewhat less commonly, OP refers to the post itself; "Original Post".

Comment: @AndrewBarber Ha, have a look at my revision history. I took it out because I could not find a reliable reference for it, so I assumed it might just have been me. :)

Comment: ahh! hehe... nope, not just you!

Comment: For newcomers (like me), it's a little disconcerting to be referred to as an acronym you don't understand.

Comment: I thought it was originated from mIRC /op  :)

Comment: thank you, I was feeling ashamed to ask that in other stack...

Comment: Until today I really didn't know what actually OP stands for but I used it (for person asking question) many times to keep the discussion going and some how I encountered this post. Thanks.

Comment: What is the non-Original Poster then? I would understand `"QP" for question poster` because the other posts are comments and answers, but from my point of view, OP is more confusing then helping.