# Can't see answers which I've received in my inbox. 

Tags: support, deleted-answers

I have asked a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12580538/google-style-page-loading-bulk-records-not-on-onload-display-some-and-fetch-r) and someone answered. Within a couple of minutes it vanished and I'm not able to see it. But the inbox does show two answers for the question.

[image]

When I click on it, no answers are shown. Have they been deleted? What might have happened?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That answer is deleted by the OP(of answer) or moderators before you see the answer. Only [10K+ users](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/moderator-tools) can see deleted answers. So you can not see that answer until you reach 10K reputation.

Comment: what is the OP?

Comment: @Mr.Chowdary http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146513/what-does-op-mean

Comment: Original Poster. (Here I am talking about OP of answer)

Comment: @hims056 Stupid question, but how do you know it was a self-deletion? You don't seem to have 10k?

Comment: @Bart As OP said *In a couple of minutes it got vanished*. So mostly it should be self-deleted if it is deleted withing a couple of minutes.

Comment: It could have been flagged or otherwise noticed by a mod, or in a popular tag it could have been quickly down-voted and deleted by peers (but less likely), so it is not absolutely the case that a quick deletion means self-deletion. But I have 10k and I can confirm this answer was self-deleted.