# Edited a question and reputation was not increased

Tags: support, reputation, edits, suggested-edits

Recently I had edited a question of following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15221242/off-hook-state-is-never-invoked-for-outgoing-and-incoming-calls).

I edited a question in that link as it was not formatted correctly. So I formatted text in the link and added comment as **formatting text**.

But after some time my reputation was not increased so I check that question again if my edit was accepted or not and yes my edit was accepted but repo was not increased.

My question:- Is there any possibilities that your reputation will not increased for editing because of the person who asked question, edited again the same question in the same way you edited? Or there is any more possibilities?

Comment: yes but not before me

Comment: That is the point.

Comment: Where did you get the impression your edition was accepted? Note that that edit was credited to the OP.

Comment: One side note about your edits: Please don't use code formatting just to highlight random things. It should only be used for actual code; not names or simple key words.

Comment: @DavidRobinson I cannot find any where that my edition was accepted but the edition that I made was as same as the edit right now

Comment: @AndrewBarber So what would you suggest for that kind of editing + formatting text in the asked question

Comment: In [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1631117) you highlighted 'cursor'. That didn't need to be highlighted at all, and it isn't code, so it shouldn't be in code format, anyway. In [this edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1608289) you did it all over the place; none of those should have been done; that edit was properly rejected as a result. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1578501) you did the same to 'activity'. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1608289), spinner. Etc...

Comment: Looks like the suggestion was rejected: http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1649671

Comment: @ToonKrijthe: a bit late to the analysis, are we? :-P

Comment: I got it so what is a proper way to edit a question? I am little bit confused

Comment: Make significant, valuable improvements. Highlighting words generally is *not* useful. Instead, do things like the code formatting (where you properly indent code, for example); that is useful.

Comment: OK thanks for your suggestion I'll keep in mind form now before editing

Comment: one more question recently I flagged an answer as an not an original answer so it was also not accepted, I do not have link to that answer. Could you explain me why is that so??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The OP [edited the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/15221242/revisions) instead, and as a result [your suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1649671) was automatically rejected.

Edits that do not go into the review queue (by the original owner, or by people with 2k+ reputation) always trump a suggested edit. The owner must have been in the middle of editing the question still when you submitted your suggestion, so the OP was never informed of your edit either.

Comment: what do you mean by OP? sir

Comment: @AbhinavSinghMaurya [What does OP mean](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146513/what-does-op-mean).

Comment: "Original Poster", the author of the post.

Comment: thanks @Bart I got it

Comment: Thanks @MartijnPieters for your answer I think that happened there