# Is it stupid to refer to yourself as the OP if you're answering your own question?

Tags: discussion, answers, self-answer

I wrote a Q&A wiki and refered to myself as the OP, rather than "I" or "my". I did it for clarity. But, I'm wondering if it's unnecessary and makes the format feel unnatural. Opinions?

The (possibly) offensive post is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20731169/can-you-call-a-function-that-has-not-been-previously-declared).

Comment: Assuming that I even noticed the answer and question were by the same person I would find this quite jarring and possibly disingenuous. Do you have a link so we can see it in context? Why do you need to refer to the person at all rather than just "the question"?

Comment: OP is "original **poster**", not "original post" so it's not stupid, it's just wrong to refer to the question itself as "OP". Bottom line, "OP" means "the user who originally wrote the post" (can be either question or answer)

Comment: @MartinSmith [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20731169/can-you-call-a-function-that-has-not-been-previously-declared).

Comment: Personally I'd avoid using abbreviations at all outside of tbe comments

Comment: @ShadowWizard - I've frequently seen it used to mean either. In this case though simply replacing "to answer the OP's question" with "to answer the question" would be better IMO. It is completely redundant. Every question is posted by its OP.

Comment: @ShadowWizard See this [post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146513/what-does-op-mean). Look under the answer for The Festivus Unicorn's comment. He uses OP as the original post.

Comment: When in doubt, see the [glossary](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40353/stack-exchange-glossary-dictionary-of-commonly-used-terms).

Comment: Still wrong in my opinion. Anyway, fixed the answer to match what I consider proper grammar. :)

Comment: @Martin Smith, Thanks. I can see how it may be redundant to use "OP.

Comment: Honestly I think we should all just stick to our Q&A conventions and use "asker" instead of "OP". I feel dirty every time I use "OP" to refer to a question asker here.

Comment: @BoltClock's a Unicorn are these time-honed convnetions, or is there a common post that outlines the most commonly used ones?

Answer (score 5):

Target the reader, the question or the code rather than the 'original poster'. A good example is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/1348195). The original poster should be irrelevant to the question itself in most of the cases anyway.

That said - if you're answering your own question and need to refer to the question author - it's better to refer to yourself as OP, you, asker or another term indicating the person who asked the question.

This is for clarity. The Q&A format works really well here. The person reading the answer should optimally not be aware of of the fact it's the same person answering the question. So in short - no, it's not stupid.