# Saving my question on Meta brings a "Discard unsaved changes" popup

Tags: bug, meta, asking-questions

I just posted [a question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/363763/should-i-say-you-to-myself-in-self-answers) on meta.

I reformulated the question a couple of times, scrolled through the list of "Similar questions" and switched browsers tabs a lot. I hit "Review your question" and later reformulated my Title again.

When clicking on "Post Your question" a spinning icon appeared on that button and at the same time a browser popup popped up, asking me if I want to discard my changes. When I clicked on 'Cancel" there, meta allowed me to save my question again - which failed because the question already existed ("A question with that title already exists; please be more specific.").

This was confusing and probably should not have happened.

I am using Google Chrome 'Version 89.0.4389.90 (Offizieller Build) (64-Bit)' under Windows in an enterprise setup (behind a restrictive proxy, etc.).

Comment: Try to disable all your extensions and userscripts. I've been experiencing the same problem with recent posts, so I decided to [test this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/363411/348196) (10k+ only) in a "clean session" and I did _not_ get the popup. I'm not sure yet which extension/userscript is causing this though.

Comment: I have Google Docs Plugins and Selenium IDE installed.

Comment: Any userscripts?

Comment: I do not use any userscripts.

Comment: I suspect its a chrome/browser side thing - and dosen't actually affect SE's autosave functionality. The styling is the generic one my browser (vivaldi) uses rather than the usual SE design language