# A Pronominal Proposal

Tags: discussion, faq-proposed, meta-faq, code-of-conduct

The recent [Code of Conduct change](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/10/10/iterating-on-inclusion/) and, more specifically, the associated [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334900/official-faq-on-gender-pronouns-and-code-of-conduct-changes) (now deleted; Wayback Machine copy [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20191023013715/https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334900/official-faq-on-gender-pronouns-and-code-of-conduct-changes)) have [not](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/335068/bye-stack-exchange-im-done-coerced-speech-is-incompatible-with-freedom) [gone down](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/335074/why-are-the-code-of-conduct-changes-received-so-negatively-and-what-can-could) [well](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/335158/why-taking-responsibility-for-other-peoples-feelings-doesnt-work). (For the avoidance of doubt, linking to those does not constitute endorsement.)

So of course I wonder whether *any* policies on this contentious issue would be more broadly acceptable to the community while still addressing the issues the revised CoC and the FAQ were intended to address. (If not, then perhaps SE management have done the best they can and the problem is just that people like to yell at one another about contentious things.)

My guess is that this *is* possible, and this is an attempt to test that guess by making a very concrete proposal and seeing what the reaction is. Perhaps it will get downvoted to oblivion and I will have learned a valuable lesson.

I would be glad to receive any constructive feedback, especially from some particular
groups of people:

- Trans people, especially non-binary people: if this were the policy, and if it were consistently and correctly applied, would you feel safe here?
- People concerned by the "compelled speech" aspects of the CoC and its associated FAQ: is this sufficiently non-constraining?
- Moderators: does this seem like something you could apply in good conscience?

And, if it turns out that this meets with general approval:

- Representatives of Stack Exchange: does this (or perhaps some version of it modified to tone down the informality of its language a bit) do what you needed the CoC and FAQ to do, and, if not, how does it fail?

The central principle I have tried to apply is that *all of this is a practical outworking of the already-existing, fully general requirement to Be Nice*. More broadly, I have tried to find principles that apply universally and apply them here.

**What are we trying to achieve?**

I take it that Stack Exchange Inc. wants (at least) the following things:

- To have a welcoming environment where no one feels as if they're fair game for rude and marginalizing language.
- Not to do things that result in a large fraction of the community, or of particular parts of the community (e.g., moderators), feeling alienated.

I take it that trans people, and others who may use less-common pronouns, want (at least) the following things:

- To be treated with the same respect as everyone else gets.
- To have their often particularly difficult circumstances understood sympathetically.

I take it that most participants here want (at least) the following things:

- To be allowed to say what they want to, so far as that's consistent with the overall goals of the place. (Which include making Stack Exchange sites friendly and welcoming places.)
- To have Stack Exchange sites function effectively for their core function of Q&A.

I think the proposals here achieve all of those things.

Cynically minded people have attributed a number of other, less respectable-sounding, goals to various groups of participants here. I have largely ignored these.

---

**Proposed CoC language**

Actually, I think the CoC itself is fine as is; it's the elaboration in the FAQ to which some people object. The relevant bits of the CoC are these:

> **Be inclusive and respectful** [...] Prefer gender-neutral language when uncertain.

and

> **No bigotry** [...] Use stated pronouns (where known).

Some readers might object that there are reasons other than bigotry for objecting to someone's pronouns, and that this looks too much like a requirement not to avoid the pronoun issue entirely by wording things so as not to need pronouns; both of these concerns are addressed in the FAQs below.

**Proposed FAQs**

> **Q1**. What's this business about "stated pronouns"?
>   **A**. It's rude to refer to a man as "she" or a woman as "he". Some people don't consider themselves either male or female and might, for instance, ask to be referred to as "they". We're asking that when someone indicates what pronouns should be used to refer to them, you do as they ask.
>
> **Q2**. Is this about transgender people?
>   **A**. It's about anyone who expresses a preference about what pronouns you use for them. Sometimes they will do this because they're trans, but it might also be because they're called Sam and people keep guessing wrong, or because they don't think their gender is any business of anyone here.
>
> **Q3**. So if someone I think is female asks to be called "he" rather than "she" then I have to comply?
>   **A**. Yes.
>
> **Q4**. What was that about being neither male nor female?
>   **A**. Some people consider themselves not to be either male or female. The usual term for such people is "non-binary". Just as you wouldn't want to be referred to by a pronoun that doesn't fit you, neither do they.
>
> **Q5**. This seems like a very marginal thing to make a fuss over.
>   **A**. While it may seem marginal to you, it can be a big deal for people who have spent much of their lives being thought of, and treated, as something that feels completely wrong to them.
>
> **Q6**. I sincerely and without malice disagree that transgender people are who and what they say they are. Am I still welcome on Stack Exchange sites?
>   **A**. You are, but some of the things you might want to say aren't (You might sincerely think that someone is an idiot, but you still aren't allowed to tell them so here, or refer to them as "that idiot", because it's rude and makes constructive communication harder. This is just the same).
>
> **Q7**. Are you saying that it's bigotry not to use the pronouns someone asks for?
>   **A**. No. Sometimes that's a thing bigots do, which is why it's mentioned in the "No bigotry" section of the Code of Conduct, but not everyone who is uncomfortable about some people's pronouns is a bigot (Note, though, that the *effect* of using language in a particular way doesn't depend on whether you're a bigot or not; something you say with the purest of intentions may be just as hurtful as if a bigot says it. Our Code of Conduct is intended to *avoid hurting people*, not to *keep bigots out*).
>
> **Q8**. But free choice of language is important to me. This rule impairs my freedom of speech.
>   **A**. By participating here you're agreeing to treat others with politeness. That includes not complaining that they're idiots (even if you sincerely think they are, and even if you're right). It also includes not misgendering them, however sincerely.
>
> **Q9**. My religion tells me that people can't change their gender. Aren't you treating me with disrespect in the name of treating others with respect?
>   **A**. You are welcome to believe anything you like about people's gender, just as they are welcome to believe anything they like about your religion. But if you go out of your way to point out your disagreement about their gender, you aren't behaving in a way we want here — just as people who make a fuss about how wrong they think your religion is aren't behaving in a way we want here.
>
> **Q10**. Am I forbidden to express my opinion about this?
>   **A**. In most contexts your opinions about gender, whatever they are, are off topic. In contexts where those opinions are actually relevant — as they might be in, say, a discussion on Philosophy.SE — you are welcome to express those opinions so long as you do so respectfully and politely. But please be aware that many things you might want to say may be *extremely distressing* to some readers, and try to minimize that distress.
>
> **Q11**. I find it really distressing to use pronouns in a way I think is wrong. Is there really no alternative?
>   **A**. You can often avoid using pronouns altogether. It's actually pretty rare to need third-person pronouns at all on most Stack Exchange sites. But if you *conspicuously avoid* using pronouns for one group of people while using them normally for others, you will likely make them feel rejected and excluded. Don't do that.
>
> **Q12**. So do I have to use pronouns where I normally wouldn't, just to make it clear that I'm using the ones someone has asked me to?
>   **A**. If you're writing something that naturally doesn't need pronouns, it's unlikely that anyone will be bothered by their absence. Problems only arise when a person or group feels singled out by having pronouns used for other people but not for them. If you're writing normally and naturally and it comes out pronoun-less, then that's fine.
>
> **Q13**. I'm not a native speaker. Am I going to get in trouble just because my English isn't great?
>   **A**. No. Honest mistakes are fine, and everyone should understand that non-native speakers make a lot of honest mistakes.
>
> **Q14**. I'm a moderator. I often have to refer to other users, I can't really choose which ones I have to refer to, and often it isn't feasible to avoid pronouns. So do I really have to use pronouns I find uncomfortable?
>   **A**. Yes, sorry. As a moderator you're a representative of Stack Exchange as well as of the community, and we at Stack Exchange have decided that using inappropriate pronouns for someone, or conspicuously avoiding using pronouns for them at all, is disrespectful. If you find that difficult, we hope you can grit your teeth and be nice to them just the same — as you would do if dealing with a user you find annoying in other ways. If you honestly can't do that, then being a moderator here isn't for you.
>
> **Q15**. Does this mean that I will be in trouble if I ever get someone's pronouns wrong?
>   **A**. No. It's fine not to know what they want. It's fine to make an honest mistake. But once you know what someone wants, please act accordingly.
>
> **Q16**. What if someone wants some nonstandard pronoun that I don't even know how to use?
>   **A**. Then everyone will be especially understanding if you get it wrong. Just do your best.
>
> **Q17**. What if someone wants to be referred to as "the Great and Mighty One" or by an obscenity or something?
>   **A**. If something is obviously unreasonable — e.g., if they are demanding to be worshiped or asking you to use obscenities when referring to them — then you are welcome to act accordingly. Note that "it sounds silly to me" is not sufficient grounds to think something is obviously unreasonable. If you and they can't agree, seek an independent opinion from a moderator (or, if a moderator is one of the parties to the dispute, the Community Team) as you would in other cases of dispute.
>
> **Q18**. If someone is non-binary, does it really matter whether I call them "ey" or "they" or "xe" or some other gender-neutral pronoun? Do I really have to handle dozens of different pronouns?
>   **A**. Many non-binary people will be OK with whatever non-binary pronoun you prefer for them — if in doubt, ask.
>
> **Q19**. I'm a moderator. What should I do if I see these rules being broken?
>   **A**. If someone makes an honest mistake, you should probably point it out gently. (Or let the person in question do it, if it seems likely that they would prefer that.) But if someone knows and is refusing to comply, treat this as you would any other case where someone is being deliberately disagreeable.
>
> **Q20**. I'm not a moderator. What should I do if I see these rules being broken?
>   **A**. Again, if you see an honest mistake, then you should probably point it out politely. If it looks as if there's something more than that going on, please flag what you see. A moderator or community manager will take a look.
>
> **Q21**. I'm worried that I may get banned. Should I be?
>   **A**. Not if you're acting in good faith. If you go out of your way to talk to, or refer to, people in ways you know they will find upsetting, then you are likely to get the same sort of escalating warnings and suspensions as you would for willfully upsetting people in other ways.
>
> **Q22**. What should I do if I don't know someone's pronouns?
>   **A**. Use gender-neutral language — use their name instead of a pronoun, use "they", or find some other way of organizing your sentence. If their username makes it seem obvious what their pronouns are, it's probably OK to go with those, but be aware that you might guess wrong and be ready to apologize and adjust if it turns out you did.
>
> **Q23**. "Gender-neutral"? Does that mean like "he/she"?
>   **A**. Many people do this and it's better than just calling everyone "he", but it doesn't work for non-binary people and therefore isn't really gender-neutral. Other ways are better.
>
> **Q24**. Do I have to say what my pronouns are?
>   **A**. No.
>
> **Q25**. I want to let people know what my pronouns are. What should I do?
>   **A**. Put them in the "About me" section of your profile.
>
> **Q26**. Isn't all this causing lots of inconvenience to everyone for the sake of a tiny minority?
>   **A**. No. Two things are required of you. First, that *when someone requests particular pronouns* you take notice. If only a tiny minority cares then this will hardly ever happen. If it happens a lot, then it turns out that a lot of people care. Second, that *you don't make gratuitous assumptions about people's gender*. That's something you should have been avoiding in any case, even if there were no trans people in the world at all.
>
> **Q27**. Seriously, though, I haven't seen any hostility or disrespect towards transgender people; why do we need any of this?
>   **A**. It's very easy not to see things that don't affect you personally! Many trans people have told us that they feel uncomfortable, unwelcome, or even unsafe here. That isn't what we want, and it shouldn't be what anyone wants. We hope that these small modifications to the Code of Conduct will make it less likely that anyone *accidentally* says things to make those people feel unwelcome, and make it easier to take appropriate action if anyone does so *deliberately*.
>
> **Q28**. If someone puts a pronoun request into a question they're asking, should we leave that in or edit it out as noise?
>   **A**. Add a comment noting what they said and suggesting that they add it to their profile. Edit it out of the question as you would with "Hi" and "Thanks". Because you've made their request less visible, keep an eye out for mistakes in answers and comments and consider making polite corrections.
>
> **Q29**. There are still edge-cases that aren't clear to me.
>   **A**. There always will be. Use your common sense, be nice, assume good faith but be prepared to revise that assumption in the face of the evidence, and you are unlikely to go too far wrong.
>
> **Q30**. I heard that someone was removed as a moderator for pronoun-related behaviour that seems, according to the above, as if they did nothing to violate the Code of Conduct. What's up with that?
>   **A**. Someone was removed as a moderator for pronoun-related matters. There's an ongoing dispute as to whether that was justified, and this isn't the right place to discuss it. Our policy going forward is what's described here.

---

**What's different**

My FAQs:

- back off a bit on the "compulsion": you have to refrain from *conspicuous* pronoun-avoidance, because that's what actually has the potential to cause hurt; this means (1) that if you're writing *naturally* and don't outright misgender people then you're fine, and (2) that you're unlikely to get in trouble for anything you could do while honestly trying to treat people nicely.
- try to clarify some of the issues by analogy with less contentious parallels which I hope will be understood even by people with divergent opinions on gender: calling someone by a pronoun they've asked you not to use is rather like calling them an idiot; *even if in some sense you're right* it's rude and you shouldn't do it here.
- explicitly address some specific pain points: religious convictions, insincere pronoun requests, having to use *specific* neopronouns.
- change the policy of leaving pronoun-declarations in questions, which in practice I think will hardly ever be an issue (aside from trolls doing it because they don't like the policy) but which I think SE staff got very wrong.

These changes are all, so to speak, in the same direction. So am I in effect saying that we should give in to the bigots? No. (The bigots want to call you "he" if you were assigned male at birth and now identity as female; I am proposing to say a firm no to that. The bigots want to insist that everyone is either "he" or "she"; I am proposing to say a firm no to that.) I am saying, though, that in practice LGBTQ+ people on Stack Exchange sites are better served by a set of rules that is a little less ambitious but that more of the users and moderators can sincerely endorse.

**My own positions**

In case anyone cares: I call people what they ask to be called. I consider your gender to be whatever you tell me you consider it is. I think people saying things like "oh, I identify as an attack helicopter" are stupid trolls and can be treated the same way as other stupid trolls. I am generally opposed to *requiring* people to say specific things. I think it is possible to have misgivings about the whole idea of transgenderness without being a bigot, but have no such misgivings myself. I would like Stack Exchange sites to be places where everyone, including people whose views I find horrifying, can coexist peacefully when discussing things that don't pertain to their mutually-horrifying views.

Comment: I think this is a fair and honest post that deserves an equally fair and honest critique. I will write one, thank you.

Comment: It's long & wordy, but maybe that's necessary. The tone is certainly a *huge* improvement. I'll give it a +1.

Comment: It may be long partly because "I lacked the time to make it shorter" but yes, in the present circumstances I think a lot of words may be needed because there are a lot of concerns to address.

Comment: I'd like to see a Track Changes version, please.

Comment: @aparente001 I'm not sure I understand. Do you mean (1) you'd like more specificity about what's different between my FAQs and the official ones, or (2) if I edit this then you'd like me to make sure I'm explicit about what changes I've made, or (3) something else?

Comment: I think adding a FAQ Q/A about using usernames and/or avoid pronoun usage if it isn't needed would be very useful, as well as explicitly addressing technical site Q/A ([1 from Makato](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/334909/476162), [2 from Shog](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/335035/476162), [3](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/335237/476162))

Comment: Could you change the religion part? The A is a strawman. I doubt they would _" point out [their] disagreement about their gender"_. Their problem is that the CoC **forces** them to use a language (pronouns) that contradicts their beliefs.

Comment: Just like [George's apology was much better than Sara's](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334248/an-update-to-our-community-and-an-apology), your FAQ is much better than the original. There might be a lesson here: Maybe the CMs should rely more on their talented community and work to improve by consensus rather than by dictum.

Comment: @Paul White Hmm, good point; I should use different language. (I think _something_ along these lines is clearly true, but evidently "representative" is a word with legal meaning that I should specifically avoid.)

Comment: @Fermiparadox I'm not sure whether you're saying (1) that _no one_ would insist, on religious grounds, on calling someone (say) "he" who asks to be called "she" or (2) that if they do then it shouldn't be called "pointing out their disagreement about their gender". I agree (of course!) that _plenty_ of religious people won't do #1, and maybe that needs to be more specific, but _some_ do. As for #2, it seems obvious to me; if I call you "he" when I know you want to be "she" then I _am_ expressing an opinion about your gender and it isn't yours.

Comment: Without looking at the content, I can say it's too long. The original FAQ has 14 questions, which were already far too many. In this FAQ that you are proposing there are **30** questions. **Thirty questions** connected to the use of pronouns, I have to comb through them to be absolutely sure, who is going to read all of that? Disgruntled users on Meta, maybe, but an SO user (who probably received a warning) looking for clarifications will just be turned off.

Comment: This is _excellent_! Thank you very much for posting it. Can we now vote to close the SE version of a FAQ as a duplicate of this one? Joking apart, I would really love to see this replace SE's version. This is a clarification of the CoC I am happy to enforce as a mod and even happier to live by as a user.

Comment: Actually, they're quite good. But I would still eliminate a few.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I think it may be like features in (say) Microsoft Word: no one uses more than 20%, but it's a different 20% for everyone. Everything that's in there is in there for a specific reason. I do agree that it's long and I would be happier if it could be shorter; perhaps with more work some of the answers could be condensed or combined without loss, but I'm not sure there's anything that could simply be deleted without harm. I could be wrong, though; do you have specific examples in mind?

Comment: @Mari-LouA these are FAQs, they don't need to be read in their entirety, you just find the answer to the one you're wondering about. And every single one of these gives a useful clarification. The CoC is short and sweet and intended to be read in full. This is something different.

Comment: @terdon but it's thirty points about *pronouns*. Imagine if the management had proposed this to begin with? Would users have magnanimously welcomed it with open arms? The principle  error lies not in the original SE FAQ, which isn't that terrible to begin with  but in not reinstating Monica.

Comment: @Mari-LouA which is a subject completely unrelated to how we should comport ourselves on the site in general. There are more than enough discussions about Monica going on and I am and have been involved in many of them. There is no need to focus on that subject, important though it is, on this post as well. Here, let's just focus on providing a useful clarification of the CoC that users can live with and mods can enforce.

Comment: 1. This is the kind of dialogue we SHOULD be having. 2. Like the OP, I value the thoughts of those IN the LGBTQ+ community more than my own, but... 3. There's a LOT to like in here. 4. I think most of Aza's improvements below make sense and offer a helpful perspective. 5. It IS incredibly long, but I'm not sure it can be made shorter without losing important pieces, and it's an FAQ, not a policy, so I think it's okay.

Comment: @snailcar I understand; obviously nothing in a document of this kind can possibly ensure either that you _are_ safe or that you _feel_ safe. But I'd settle for something like "does what a document of this sort can reasonably do to make things around here tolerable for LBGTQ+ people".

Comment: Might I suggest using this as a basis for a community FAQ? Considering one of the key issues is community feedback, we could roll in the necessary bits from the answers and possibly make something that reflects the experiences of the community better. Might also be a nice gesture to work together on this

Comment: Well done.  I endorse this post, and would use it as the basis for my moderation efforts going forward (if I were still a moderator, that is).

Comment: I don't post here regularly, but I can see how you tried to address many corner cases that were left out in the official FAQ. However, I don't think a CoC that asks users to simultaneously respect everyone's gender and religion is possible. The Q that begins "Q. My religion tells me that people can't..." simply fails to bridge the gap, although it is a commendable try. I have not upvoted or downvoted your post, or, in fact, anyone's post concerned with this controversy. I don't know what should be done about this issue, although your revised FAQ sounds like one possible path.

Comment: This is the [faq-proposed] post that Stack Exchange _should have_ brought to the community: for questions, discussion, and refinement.

Comment: Various people have edited this and by and large their edits are fine. I've just undone a few things that were intended as stylistic improvements but that I consider stylistic disimprovements, and I'd like to mention one more substantial thing I reversed. I referred to "unusual pronouns" and it was changed to "different" in order to be less "othering"; I submit that using the word "different", which literally means _other_, is not an improvement in that respect. Unusual does not mean bad, and pronouns other than "he" and "she" _are_ unusual.

Comment: But of course it's not up to me what makes people feel othered, and if it turns out that "different" is preferred to "unusual" by most people who use those pronouns then I'll gladly put it back again. All feedback welcome, as usual.

Comment: This, this, a thousand time this. This should be featured. This should be a model of what SO should be doing with us. I might not agree with all of it and I have some nuances I might voice later, but holy cow is this _lightyears_ ahead of what SO did. I also greatly appreciate how the default stance here is not 'my way or the highway; you're not welcome here'.

Comment: This is essentially my interpretation of the “official” Code of Conduct, and what I will be following/enforcing as long as I am allowed to remain a moderator. In particular, I like that it focuses on the stated (and hopefully intended) primary goals of inclusiveness and respect, rather than policing speech and asking moderators to judge intent. I’m sure the FAQ can be trimmed down, and I’d be more than open to iterations on it (like explicitly allowing neutral, third-party pronouns), but your CoC is pretty much exactly as it should be; nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan The changes I made improve readability, grammar, and inclusiveness. Please consider good faith when interacting on the site, including weighing the contributions of others to content you post. The overwhelming majority of changes I made were to phrases or wordings that were outright ungrammatical.

Comment: I don't find all the answers in your proposed FAQ "perfect" (lacking a better word), but I upvoted because you are giving intermediate options.

Comment: @TylerH *The overwhelming majority of changes I made were to phrases or wordings that were outright ungrammatical* I don't think "glad of" is ungrammatical, it might be a Britishism though. Hmm, Longman agrees: [be glad of something](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/be-glad-of-something) As for the "overwhelming" that's debatable.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I did say most, not all, though it looks like I was thinking I made a lot more adjustments to this post than I actually did -- I edit a lot of posts, so I must've been thinking of a similar one. At any rate, "glad of" is awkward to me as an American to the point of having to stop and think exactly what it might mean, and I doubt "glad to receive" sounds as awkward to British readers, so IMHO that's a clear improvement.

Comment: @TylerH I commented because "glad of" did not sound weird to me in the slightest, and I'm *Britalian*, the Longman dictionary doesn't say it's BrEng either. I did find one dictionary entry (MacMillan) labelling it "old fashioned", so it could be that. BTW, Lexico (formerly Oxford Online dictionary) has *The two intrepid cyclists would be very glad of sponsorship*

Comment: @TylerH I think you caught one actual mistake, whose correction I left in; I am pretty certain that none of the things I undid were grammatical errors. (Might be a British/American thing, indeed.) Evidently we disagree about whether "different" or "unusual" is less othering, and as I said above I'll happily change it back if there turns out to be a clear preference from the potentially-othered people in question. I'm not sure what I said that makes you think I thought your changes were not in good faith, but I don't think that; I just disagree with some of them.

Comment: ... Wait, you _just unilaterally changed them back_ again? I thought we weren't meant to do Wikipedia-style edit wars here.

Comment: I solicited a bit of feedback in Another Place, where the general feeling was that indeed "glad to receive" is clearer to many than "glad of", so let's leave that as it is. Jury's still out on "unusual" versus "different"; best suggestion so far is that "less common" might be better than either, but perhaps what's needed is an entirely different way to say it. I haven't thought of a good one yet, though.

Comment: Not a single word here from any staff or CM. Curious, isn't it?

Comment: @VictorStafusa As we've seen, SE sometimes moves a bit slowly on this stuff (I wonder whether lawyers are involved), so I wouldn't assume they aren't listening.

Comment: @TylerH I've rolled back your roll back for now because it seems conflict with author's intent (since Gareth already rolled back your changes once). Lets not do edit wars - if OP wants those changes he can make them.

Comment: This was ok up until _if you conspicuously avoid using pronouns_ which means: we will judge you by arbitrarily deciding what was avoided, i.e. we will judge you by what we don't even see. This creates fear and resistance. And it quite clearly is  contrived to do so and not coming from a real-worl situation.

Comment: Then I have to change my upvote to downvote for OP inexplicably acting in bad faith counter to the very spirit this post claims to be made in. cc @DavidGrinberg

Comment: @TylerH You are, of course, welcome and encouraged to vote your heart. I do not believe that you can seriously call Gareth a bad faith actor though. A disagreement between two very similar adjectives does not make a bad faith actor. Moreover, the mountain of evidence that is _the entire rest of this post_ and the positive engagement by the community clearly shows the opposite.

Comment: @TylerH What have I done "in bad faith" here? I'm confused.

Comment: (It looks as if you're deciding that _I'm_ acting in bad faith because _David Grinberg_ rolled back your most recent edit, but surely that doesn't make any sense?)

Comment: @TylerH After getting a bit more feedback elsewhere, I've gone with (1) your "glad to receive" which does generally seem to be preferred and (2) a third option for the unusual/different thing that I think improves on both.

Comment: To the "Well, I haven't seen anything unwelcoming to transgender people", I would add that *the response to the CoC itself* was very unwelcoming, because it looks like a thousand people upset that they don't get to misgender anymore. Some people may have had more nuanced reasons for downvoting, but that doesn't change the initial kick in the teeth.

Comment: Have we forgotten what FAQ means? Are all 30 (so far) really asked *frequently?* I get why this is upvoted - it's an attempt. But I'm concerned that there's too much attention on polishing the wording of 30 answers and not enough on saying, "what the heck, we're writing a whole Gettysburg Address to explain one sentence in the CoC!" If the premise is that these 30 QAs need to be right, that's aiming for failure. You need to figure out how to get it down to three or four. At this rate you will inevitably need sub-FAQs for the individual FAQs. Tell me that someone else sees this.

Comment: I saw it! I agree, they may not all actually be frequently asked (though I bet a lot of them will be) but the same is true of a lot of things that call themselves FAQs. I do think that if anything like this is adopted then one of the questions should be something like "why all the fuss about this stuff?". But I don't think it's wrong that there's a lot of material on this point; it's unfamiliar territory to a lot of people, after all.

Comment: I hope I don't sound derisive, because I appreciate what you're doing and why. But if you can't say this in three, you can't say it in thirty. When you reach a certain mass people will ignore the words and only see how big it is. No one will remember the words, only the number 30. There are 30. If you cut it down to three you can add links to other sites where people who want to read a few pages can do that.

Comment: I expect most people will never read it. That's fine; it just needs to be there for consultation. But if the goal is to clarify SE's intentions surrounding the new CoC then it needs to describe SE's intentions surrounding the new CoC, and links to someone else's material doesn't really do that job. (Of course, neither do _my_ versions of their intentions as such, but we have to imagine this or something like it being posted officially by SE). Don't get me wrong, I'd love it to be shorter, but I didn't see a way. Maybe there is one and I missed it.

Comment: Just think about what people will say. "After weeks of controversy, Stack Exchange released a four page addendum to the pronoun sentence in their Code of Conduct. 80% of their Code of Conduct is now about pronouns." That will be the message. 30 bullet points. 80% pronouns.

Comment: Maybe. But if it were 10x shorter I am confident that the same people would find other complaints to make. Again, I agree that in the abstract a 3-question FAQ is better than a 30-question FAQ; but if there are 30 questions worth of controversy surrounding the issues it covers, there's no good solution and the only question is what tradeoffs to make.

Comment: This question already has already spawned numerous additional requests for clarification or changes. If the intent is to really answer the questions raised then it should incorporate all of them. There should be maybe 40 or 50. It should keep growing. Otherwise, why does one question get an answer but the other falls under Q29? It seems odd to have 30 points and then say they don't cover the edge cases. There should only be that many points if most of them cover edge cases. Most of this should be replaced by Q29.

Comment: I think this a well written, thoughtful and well research approach that I fully endorse. Personally, I didn't see much difference between this and the original, but I think this does good job of clarifying some of the questions/concerns that were raised.

Comment: Very well written, and much, much better than the original, but ... still no.

Comment: “the associated FAQ” link https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334900/official-faq-on-gender-pronouns-and-code-of-conduct-changes is broken. Please restore.

Comment: I've added a Wayback Machine link.

Comment: I applaud the time and effort you put into this.  Phase 2 is liposuction. :)  There is a lot of "short attention span" participation at internet sites (SE/SO or not), so a thorough scrubbing for brevity is in order to give it better shape.  Again, applause for the time and effort invested.

Comment: As a trans person myself, who didn't know about this post until now, I just want to thank Gareth not only for the policy - which in my opinion has all the bases covered and is absolutely excellent! - but also for taking the initiative on this and putting in the effort. Including dealing with corner-case situations! Thanks Gareth.

Comment: @AJM-Reinstate-Monica You're welcome! Thanks for the kind words. I don't know whether you know, but there's a new [official CoC pronouns FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336364/what-does-the-code-of-conduct-say-about-pronouns), created by SE and largely based on this one. It's been better received than its predecessor, not that that would be difficult :-).

Answer (score 83):

My thoughts on this post are highly positive and I sincerely commend the work you put into this. I have some critiques towards subtlety that I think could be helpful in narrowing down the issue further. But I appreciate what you've done with the FAQ, here, for a lot of reasons.

The reasons I appreciate this mostly boil down to:

- Clearer assertions about what behavior is requested and required;
- Clearer explanations of why that behavior is requested/required;
- The same for the negative case;
- It gets the whole issue... pretty much spot-on correct.

So my comments more so aim at subtleties, things that I wouldn't want to see swept under the rug, but aren't necessarily *bad* for the most part.

> I wonder whether any policies on this contentious issue would be more broadly acceptable to the community while still addressing the issues the revised CoC and the FAQ were intended to address.

I wonder this, too. The form of contention we are seeing leaves me wondering whether people sincerely just don't believe they should have to use trans people's pronouns *at all*, and are seeking a framework that will allow them to deny that onus. If that's the case, then efforts to reword the CoC *with them in mind* are doomed to fail. We would be better rewording the CoC to be effective for those who are more liable to hear.

I hope your positive guess is correct. I suspect at minimum *some* people will need to be empathetically exited no matter the outcome.

> [Trans people] want to have their often particularly difficult circumstances understood sympathetically.

This is... complicated. This would be nice, but it's not required. Truthfully, it's unlikely your typical cis person is really going to *understand* what it's like to be trans, and that's not a reasonable thing to ask of most people. Really, I think most of us just want to be *believed*. I want to be able to say "I am a woman" without receiving challenge for it. I want people to just... trust me, when I pass them my pronouns. Above all else, I would like to be *trusted*.

That way, whether someone treats me with respect isn't gatekept on whether they have sufficiently understood what it means to be trans; whether *I have explained* sufficiently what it means to be trans.

> Cynically minded people have attributed a number of other, less respectable-sounding, goals to various groups of participants here. I have largely ignored these.

It's appreciated.

> Actually, I think the CoC itself is fine as is; it's the elaboration in the FAQ to which some people object.

I worry that may miss the point of the objections. A number of the objections, questions, "concerns," "both sides"-es... are essential misreadings of the provided FAQ, or rules-lawyering expansions on them. That tells me people aren't actually *reading* it with an accepting mind to begin with. Yes, it's not perfectly clear, and better copy to make it clearer is probably warranted (and welcome!), but the fundamental problem may not be as much one of wording as you might think.

> Some people don't consider themselves either male or female

Should be: "Some people are neither male nor female..." Positively assert the existence of many genders; don't leave it open for interpretation. Leaving it as a matter of opinion is a factual inaccuracy. It will anger some people who do not believe there are many genders to word it this way, but I'd rather not introduce inaccuracies for their sake.

> **Q.** This seems like a very marginal thing to make a fuss over.
>   **A.** That isn't a question. Regardless, while it may seem marginal to you, it can be a big deal for people who have spent much of their lives being thought of, and treated, as something that feels completely wrong to them.

This may elide the point a bit. In reality, whether or not someone chooses to use another person's pronouns communicates a *lot* more than a linguistic decision. It communicates attitude, tone, etc. about who I am and what someone makes of my humanity. The real answer here is, "While it is on its surface a marginal thing, for the people for whom this is significant, it communicates more than you may expect."

I'm not sure how to word this to fit an FAQ format, though. It's kind of a subtle point.

> (You might sincerely think that someone is an idiot...

I worry about this one a bit, because it scans like the hat tip to "mentally ill t[slur]" stereotype. A different example would probably be better suited here.

> **Q.** Are you saying that it's bigotry not to use the pronouns someone asks for?

There is a subtle issue with the framing of this question. Bigotry is not a thing one either Has or Does Not Have; it is not either Present or Not Present in speech. It is always there, we all have it within us. It is *managed*.

So when your answer replies, "that's a thing bigots do," that gives someone the freedom to go, "well, I'm not a bigot, so this is okay." In reality, no comment will ever be free of bigotry, in the same way that no social structure built atop an indigenous people will ever be free of imperialism. It's something we live with and manage.

That being said, this is a pretty subtle concept to include or summarize in an FAQ.

> **Q.** But free choice of language is important to me. This rule impairs my freedom of speech.
>   **A.** That isn't a question. Regardless, by participating here you're agreeing to treat others with politeness. That includes not complaining that they're idiots (even if you sincerely think they are, and even if you're right). It also includes not misgendering them, however sincerely.

Suffers the above problems. The phrasing here implicitly cedes the point that it is acceptable to think of trans people as analogous "idiots." That's not a good middle ground to seek. Instead, an FAQ should positively assert that the stance is incorrect, but if you're able to can it and keep it to yourself, that's all right, or at minimum non-justiciable.

Not sure what "sincerely" misgendering someone is, outside of one-off mistakes.

I would reword this answer: "By participating here, you are agreeing to treat others with kindness. That includes not complaining about what respect for them involves, even if you disagree. It also includes not misgendering other users."

> You are welcome to believe anything you like about people's gender, just as they are welcome to believe anything they like about your religion. But if you go out of your way to point out your disagreement about your gender, you aren't behaving in a way we want here -- just as people who make a fuss about how wrong they think your religion is aren't behaving in a way we want here.

Critical and good. Thanks for writing this.

> Q. Am I forbidden to express my opinion about this?

This question is... complicated. It's more complicated than you might think, and if you look only at edge cases it may confuse people further. The real answer here is: "If your post essentially denies the truth in trans people, then you can't express that here, except under some *extremely* select circumstances. Even under those circumstances, care needs to be taken not to harm people."

> But if you conspicuously avoid using pronouns for one group of people while using them normally for others, you will likely make them feel rejected and excluded. Don't do that.

Good.

> **Q.** I'm a moderator. I often have to refer to other users, I can't really choose which ones I have to refer to, and often it isn't feasible to avoid pronouns. So do I really have to use pronouns I find uncomfortable?
>   **A.** Yes, sorry. As a moderator you're a representative of Stack Exchange as well as of the community, and we at Stack Exchange have decided that using inappropriate pronouns for someone, or conspicuously avoiding using pronouns for them at all, is disrespectful. If you find that difficult, we hope you can grit your teeth and be nice to them just the same -- as you would do if dealing with a user you find annoying in other ways. If you honestly can't do that, then being a moderator here isn't for you.

- No "sorry" here. Just yes. Don't apologize for asking people to be kind.
- "We... have decided that using inappropriate pronouns... is disrespectful." I would quibble and say it *is* disrespectful (Stack didn't just up an decide this on a whim), it's just never been explicitly addressed to date. But this is a minor point.
- Sincerely appreciate the closing line. This ultimately becomes a compliance/HR issue.

---

The rest of your FAQ is good and appreciated, by me. I might spot something later and come back to edit, but it passes at first test.

Onto the "what's different" section.

> back off a bit on the "compulsion"

For the most part, this is not actually encoded anywhere in the FAQ -- at least no more than it is in your post. People are going to scream "compelled speech" until the pigs fly home (or something), or at least until they're asked to leave. It's probably a good word to avoid, though.

> The bigots want to call you "he" if you were assigned male at birth and now identity as female[...]

Small tip: "The bigots want to call you 'he' if you are a woman who was assigned male at birth" does more to positively assert that trans people are the gender we say we are.

It may not be useful to phrase it as "the bigots," though, for the above reason on bigotry.

> I would like Stack Exchange sites to be places where everyone, including people whose views I find horrifying, can coexist peacefully when discussing things that don't pertain to their mutually-horrifying views.

This is always worth thinking carefully about. I'm not going to tell you you're wrong to do this, but rather, that it can be hard to see all of the effects of keeping people like this around. We struggle *hard* to be heard whenever a new form of it pops up. Unless you're trans, it's highly plausible people like this are doing harm without you even realizing.

That makes this position... trickier than it would seem, just based on what you've written here. Not *wrong*, per se. But this won't help people stay safe on its own.

---

I like these changes. I don't think they substantively alter any of the implementation or function of the CoC/FAQ, but there are some good suggestions in here worth keeping.

I hope this answer is useful to you.

Comment: Thanks! Much useful food for thought here. There's a repeated theme that I might summarize as "this needs to assert more positively that trans people are Right and those who are uncomfortable about using their pronouns are Wrong", to which my immediate reaction (which I reserve the right to reconsider) is: yes, I do in fact agree that trans people are Right, but it is sometimes better not to be maximally in-your-face at people who are Wrong, and I think this is one of those times.

Comment: So, e.g., if I change "now identify as female" to "a woman who ..." then _yes_, it will more positively assert that trans people are who and what they say they are, but in doing so I fear that it will make itself less likely to be heard by people who are _not_ as yet completely convinced of that, but who might be persuaded to be much less dickish about it.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan This is a pretty complex catch-22. If you word things in such a way as to bring people along, you _may_ end up writing in a way that denies queer justice. If you write in a way that promotes queer justice, you _may_ end up turning those marginal people away. The things to remember: the people "on the edge" are actually a tiny minority, as most people have made up their minds; and the act of education is better done 1:1 when personal circumstances make it possible. An FAQ is likely not the place you'll convince someone trans people are who we say we are.

Comment: I think the goal of a Code of Conduct should be primarily to regulate people's _conduct_, not their _opinions and values_, not least because most people are more willing to change their conduct than their opinions and values. And, if I'm right -- which I might not be! -- in thinking that some people with intermediate views are more likely to be persuaded to good _behaviour_ by a document that doesn't go out of its way to presume that their opinions are wrong -- then the less-asserting document will do _more_ to get people to behave in ways that don't hurt trans people.

Comment: @ExcludedandOffended This is not a political opinion, and I won't be arguing that point with anyone here.

Comment: And in this particular case I _don't_ think people "on the edge" are a tiny minority. Trans issues are still pretty new to a lot of people, and there are a lot of unformed or partly-formed opinions out there.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan That's possible, but I'd then want to seek a way of communicating a behavioral expectation that doesn't simultaneously imply an open question about the existence of non-binary people. I think that's possible to do, but I'm not immediately sure how to do it.

Comment: I appreciate your taking the time to add nuance & perspective to this. So far, this thread feels like the conversation we should have had in the first place. I do want to say, that although there's no question a few of the people with "concerns" are trying to cover for actual transphobia, I think that's really a very small minority. We can (& it's really essential here to) assume good faith on the part of the people who are pushing back on the coercive aspects of the new FAQ.

Comment: I'd like to point out that the idea behind the compulsion of speech metastasises when you're on the autistic spectrum. It's an anxiety to make people feel as welcome as possible, especially as there'd be a punishment waiting if someone does report you for it. The CoC changes may not have allowed for the breathing room to assume good faith, but this question addresses it completely, and settles that anxiety

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan I'm not sure where you've read into my post that I'm trying to regulate opinions and values, and would like to change that, because that was not intended. I sincerely respect the behavioral outlook of your post. What I'm worried about is the implied acceptability of the negation of trans people. It's possible to make the post behavioral without implying that you view that as an acceptable _stance_. Declaring openness to all ideas in this case _is_ a position.

Comment: @gung Transphobia's something all people need to manage in different ways. I think there's definitely a graduated scale here. A lot of the people we call capital-T Transphobes are just sitting at the worse end of a broad spectrum of harmful behaviors. I think, as part of this CoC update, people should be at least willing to inspect their own behavior, even if it's not severe. Hopefully that clarifies my terminology a bit.

Comment: @KyleFairns I'd be happy to chat with autistic folks 1:1/1:n to better understand their needs and how a CoC can better meet them. I know it's an imposition, though, so I wouldn't ask that of anyone on the spot.

Comment: In a situation where I hold position X and a bunch of other (otherwise-)reasonable people hold incompatible position Y, if I write in a way that presupposes X then it _will_ put Y-believers off. Writing in a way that presupposes as little as possible doesn't imply finding Y plausible, it just means _wanting to be able to communicate with Y-believers_. Whether that means finding Y "an acceptable stance" is a matter of definitions. It _does_ imply thinking that believing Y doesn't put a person so far beyond the pale that it's no use talking to them, but that's all.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan, in laymens terms, the language used in the current CoC "shuns the non-believers" but the language you've used, we can start a conversation that may end up in educating people on the subject?

Comment: (I do appreciate that being constantly faced with people who say Y! Y! Y! Y! makes anything less than uncompromising rejection of Y unpleasant or worse, but unless the only people who think Y are people there's literally no point trying to reach -- which in this case I think isn't true for many of the relevant Ys -- I think it may be worth putting up with that for the sake of hopefully getting better behaviour from people overall.)

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan That's... kind of true, outside of some linguistic trickery, so I'll roll with it for the sake of discussion. If that's the case, the question becomes, who would you rather appeal to? And, who would you rather turn away? Ultimately this framework for understanding how it's written means you have to pick the perspective from which you write a CoC. The perspective chosen prioritizes cis people on the margin over trans people by default, and I'm not sure that's the correct decision. At minimum, it shouldn't go uninspected.

Comment: I'd rather not turn _anyone_ away, though in practice obviously no matter what I write there will be people who hate it. I'm not sure exactly what you mean by "prioritizes cis people on the margin over trans people by default" but my _intention_ is to prioritize _what leads to better treatment for trans people overall_ over _how in-your-face the FAQ is in its support for trans people_. Because I'm pretty sure almost all trans people on SE sites spend much more time interacting with people who aren't yet fully onboard than they do reading the FAQ.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan Yeah, I hear you. This is an ongoing debate in the activism circles I run in, to be totally honest, so I'm empathetic to the way you've written it, for sure. The only other remark I'd have is, it's worth keeping in mind that most people aren't going to read the FAQ anyway. FAQ documents are more like, control/reference documents for power-users who are the actual agents responsible for promulgating culture. So it's okay if they're a little stronger in their wording -- they're really the people we want _on board_ with this. "Why FAQ matters" is probably for chat, though.

Comment: (There's a lot of other interesting stuff in this answer besides the single thread we've been discussing. I need to go to bed now -- it's 4.30am local time -- but I'll be revisiting the rest of it for sure. Thanks again.)

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan Thanks to you, too. Happy to drop into chat, any time. Just make a room and ping me :)

Comment: I can't even disagree with you. My previous comment deleted.

Comment: This is an AWESOME set of suggestions and perspectives for an already thoughtful and impressive proposal. Thank you.

Comment: Unsure this comment is useful, but I'll feel better writing it: if that  Faq comes to be the one SE follow, I wouldn't be afraid of how I write, It boils down to 'be sensible and do your best', this is not the feeling he actual FAQ gives me

Comment: @Aza I hope I'm not misunderstanding what you're saying, but in a way it feels like you're suggesting that a) everyone is a bigot to some degree, all the time and b) that you'd rather turn away the bigots than appeal to them. Both seem like reasonable propositions depending on your definition of what makes a bigot, but I can't really make them work together.

Comment: @sgf This is a pretty subtle discussion about where you draw the line on community safety. It's a little difficult to have in comments, though.

Comment: @Aza, I'm looking at the issue through a different lens, so my take on some of this is different.  But let me address one point in your answer.  re: compulsion (my own issue with the FAQ), you say, "For the most part, this is not actually encoded anywhere in the FAQ -- at least no more than it is in your post. People are going to scream "compelled speech" until the pigs fly home..."  Look at direct statements in the FAQ like Q9 and Q10.  They specifically mandate that there is no choice but to do it, and they are consistent with other SE statements.  (cont'd)

Comment: Perhaps that is not the intent and it is just poor wording.  In that case, the issue can be put to bed with a simple clarification.  On that issue, your answer is oblivious to the needs of some other users in the same way you find some other users oblivious to the needs of the trans community.

Comment: "Bigotry is not a thing one either Has or Does Not Have; it is not either Present or Not Present in speech. It is always there, we all have it within us. It is managed." Are you referencing some trend in psychology research or something similar? By definition bigotry is not some innate property that varies in people but rather a term used to describe *exceedingly* intolerant *behavior*. Anyway, I think it's a moot point, as the suggested FAQ entry above immediately explains that even though someone who does it may not be a bigot, it's still not OK (and could still be taken as offensive).

Comment: As usual, your posts on this issue cut right to the bone of the problem in a clear, concise, and accurate manner. Thank you so much for advocating on this issue as effectively as you have been.

Comment: This post is sooo long; the bounty should be increased. That said, I TRULY do not understand why ANYONE cares how someone else gender-identifies. I’m reminded of people who express their adamant “non-belief” in “Gay marriage.” If you don’t “believe” in marriage for LGBTI people, then don’t marry one. Call people by how they identify. WTH is the big problem?

Comment: "In reality, no comment will ever be free of bigotry" - Only if you're using a definition of "bigotry" which is so broad that it loses all meaning.

Comment: @Aza I categorically reject that avoidance should be included at all. You can say that's not compelled speech... but you're incorrect. I don't know how else to say it, but it's like saying 2 + 2 = 5. It's a form of incorrectness that is self evident. As for controlling what people believe, it does: The FAQ states that merely not recognizing it - i.e. believing or agreeing - is a violation of the Terms Of Service. Remove that language, and I'm sure everyone will be fine with the changes. Many people are taking issue with it. Believe them. They're not lying to you.

Comment: @GhostCat I would recommend carefully inspecting why you feel that way, because Stack did exactly what the community asked in this case. Why does that deletion feel like a slap in the face, after Stack actually listened and redrafted the FAQ? This is rhetorical, though -- please don't answer here.

Answer (score 65):

It's long & wordy, but maybe that's necessary.  The tone is certainly a *huge* improvement.  I'd like to highlight this part:

> Q. I find it really distressing to use pronouns in a way I think is wrong. Is there really no alternative?
>   A. You can often avoid using pronouns altogether. It's actually pretty rare to need third-person pronouns at all on most Stack Exchange sites. But if you conspicuously avoid using pronouns for one group of people while using them normally for others, you will likely make them feel rejected and excluded. Don't do that.
>
> Q. So do I have to use pronouns where I normally wouldn't, just to make it clear that I'm using the ones someone has asked me to?
>   A. If you're writing something that naturally doesn't need pronouns, it's unlikely that anyone will be bothered by their absence. Problems only arise when a person or group feels singled out by having pronouns used for other people but not for them. If you're writing normally and naturally and it comes out pronoun-less, then that's fine.

I think the implied flexibility—as long as both parties are interacting in good faith—is crucial.  This should allow people to find solutions that work for them so that we don't always have the north-going Zax and the south-going Zax butting heads obstinately and making the site blow up.  Many people disagree about many things, and yet we make it work.  That happens in life, and it has happened on SE sites.  It can happen in this case.  Trans people are not unreasonable, they want basic respect, not special treatment.  People who are unfamiliar with these issues, or uncomfortable with one or another option, aren't unreasonable either; they often just want to find a way that works for them and won't leave someone else feeling insulted.  Allowing the two parties to find a solution is the right way forward here.  (I would have thought that's common sense.)

I do want to note that draft versions of the new code of conduct were circulated amongst moderators for comment.  I, and other mods, made suggestions along these lines and the phrasing was softened.  I actually don't think the wording of the new CoC is problematic.  However, I was then blindsided by the coercive and authoritarian FAQ that came with it.  This corrects that and brings it back to the spirit that I thought many mods had been going for.

Comment: Love the Dr. Seuss reference! Glad you brought up the mods being blindsided by SO's FAQs; I think many of us non-mods weren't aware that the FAQ section had been pushed past the community.

Comment: For those who aren't familiar, [these](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dZmZzGxGpSs&ytbChannel=TheodorSeussGeisel) are the Zax.

Comment: @gung: I was wondering about that myself, and wasn't sure whether it was just a reference I didn't get, so thanks :)

Answer (score 39):

> People concerned by the "compelled speech" aspects of the CoC and its
>   associated FAQ: is this sufficiently non-constraining?

To me, the "compelled speech" angle comes from a previously unknown (to most), brand new way in which we're all suddenly expected to use language. This way of using language, frankly, does not make a lot of sense to some.

Consider this hypothetical:

What if people simply did not have names. What if the concept of a name was simply unknown? If you wanted to refer to someone you would use their physical description, perhaps where they worked, where they lived, etc. You might be "The 5'9, pregnant, stenographer who drives a Honda Civic", and everyone would know you by that description

And then, suddenly, The Government declared that you must call people by these things called "names" if they want you to. These names are, as far as you can tell, completely arbitrary and meaningless.

You've been used to the old way, and now you have to come to terms with this new concept and learn how to use them. Even worse, you're told that doing it the old way can be disrespectful, even offensive. If you resist, you will suffer consequences.

You might understand this hypothetical person's feelings. This person might end up feeling like the disrespected one.

That's how it might feel to suddenly be compelled to refer to someone as "ze".

Now, how does this proposed FAQ lessen the blow:

> We're asking that when someone indicates what pronouns should be used to refer to them, you **do as they say**.

"Do as they say" has a "compelled speech" smell to it. We're still being compelled to use language in a way the vast majority of us are not used to doing. If someone wants to be called "ze", we must comply. That's compelled.

There are some situations in which you can make certain demands of other people, however.
To asked to be called "she" instead of "he" is one of those acceptable demands. This *is* also "compelled speech", but people are okay with it, because it's part of the invisible social contract.

The difference is that "ze" is not widely accepted **yet**. The concept of arbitrary pronouns is new and strange to most.

It's a tautology: something must first be widely acceptable before it becomes an acceptable demand. Otherwise people might think *you* are the one acting in bad faith when you demand to be called 'faeself'

The good news is that social contracts change over time, and maybe 50 years from now, this will just be "the new normal". Heck, maybe I'm the dinosaur already.

Anyway, forcing people to integrate neopronouns into their speech, which may be new and unfamiliar, will cause them to feel "compelled" and disrespected.

I don't think any sort of re-wording will help this. This is a fundamental, unchangeable part of the new CoC, unless SE decides to roll it back.

This is not an argument that we shouldn't use one's stated pronouns. I'm just explaining the "compelled speech" argument.

Comment: This is a very good explanation that does a great job of capturing many people’s feelings about the new expectations. Very insightful. Ironically, this is the kind of respect and inclusiveness that we should be fostering and praising here: understanding and sympathizing with others’ feelings. Now, it might still be the case that these old-timers you refer to need to “get over it” and get used to the new way, but it’s still critically important to understand how they feel and why adapting may be difficult for them. And, most importantly, why immediate failure to adapt isn’t evidence of bigotry.

Comment: You write: 'These names are, as far as you can tell, completely arbitrary and meaningless.' You clearly consider this a valid ingredient for feeling compelled. But in my eyes it is up to the hypothetical person to update their knowledge and understanding of the issues involved. Compelled speech can be very undesirable and discriminating, but you kind of seem to forget how undesirable and widespread the discrimination of LHBTQ+ people is, right now in the real world.

Comment: This is a good explanation. You might also expand it to include the fact that we already had "compelled speech" in some circumstances. Say before all this brouhaha I had started calling John Q. Public "she," and he, identifying both as male and a gender-traditionalist, objected to this and asked to be called "he." Had I continued to call him "she," even if I claimed religious reasons for this I would almost certainly have been sanctioned (and rightly so, IMHO). I could correctly claim "compelled speech," but I don't think anybody would have cared.

Comment: @CurtJ.Sampson I tried to include that we already do have 'compelled speech' in the paragraph starting with: "There are some situations in which you can make certain demands of other people..."

Comment: @Frank'aWaaldijk I keep hearing this thing that LGBT+ people are are facing widespread discrimination. I would like to believe it but haven't seen much data yet. As you're a mathematician, could you please provide some relative statistics, as compared to, say cis people?

Comment: @Frank'aWaaldijk Thanks. The marriage legality statistic certainly is a good point. I do have access to internet resources though it's not always clear what to search for; there was no need for the snark.

Comment: @S.D. Sorry about the perceived snark, and yes you caught me at a grumpy moment. But the discrimination is really widespread and in my (perhaps not so humble) opinion hard to miss. There are countries where certain internet resources are censored or hard to access, and I did not want to presume that you had unrestricted access. Anyway, I should have replied more graciously, sorry again, nothing personal.

Answer (score 34):

I really appreciate the effort. This seems to be going in the right direction — and the process of discussion itself goes in the right direction.

Unfortunately, this FAQ is extremely long — even longer than the official one. To be usable, we'd have to come up with something that's short enough to be actually readable.

I think it would help to **separate gender and language as concerns**. Collapsing the two under “pronouns” muddies waters. Yes, I know that in English gender is mostly expressed through pronouns. But *not using someone's preferred pronouns* is not the same thing as *misgendering someone*. Not using someone's preferred pronoun includes not using pronouns at all, or using a gender-neutral pronoun, either of which can be either good or bad depending on whether this is the way you always write (good for you) or you're targeting someone in particular because you refuse to acknowledge their gender (which is bad).

There is one important question that you've punted:

> **Q.** I was taught that English has three third-person singular pronouns: *he*, *she*, *it*. All the books that I've read and all the movies that I've watched used these three pronouns consistently with what I was taught. What the hell are all these other words in this picture?
>
> [image: declension of 9 pronouns from UWM]
>
> and [even more](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334900/official-faq-on-gender-pronouns-and-code-of-conduct-changes/334991#334991)?

Comment: This is very helpful, but I would still need a bit more guidance regarding the grammar. First of all, is it correct that all these pronouns refer to a single person? I found the example sentences at [uwm.edu](https://uwm.edu/lgbtrc/support/gender-pronouns/). Can I rewrite the second sentence to _(1) tries to convince (2) that ..._?

Comment: I disagree that this newly-proposed FAQ is too long and needs to be shortened in order to be "readable." When people have a lot of questions, I would expect a long FAQ. FAQs don't need to be memorized, they just need to adequately address questions that a user base may have. Users can scan through questions and pay attention to the ones that address their particular uncertainties. Moreover, as this new FAQ illustrates, it should be done such that the community does not feel like they are being chastised, but instead feels like their questions are legitimate and are being addressed accordingly.

Comment: @wimh Each row of that table is for a different pronoun. One person may ask to be called "ve" and another "fae". Gilles, I haven't altogether punted the question; one of my FAQs is about "nonstandard pronouns that I don't even know how to use". But maybe there should be something along the lines you describe.

Comment: On the more general point: I do agree that misgendering someone is a more specific, and more severe, thing than using a pronoun that isn't the one they use but doesn't specify gender. (And unless I've messed up, my FAQ never uses the former term to refer to the latter.) But some people _do_ feel strongly about the pronouns used for them, even within the gender-neutral pronouns, and I think "use the pronouns people ask for" is a simpler rule that _in practice_ is scarcely ever more trouble to keep than "use pronouns matching the gender of the ones people ask for".

Comment: @J.R. the ability to scan something quickly and find the necessary information you are searching is something I teach to Italian students, it's an important  skill to master, but when you're faced with a **wall of text**, and English is not your first nor your second language but your third or fourth, the proposed version, although well-written and very clear, is still an insurmountable hurdle for a non-native speaker and for anyone who is not used to reading long detailed texts...

Comment: @Mari-LouA - That's why so many FAQ pages only list questions, and then you can click on one of those questions to read the answer. Nothing prevents this "wall of text" from being reformatted and eventually put into a page similar to, say, [this one](https://faq.whatsapp.com/).

Comment: @J.R. I can think of only one page that contains links to Q&A and that is the [FAQ for Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites) Take a butcher's at any of the linked posts, none, none have anywhere close to thirty bullet points or paragraphs. Despite the proposed FAQ being very well-written as it flows and has a friendly welcoming tone – it also explains complex ideas in a simple manner – it is too long. SE won't adopt your solution to the wall of a text, and they won't adopt McCaughan's FAQ either.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - I don't really care if this gets reformatted or not – that was just a thought. However, I care deeply about if SE will adopt this improved FAQ (or some semblance of it). Are we dealing with people who are flexible, reasonable, and open to positive changes and improvements? Or are they dictatorial and close-minded, convincing themselves that they are on the right course despite the unprecedented backlash from the community? That's the real issue I see, and it's much more important than the length of this proposal.

Comment: `Are we dealing with people who are flexible, reasonable, and open to positive changes and improvements?` No. Maybe once upon a time they were but not "today".

Comment: @Mari-LouA if done properly, what you will be faced with is a list of questions and you'll need to click to expand and read the answer. So much less text. Should be something like this: https://i.imgur.com/c9QQzon.png

Comment: To be honest, speaking as someone who might literally think (though likely not type) the question you cite as "punted"— **I don't think this FAQ is too long.**  Also I read this entire FAQ and I think it's a *fantastic* improvement over the "official" FAQ, and I have no objections to this one.

Comment: A: Other pronouns.

Comment: Yes, the FAQ is long. Because people have many questions. The relevant part of the CoC is however admirably concise: only one sentence.

Comment: @Raedwald The problem is that the FAQ sets rules that are not at all implied by the code of conduct. Someone who wants to apply the rules has to read and understand the whole FAQ.

Comment: Respectfully, I think that image is inadvertently fear-mongering. Several of those pronouns are virtually never used even in the most radical nonbinary communities. I've lived in all-trans houses where most of the people who came around were gender variant and I've never heard of someone who went by "per" or "ve". It makes it seem like there's this whole crazy list of things to remember when it's really not that complicated.

Answer (score 33):

> Q. Does this mean that I will be in trouble if I ever get someone's pronouns 
>   wrong?
>
> A. No. It's fine not to know what they want. It's fine to make
>   an honest mistake. But once you know what someone wants, please act
>   accordingly.
>
> Q. What if someone wants some nonstandard pronoun that I don't even
>   know how to use?
>
> A. Then everyone will be especially understanding if
>   you get it wrong. Just do your best.
>
> ...
>
> Q. There are still edge-cases that aren't clear to me.
>
> A. There always
>   will be. Use your common sense, be nice, assume good faith but be
>   prepared to revise that assumption in the face of the evidence, and
>   you are unlikely to go too far wrong.

I think you fixed it

Answer (score 31):

First, I commend you on the attempt, and for the obvious work that went into this.  You've done a good job of making the CoC seem more reasonable, and you better explained the reasoning.  It generally does a much better job of framing things.  A suggestion and a concern:

1. My first reading gave me the impression that your proposal characterizes people who have a different perspective as "bigots".  That seemed to dismiss any basis for a differing view.  Rereading the proposal, I see what you describe in the comments, that you're just describing bigotry.

   It's a very fine and delicate line to navigate.  People can easily misinterpret it, as I did without the context of the comment.  Misinterpretation will lead to a much less positive perception.  Suggestion: include context to orient the reader, and don't dwell on it more than necessary.  Keep the focus on the goal of encouraging positive behavior.
2. There is a fundamental issue that was introduced several weeks ago (note, your draft is the first document which frames things in a different way): that all users **must** use the stated pronoun or be subject to penalty.

   With your proposal, there's the potential that this problem might go away, but the issue is a major impediment to acceptance.  It's worth at least getting people on the same page so there can be discussion of whether the issue has been addressed.

   The policy has been framed as a simple act of respect to make people feel better about themselves.  For many users that's all there is to it, and it's hard for them to fathom how there could be a real issue for anyone.  If that were the actual extent of the policy, there would be no issue.  But the policy creates an issue by unnecessarily taking things a step further, adding no incremental benefit for trans users and causing harm and offense to other users.

   There are real and serious concerns for many users, and they seem to keep being misunderstood or dismissed in cavalier fashion by some. "Compelled speech" is only part of it; the concerns aren't that simple.  Let me try to describe some (but not all) of the concerns.   Since the only standing document is the official one, my use of CoC will refer to the official FAQ, which is what is driving the concerns.

   - Some users have sincere religious beliefs with which this requirement is in conflict.  The concept of not being required to violate one's religious beliefs is generally considered a fundamental freedom.  The CoC requires these users to choose between violating their faith and participating here, with the justification that the goal of the CoC is to insure that no one else is offended.  Respectful use of a pronoun other than the preferred one, in an otherwise respectful interaction, may not be optimal, but I don't think a reasonable person will be harmed by that, or should take offense.  Thus, the requirement appears to be without foundation, and  appears to reflect a callous disregard for the needs of such users.
   - Closely related, there's a concept in law of fairness, that when you balance the interests of two parties, you impose no more burden than necessary.  The CoC contains no sense of compromise, to provide adequate protection for the trans community while not being excessively burdensome on others.  By any reasonable standard, trans members can be treated with respect without imposing an absolute requirement that others violate their religious beliefs.
   - Some users are uncomfortable using certain pronouns.  Houseman's answer may be a good explanation that's applicable to many or most of these people.
   - Everyone agrees that trans members should be treated with respect, and that using a preferred pronoun is respectful.  When people do this, that's great and supportive.  What is concerning is when the failure to use the preferred pronoun is framed as being disrespectful.  There are many reasons why someone might not use the preferred pronoun, none of which is a matter of disrespect.  This demonizes some users, and creates a situation where failure to use the right pronoun is a thing, with the starting assumption that the person who did it is in the wrong.

After careful rereading of this proposal, it looks like it is a good finessing of the issue.  Wording along these lines may actually solve the problem.  If this had been the original wording, there would likely have been easy acceptance.  However...

Given SE's position and official pronouncements to date, people are looking for explicit assurance that preferred pronouns are not compulsory.  That is the context in which you are proposing this change.  By gracefully dancing around the issue, this proposal doesn't address that.  The concern remains, that if SE were to adopt essentially this proposed wording, the current official version may reflect Stack Overflow Inc.'s true intent, and this wording would be used to put a pretty face on it and mask the issue.  If there's a way for SE to provide explicit reassurance, perhaps in some separate document or discussion, that would put the issue to bed.

Comment: There are also people with various health issues that can have great hardship following current CoC. See: [How should I deal with the new CoC as non-native English speaker?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/335225/how-should-i-deal-with-the-new-coc-as-non-native-english-speaker)

Comment: My intention is precisely _not_ to characterize everyone who disagrees as "bigots". There _are_ bigots, but plenty of people who disagree with me about this stuff are not bigots. However, I'm not under any illusion that it's possible to write something that literally _everyone_ agrees with. What I'm hoping for (but I don't know that I've achieved so far) is something that _very few people disagree angrily with_.

Comment: I specifically tried to write in such a way as _not_ to say that you have to positively use the pronouns a person asks for or face sanction. Non-specific language and disengagement are always options (except for moderators, who face a different situation; I think anything that permits a moderator to refuse to engage with, say, non-binary people is a non-starter in terms of acceptability to SE management, and rightly so).

Comment: My suggestion is to just leave out those kinds of words.  If you need to characterize behavior, stick to a description of the behavior without attaching labels.  You did an impressive job with what you had to work with.

Comment: I understand the suggestion, but I think that if a document like this doesn't go out of its way to admit that there is such a thing as bigotry and it is a problem, and to explicitly distance itself from it, then some people will (for the avoidance of doubt: sincerely) view it as itself an expression of bigotry. Again, the aim is to minimize the number of people who are angry about this. It's possible that I got the balance wrong, or that there's no good balance to be had, but there are specific reasons for including the language about bigotry that I did.

Comment: For the avoidance of doubt, though, I don't mean to dismiss your concerns.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan, I just reread your document.  My original read was through the lens of SE's FAQ.  What I picked up on were actually ambiguous statements, and the lack of explicitly addressing the previously defined "compulsion" issue.  This version finesses that.  If what you describe here is an accurate and full description, this may cover it.  SE defined their intent with their FAQ so there will be a concern that SE's FAQ is the real intent (i.e., compulsory), and this version just sugar coats that.  Hopefully, that will get cleared up.  (cont'd)

Comment: BTW, one other suggestion, you might want to drop the gimmick of phrasing as a statement and then starting the answer with "that isn't a question".  It's a little contrived.  :-)

Comment: I only did it _twice_! :-)

Comment: (The contrivance was for a specific reason: those were things that seemed like they needed addressing but that weren't naturally written as questions, so I thought I'd lampshade it. It probably wouldn't be the best tone for an actual corporate-authored FAQ, for sure.)

Comment: This -- especially your last bullet!  "X is respectful" does *not* mean "not X is disrespectful".

Comment: I've proposed a bunch of copyedits so that your ideas come through as clearly as possible.  If they don't feel right, I'll understand if reject some or all of the proposed edits.

Comment: _"The concept of not being required to violate one's religious beliefs is generally considered a fundamental freedom."_ No, it is not. The concept is that you are free to practice your relgious beliefs _only to the extent that the practices do not infringe on what we have decided are the rights of others_. E.g., we vaccinate children anyway even when this conflicts with their parents' religious beliefs.

Comment: @CurtJ.Sampson, in relation to the discussion here, in what way is the practice of people's religious beliefs infringing on the rights of others?

Comment: @fixer1234 It's an excuse I'm commonly hearing for violating the right (on Stack Exchange) to choose the pronoun by which others will refer to you.

Comment: @CurtJ.Sampson, I didn't want to get into a treatise on the fine points of  religious freedom.  Yes, the government reserves the right to limit freedoms when the health and safety of others are at stake, and the like.  And what people consider for themselves is not always what is provided by law.  re: pronouns--people certainly have a right to choose their own pronouns, and it is respectful for others to use those.  The question is whether one person has the right to compel another person say something that violates their faith.

Comment: @fixer1234 No, the question is whether or not _Stack Exchange should make such a rule for speech it publishes on its site_. Note that this rule does not truly "compell" someone to do something, it simply says that they can't post on SE unless they follow that rule; they always have the option of not posting here.

Comment: @CurtJ.Sampson, that's kind of what that particular ruckus is about--violate your faith or don't post here.  This may all be a moot point since recent posts from SE staff seem to indicate that this requirement may not be included in the revised version of the CoC FAQ as a necessary condition for treating people with respect.

Comment: @fixer1234 I don't see how the point can be moot at all, since the core conflict is, "A wants to be referred to by pronoun X; B wants to refer to A by different pronoun Y." Only one of these two can have their way.

Comment: @CurtJ.Sampson, by "moot", I meant that the CoC FAQ might no longer directly specify it.  How they solve that issue remains to be seen.  But there are other options than pronoun Y, like not phrase in 3rd person, refer to username, gracefully disengaging if it's an issue, etc.  People who intend to treat each other with respect will find mutually satisfactory ways to do it.  Trolls can be dealt with.

Comment: @fixer1234 When you write something that needs a pronoun, those other options you mention are not available. When you deliberately write in a contorted way that makes it clear you're avoiding pronoun use, you're still being disrespectful. This has all been discussed in extensive detail before. If you think that these other solutions really are a solution for all your cases, then you shouldn't be concerned about the rule because it won't affect you, will it?

Comment: @CurtJ.Sampson, I don't know how it will all work.  We started this discussion in relation to religious issues.  They resulted from specific FAQ wording, as did a number of other issues.  At this point, we're second guessing hypotheticals.  It would make sense to wait to see the revised document and then react to that.  Can we do a rain check on this discussion?

Answer (score 29):

I typically prefer not to disclose my IRL gender/sex, but, since the post specifically calls for trans and nonbinary persons to chime in: I am a nonbinary-ID'd person taking cross-sex hormones, making me both trans and nonbinary.

(Btw, if anyone's curious, I am actually not a fan of the current popular ideology of gender identity, how it works, its relation to sex, and so on-- however, taking cross-sex hormones gives someone mixed physical sex characteristics, and this is what leads me, someone who does not give a flip about queer theory and so on, to ID this way.)

That said...

I find both the original code of conduct's FAQ and the proposed change overly lengthy, and not getting to the real heart of the matter. We should ask ourselves what the true thing we want to avoid is. I would say it's people going off-topic by harassing others about their gender or sex (I've never seen such a thing, but I'm on the math and programming side of things where such topics would not arise in the course of a normal Q&A). And ~why~ do we want to avoid it? Because it's extremely annoying for someone to derail a thread with rude and irrelevant content. I hope we can all agree that, for our own respective definitions of harassment, harassing behavior is undesirable.

All of the proposed FAQs that I have seen so far have taken a position on what constitutes harassment then tried to address all the predictable cases of its manifestation. I am inclined to think that harassment is like Supreme Court Justice Potter Stewart's description of "obscenity" in Jacobellis v. Ohio: *"I shall not today attempt further to define the kinds of material I understand to be embraced within that shorthand description, and perhaps I could never succeed in intelligibly doing so. But I know it when I see it[.]"*

My personal primary objection to the official FAQ and proposed alternatives is the threat of an increased noise to signal ratio for content. Frankly, I don't want to see people asking others' pronouns, volunteering their pronouns, squabbling over the use of pronouns, etc. Any addition to the site that attempts to automatedly inform answerers of questioners' pronouns will be just that to me: noise. Any in-line inquiry or disclosure will certainly be noise as well. And the elaborate dances that I anticipate as users overcompensate or stumble while trying to avoid specific prohibited behaviors or engage in specific proscribed behaviors may be the worst of all.

Thus, I think the most effective method of addressing harassment is to simply prohibit harassment itself and allow moderators to identify it as it arises on the basis of it being off-topic rather than on the basis of any particular ideology or specification. If someone finds out that OP uses "they" pronouns, and writes "OP asks what a dog is. My answer to HIM would be that HE can use HIS dictionary to see for HIMself what a dog is, or simply look at HIS dog." While this may not use any more characters than an appropriate answer, the capitalization and insertion of an implicit ideological comment about the answerer's opinions on gender identity is off-topic content, despite not being on a separate line from the answer. Anyone abnormally inserting excessive pronouns or giving a roundabout and unusual explanation to make a point should be quickly identifiable by native speakers as the answer will seem bizarre. In stackexchanges with questions that specifically involve or are contingent upon the poster's gender identity or sex, an answer that regards a different gender identity or sex would again be off-topic as it would address a question not asked.

In my opinion simply failing to affirmatively acknowledge someone's pronouns or identity in a thread unrelated to social or personal matters does not constitute harassment (unless it's a repeated pattern of conduct where the person runs around answering all questions by that asker just to make a point of botching their pronouns over and over, which would again fall under active rather than passive behavior).

And to address the most likely case: suppose someone says "Well, I would advise OP to look under her bed and observe blah blah blah" and OP responds "I'm a guy :p" in a comment. Okay, technically a bit who-cares but this sort of thing is not over the line for chit-chat in comments. But once the answer responds back "Oh no you're not, I don't believe in guys!" that is taking it into another realm; it is starting a spin-off discussion. Either don't respond (if you don't care or don't believe in men), or some cursory acknowledgement if you feel personally compelled to reply.

Thoughts?

P.S.-- the vast majority of trans people, in my estimation, do not want to be made a spectacle of like this and have everybody hate us because a few people decided to plop "our" "needs" onto the dinner plate of the whole world like an unwanted serving of fish. We have no more vested interest in strangers in a Q&A forum knowing our gender than anyone else (nor do we need the most protection online or whatever the wording was in the CoC release... it's online for heaven's sake, the whole thing is that no one can "see" your arbitrary physical characteristics). Do you see cis people running around making sure everyone knows they're a man or a woman before anyone can answer? No! This whole thing is so embarrassing. I'm curious whether there was an actual trans person anywhere behind the original proposal.

Comment: I would like to footnote that upvotes will not be taken by me at least as an endorsement of my ontological views on gender itself (vs. the matter at hand). I don't want to derail too much with that.

Comment: Even as someone who probably rather strongly disagrees with your views on sex and gender, I can wholeheartedly support this common sense answer. It amounts simply to, "Don't be an _______," something I'm on board with irrespective of our disagreements. This is what the Be Nice policy used to be about: respect and courtesy for **everyone**, irrespective of their opinions, not just particular groups of people. +1

Comment: Re: the last sentence, it could be [a case of overcompensation](https://hashtagcauseascene.com/podcast/sara-chipps/), e.g. at 05 min 33 secs, 19 min 33 secs, and 24 min 13 secs. (See also [MSE 336623](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336623).)

Comment: @P.Mort.-forgotClayShirky_q I listened starting at 5m 33s and didn't hear anything relevant. Are you sure that is the right time stamp?

Comment: With all due respect, those links strike me as not particularly relevant, to be honest (like, I see the topical connection, but I think it's more likely that each one of these cases was a separate, arbitrary social justice debacle. They're incredibly common, and being trans I can say that this sort of needless controversy tends to kick up everywhere that The Trans Question arises-- all the more reason imo to strongly avoid getting into discussion of personal characteristics, but I get that not everyone feels that to be natural behavior for themselves).

Answer (score 27):

This is a considerable improvement.

But it still raises a barrier for people who deny that genders beyond the binary ones actually exist.

This is a barrier which won't hinder me since I am favourable to neopronouns. But I have to oppose raising it. Not just because it opens the way to other barriers which may eventually bar my way. But because I try to respect everyone when possible, even those with ideas I oppose. Respect only has merit when aimed at those you disagree with. If a middle ground can be found, like gender-neutral speech which neither affirms not denies identity, then I'd rather meet them there than not at all. More so when what we are discussing is how to split std::string.

Consider the following exchange between Odeen (who states xe as preferred pronoun in xyr profile), and Tritt (who denies genders beyond the binary ones but has never stated so in SE). Both have read each others' profiles and are aware of preferences.

> *Odeen*: How can I split a std::string?
>   *Tritt*: Use this algorithm which uses strstr
>   *Odeen*: Your answer would work for a C-String but I am asking about std::string
>   *Tritt*: You may still apply it by using c_str

"You" and "Your" have been used, which means that neither person has acknowledged, accepted or rejected the gender identity of the other person. Preferred pronouns have not been used, such issue was just not relevant to the discussion.

As far as I understand them, the previous exchange is fine both in the official and the improved FAQs and nobody is going to be suspended. People are allowed in Stack Exchange to talk with each other without acknowledging gender identity as long as they use the 2nd person. But such possibility does not exist for 3rd person singular.

Consider this exchange where Dua also participates.

> *Odeen*: How can I split a std::string?
>   *Tritt*: Use this algorithm which uses strstr
>   *Dua*: @Tritt Your answer would work for a C-String but Odden is using a std::string so strstr would not work for xem.
>   *Tritt*: @Dua They may still apply it by using c_str

Tritt here is running afoul of A1 and A18 of this improved FAQ. Which means suspension when he clarifies that it is intentional and not a mistake after being contacted by a moderator acting on a flag.

Using xe would imply acknowledging xyr gender identity, which he does not and thus would be a lie. Using he, she or he/she would be impolite, which he also does not want. Using other phrasing would mean wording things in ways he would not usually do in order to avoid acknowledging xyr gender identity, which the FAQ disallows. Despite his own opinions Tritt does not want to go out of his way to deny xyr gender identity. Neither does he want to go out of his way to affirm xyr gender identity.

He wishes to always speak gender-neutral in SE, just as he does in 2nd person. He will also use they when referring to people like himself who prefer he as a pronoun.

**But neither the official FAQ nor this improved FAQ allow remaining gender-neutral in the presence of stated pronoun preferences when using the 3rd person singular.**

Comment: meeting in the middle isn't good enough for some

Comment: "Despite his own opinions Tritt does not ... go out of his way to deny xyr gender identity" yes, he does.

Comment: This is definitely a situation SE should consider, but I’m not sure how to solve it without giving people a religious exception to the rules. Is your suggestion to always allow the gender-neutral “they”?

Comment: Aside from all the gender considerations, use of neopronouns will introduce lack of clarity, especially on technical sites.  The large majority of people are completely unfamiliar with these words.  In your example: "Your answer would work for a C-String ... strstr would not work for xem."; most people's reaction will be "what is a xem?; is it a programming construct I'm not familiar with?"  This is an aspect that hasn't been addressed, that may be an unintended consequence.

Comment: @ScottHannen Well, the reason it’s so long is that everyone complained that the original FAQ was unclear, had too many loopholes, and didn’t address some people’s key concerns. It would be nice if the 1 sentence that’s actually in the CoC was enough, but I think the past week here makes it clear that it isn’t.

Comment: @fixer1234 Changing society so that such unfamiliar words become familiar is something I view as worthy the inconvenience. They are still not 2nd nature to me so I have to check the table when writing that. Much as I had to first write in spanish and then translate to english years ago. I was not able to think directly in english much as I am still not able to think directly in neopronouns. So I favour SE promoting these neopronouns but also want to avoid alienating people not willing to make the effort as long as we all can remain polite despite our differences.

Comment: @divibisan Yes, having a 3rd person singular pronoun which is always allowed in SE just as "you" is always allowed for 2nd person is what I would suggest. "They" is a good candidate, but I am fine with any pronoun which can be assigned the same meaning to 3rd person singular as "you" has for 2nd person singular.

Comment: @divibisan - I don't think that's why everybody complained. I don't think anyone said, "I don't like this, but if you write me a Declaration of Independence-sized dissertation that will make it better." When people hear that we came up with thirty more rules (I'm sorry, FAQs} on this one subject, *they will mock us epically.* It's comical, like something out of the movie Brazil. If I was making this up as a joke I would have said 20.

Comment: What’s wrong with `“Dua: @Tritt Your answer would work for a C-String but it won’t work for a std::string.”`?

Comment: @ColleenV The phrase which runs afoul of A1 and A18 is by Tritt, not by Dua. It is `“Tritt: @Dua They may still apply it by using c_str”`. Tritt is using the pronoun "They" in reference to Odeen despite xem stating a preference for "Xe".

Comment: @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos Sorry, I didn’t finish my comment and didn’t realize I hit enter. That conversation can be had without needing personal pronouns at all. The first part of the sentence refers to “CString” why does the second part refer to Odeen? `“std::string can be converted into a CString using c_str(), so that’s not an issue.”`

Comment: When a large group of people are suddenly exposed to something of which they did not previously have much knowledge (or even an awareness of the existence), of course there are going to be a lot of questions. It's like somebody had suddenly discovered a fundamentally new area in a science, or completely rewritten a core structure in a programming language or sports ruleset or constitutional law. Acting like it's a problem to have a big new thing is not helpful to understanding it, and frankly, being mocked by someone who doesn't bother to try understanding doesn't mean much. @ScottHannen

Comment: @Nij - I'm not sure if you're reading what I'm saying or just scanning for certain words. Anyway, if this is like a new programming language or constitution (your comparisons, not mine) then it obviously doesn't belong in a FAQ. We use tags and entire sites for those sorts of things. Being nice is great, but no one is going to study how to use words for a specific group the way they learn a programming language. It's almost as if you're agreeing with me about how impractical that is. I'm disengaging from this. I've said my part. There's just too many other things in the world to follow.

Comment: This whole business about whether multiple genders exist is pretty irritating since I don't think anyone's actually disputing the material circumstances at all. Surely we could all agree on the set of ways people are born, and the set of way people can become after birth through various means, physically. (And if someone didn't, we could be called upon to manifest, and conclusively manifest, an example thereof.) And the same should be able to be carried out in terms of what describing other people's pronoun desires-- no one is arguing whether anybody WANTS to be called "they" or not. (cont)

Comment: (cont) So it seems that the real argument is not about what "exists" or not, but the manner in which various words should be used. Ie should they correspond in some manner to one's secondary sex characteristics, and if so how will such information be obtained, and when will the inquiry be consider sufficient to have made a reasonable attempt at appropriate determination? (And what of the abnormal cases of secondary sex characteristics? Because that's what medical transition results in, so that is partially what this is about. You wind up post-natally intersex, essentially.)

Comment: English has three animate pronouns: masculine (he), feminine (she), and non-specific (they). But the non-specific "they" covers all uses. If a person says they are (insert gender here), then they are to be believed, but I fear that exclusive use of "they" (as a superclass of all other possible pronouns) may be punished here. I strongly believe that it is _not_ misgendering to refer to someone (e.g. someone who uses "xe") by a more general pronoun. Is that view fundamentally wrong somehow?

Answer (score 25):

> **A.** By participating here you're agreeing to treat others with politeness. That includes not complaining that they're idiots (even if you sincerely think they are, and even if you're right). It also includes not misgendering them, however sincerely.

In the interests of intelligibility, I would consider it a great improvement to reword this so as to avoid the neologism *misgendering*. Two weeks ago I had never encountered this word. I've had to try to figure out what it means from context, and I'm not convinced that it's been used consistently by everyone in the recent meta discussions. The code of conduct and its FAQ should be clearly understood by everyone with a working grasp of English (say, Cambridge First Certificate), not just a subset of native speakers.

Comment: I think it might be a good idea to include a definition (possibly in a tool-tip or popup) since this may be the first time some people encounter these words.

Comment: The word "misgendering" is an important one, but it may actually be a pretty reasonable accessibility feature to define it in-place. Both for ESL speakers and people who are new. (Edit: yeah, concur with divibisan. On-hover might help.)

Comment: In which case what would be a better, simpler word or phrase?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek maybe "not mis-stating their gender"?

Comment: @divibisan, don't forget that mobile UI doesn't have hovering.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek, I'd prefer to leave that to people who have a crystal clear idea of what the word means.

Comment: @MonicaCellio Doesn't this have the problem that for people who are deliberately "misgendering", say, out of some religious belief, that they won't accept that they are misgendering at all? After all, "I'm just saying it the way it is." It's like asking someone not to say racist things - it doesn't work because no one believes themselves to be racist.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro I don't follow. If somebody says "I'm a man", using "she" is misgendering. If someone says "I'm non-binary", using "he" or "she" is misgendering. Knowingly doing that is rude. But avoiding using gendered language *at all* isn't *mis*gendering because you didn't gender at all. And if you use the same approach with everybody, you're not singling anyone out for special treatment and it's not discriminatory. I don't care *why* you do it; I know that some people avoid saying anything about Jews because they're antisemitic, but I have neither the power nor responsibility to fix that.

Comment: SE should be policing actions, not (assumed) intent.

Comment: It might not be a problem at all; I'm just theorizing. I thought I would mention it because it seems like a "technically correct" argument that could be advocated by trolls, but that has never worked in the past even without the current CoC.

Comment: @MarioCarniero, I'm not aware of any religious belief that requires adherents to treat others with disrespect. I say this as a devout Christian. You don't need to have respect, in the sense that you don't need to actually *feel* respect, but it is essential to *treat* people with respect. It's neither Christian nor ethical to treat people with disrespect.

Comment: @MaxA. (For the record, I agree entirely with Monica's position here. My goal is to find a way to say this without political overtones.) I think that as long as we say "treat others with respect", there is no problem with this being broadly appealing, but it's not particularly specific about gender stuff. If we use the term "misgendering", then there are two ways to read it: (1) referring to someone with a gender they deny; (2) referring to someone with a gender other than the one they are. The version we want to police is (1), which does not involve intent at all. ...

Comment: ... But for better or worse (1) doesn't really positively assert the trans position here, and I would assume that Aza objects to it. I think the natural reading of the term "misgendering" is (2), but for those that believe that gender is innate and defined at birth, (1) and (2) are different things, and we need to specifically express that even if you believe you are following (2), if you violate (1) that's not okay because you are not being nice. But what we must avoid is calling respectful conscientious objectors Bad People in the CoC, because that will only cause strife.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro You can believe that gender is defined innately at birth and still use the pronouns people request for themselves. I genuinely don't understand the problem. My religion compels me to object to Islam, Judaism, Hinduism, and every other world religion save Christianity. But if someone calls himself a Muslim, a Jew, or a Hindu, I call them that as well. Likewise, if someone claims she is a woman, I'll call her that. She's not asking me to sleep with her, so I don't care what she was born as.

Comment: @CurtJ.Sampson yeah, but I was talking about treating everyone the same -- if you use Bob's pronoun but not Alice's that's a problem, but if you don't use *any* of them, it shouldn't offend a reasonable person assuming good intent.

Comment: @MaxA. My point was not about the position, but about the wording. Why not put that in the FAQ: "Use the pronouns people request for themselves." It's straightforward, accurate to enforcement, and doesn't beg any political questions. The downside is that it's too direct - it's not supposed to be "compelled speech" but rather to be taken as a recommendation. Surrounding wording can make that more clear.

Comment: @MonicaCellio I think that once Bob has explicitly asked you to refer to him as "he" instead of "they," refusing to do so is rude. My sense is that you disagree strongly with this. If you don't, you should make that clear.

Comment: @CurtJ.Sampson no, that's not what I'm saying.  If Bob asks for "he" and Alice asks for "she" and Lee asks for "they", then it's appropriate to either use all of those or use *none* of them.  Don't call people what they don't want to be called (of course!), but you might not even need to use a pronoun at all, depending on your writing style.  That's my point.

Comment: @Monica I'm confused now, because it sounds then as if you _do_ agree with SO's newly explicit policy: when someone asks for a specific pronoun, you will use it when you need a pronoun, and you will not go through language contortions to avoid the need for a pronoun in those cases. In other words, you do agree with what some people are calling "compelled language" (which I think is an accurate, if probably slanted, term for this).

Comment: *When using pronouns*. But the original draft, and now the FAQ, said you must use pronouns. My point is that my natural writing style *doesn't do that*. They fired me because I want to keep doing that. I'm not discriminating in doing so.

Comment: @MaxA. I don't think your analogy is quite on point. It doesn't make sense to object to a Hindu calling themselves a Hindu regardless of whether or not you object to the religion itself. But if they call themselves a Christian and then go on to talk about how they worship Vishnu, you might have objections to their self-characterization.

Comment: @user259412 Don't use conservatism as an excuse to treat people with disrespect. I'm as anti liberal as it gets, but I'm not a bigot.

Comment: @DM If they call themselves Christians, then they are.

Comment: @user259412, this discussion has got *way* off topic. If you or others want to continue it, please create a chat room and just leave a link.

Comment: @CurtJ.Sampson, *"I'm confused now, because it sounds then as if you do agree with SO"*. This is exactly the problem. It appears that Monica and SO have been talking at cross purposes, Monica has always remained entirely reasonable, and was just trying to clear up some points of confusion in the new policy, but it seems SO have gone out of their way to assume bad intent, because they're so focused on looking for bigots, that they're seeing them everywhere. False positives are a very dangerous thing, it seems that SO need to go back to the drawing board on their bigot algorithm.

Answer (score 19):

Thank you for your work. I'll reply as a member of the following group:

> People concerned by the "compelled speech" aspects of the CoC and its associated FAQ: is this sufficiently non-constraining?

My answer to that is **no**.

You're further saying:

> So of course I wonder whether any policies on this contentious issue would be more broadly acceptable to the community while still addressing the issues the revised CoC and the FAQ were intended to address.

My answer to that is "most likely no".

The issues I have with the CoC aren't that it's badly worded and needs a better tone (which you have managed to achieve for the FAQ). It's that the FAQ gives us a mandatory interpretation of the CoC that basically means that people who disagree with SE, Inc's opinion on "harming people" and their thoughts on how to be more welcoming and more inclusive are no longer welcome to participate without warping *their* identity.

I've thought a great deal about this (so much that I've considered asking a very extensive question about it). The only way you could salvage the current CoC would be to throw away the official FAQ and write a less authoritorian one that doesn't make blanket statements about what is harmful to any specific group of people while staying silent about everyone else. In fact, it shouldn't make blanket statements about what is hurtful at all.

Another option would be to ditch the FAQ and let people come to their own conclusions about how to interpret the CoC, which by itself I wouldn't consider to be a problem if people's actions were continually assumed to be in good faith. The community could then work out a modus vivendi over time. Of course, this would require a much better handling of CoC violations than how Monica's alleged violation was treated. With Monicas case still unresolved, the new CoC is frankly meaningless for me.

Comment: I am a bit surprised to read this. This proposal looks way less authoritarian to me and at least acknowledges that there can be legitimate concerns and even a conflict of values and gives some consideration to such issues. It is a significant improvement compared to the plain disregard we have in the official FAQ, IMO.

Comment: I agree it's an improvement, but not in the parts that I really care about. Maybe [my answer here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/335316/626958) will make my issues clearer.

Comment: @Goyo Golden cage is still a cage.

Comment: I think you should link to your other answer directly within this answer.  I couldn't understand your point in this answer until I read that other answer.  Now I fully get where you're coming from.

Comment: _"and let people come to their own conclusions about how to interpret the CoC"_ - does that include moderators, because if they interpret it how they like, its going to be a horrorshow. And if they mods do know how to interpret it, we should know that so we can do the same.

Answer (score 16):

Overall, I think this is well written and a good summary of the spirit of the changes! The only issue I have with it is this section:

> **Q.** If someone is non-binary, does it really matter whether I call them "ey" or "they" or "xe" or some other gender-neutral pronoun? Do I really have to handle dozens of different pronouns?
>   **A.** Many non-binary people will be OK with whatever non-binary pronoun you prefer for them -- if in doubt, ask.

This could be interpreted to say it's okay for User1 to say "Actually, I go by xe/xem pronouns", and User2 to respond "I don't like those, can I call you they/them instead?" (which I believe would be considered rude, as it's (an attempt to) reject User1's pronouns).

So I'd suggest rewording to make that more clear, maybe something like:

> **Q.** If someone is non-binary, does it really matter whether I call them "ey" or "they" or "xe" or some other gender-neutral pronoun? Do I really have to handle dozens of different pronouns?
>   **A.** Many non-binary people will be OK with whatever non-binary or gender-neutral pronoun you prefer -- but if they request a specific pronoun, use that for them going forward. If in doubt, ask.

Comment: My experience with non-binary people is that the usual reaction to "Can I use 'they' instead?" would be "Sure, that works too", with a large minority saying "No, 'xe' only, please", and almost no one considering the question rude. Might be an issue with clutter/repeated requests, though.

Comment: I don't doubt you, but I'm still uncomfortable with wording that could be taken as encouraging users to question someone's stated pronouns.. it can feel very unaccepting (you wouldn't ask someone who said "I'm a 'she'" if you can use "he" instead!), so I'd rather just trust people to give the options they're ok with up front. You make a good point about repeated requests too, especially since we talk to new users all the time online it can really add up and make someone feel "othered".

Comment: I think you’re both right, but since our goal here is to reduce ambiguities, I feel like Em C makes a good point.

Answer (score 16):

This is a very good start, but Q14 categorically excludes Caleb, a moderator with religious beliefs, from moderating a site he founded about his religion, because of those very religious beliefs. That is the opposite of inclusive. SE shouldn't have second class citizens.

To be clear, [he's not asking to be allowed to call people what they don't want to be called](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6718/brothers-i-must-go). He's just asking for being allowed to disengage or find middle ground if he needs to.

I've posted a [proposal](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/335964/changing-the-code-of-conduct-to-be-more-inclusive) that attempts to address this concern and also addresses bigotry based on gender identity more broadly than the current CoC.

*(Edited to add which question excludes Caleb and that's he's not asking to call people by pronouns they don't like.)*

Comment: I don't think anything in my proposal excludes a moderator with religious beliefs from moderating. Not unless their beliefs specifically forbid them to (e.g.) call a trans woman "she"; I don't know of any religion that imposes such a requirement on its believers. In any case, I am fairly sure that no position that _doesn't_ explicitly forbid "mispronouning" would be acceptable to SE management.

Comment: @Gareth: according to [Caleb](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/users/30/caleb), the recent changes are "enforcing conformity to ideologies openly antagonistic to [his] beliefs". Given that he was willing to resign the moderatorship of a site he helped found over it, I'll take his word for it..

Comment: The trouble is that there's a lot of scope for equivocation there. Does "conformity" just mean "having to use one set of pronouns rather than another"? Are "his beliefs" specifically ones that are in some sense imposed on him by his religion, or does it just mean beliefs he happens to have that he thinks of as religious? Because if all it comes down to is "I think this person is a man and don't want to have to refer to them as 'she', and I think of that as a religious matter" then I don't think it's fair to say that it's SE "categorically excluding" Caleb rather than [...continues]

Comment: ... Caleb choosing to walk away. I'd like to know whether people complaining that calling trans women "she" violates their religious principles feel the same way about calling ships "she", or about the German word for "girl" being neuter; I can't recall anyone ever saying they have a problem with either of those things, or any of the other everyday cases in which there's a mismatch between the words you're expected to use about someone or something and what you might actually think that person's or thing's gender truly is.

Comment: Incidentally, there's an important point here: neither the CoC nor the official SE FAQ nor my proposal makes any demand that anyone believe or express any particular thing about anyone's gender! They say "use the pronouns people ask for", and that's all. If someone says "I'm a man; please refer to me as 'she'" then SE policy is that we're to refer to that person as "she"; as a result, using particular pronouns to refer to someone _is not_, as such, a statement about their gender. Of course, the most common reason why someone will ask for particular pronouns [...continues]

Comment: ... is because they want to be referred to by pronouns that _do_ match their (internal, felt) gender identity. But we don't need to care _why_ they've asked for those pronouns.

Comment: I should be a little more precise: if someone makes it clear that they identify as (say) male and you go out of your way to talk about (say) "women, such as X", then you're failing to be polite and respectful and you're likely to get into trouble. But that's just not a thing that anyone has to do on SE, and all you need to do to avoid trouble is to refrain from being gratuitously dickish. A person's religion might oblige them to believe that X is a woman, but I don't believe anyone's religion requires them to _point it out obnoxiously_.

Comment: Consider a game where different players are all allowed to choose a colour as the name. It might be *X*'s religious belief that only red and blue and yellow exist, but if *Y* chooses to be called green or pink or grey, *X* doesn't need to agree that these colours exist, or even that *Y* is actually in fact green (pink, grey, ...) to refer to *Y* by that name, and *X* definitely doesn't need to vociferously argue that Pink is really Red or that Green must pick either Yellow or Blue. And if *X* doesn't like using arbitrary words to describe people because of an irrelevant ... [1/2]

Comment: [2/2] ... because of an irrelevant group of things that happen to share some of the words, well, *X* is truly free to not do that, and not be involved. But it's not the policy of allowing people to choose their own colour that has excluded *X*, it's *X*'s refusal to let go of this small part of control over other people's choices. And if *X*'s job requires them to let it go in order to effectively achieve the goals they are placed in that job for, they have only their own beliefs to consider, and make a decision for themselves based on it. @rockwalrus

Comment: @Gareth: Caleb's resignation is linked in the answer and addresses many of your comments. I cannot paste all the relevant passages in this tiny space. Suffice it to say that he's willing to avoid expressing disagreement in several ways and to work out any actual issues that occur with the other person like two grown adults should do, but that's not enough to keep from being explicitly disqualified by your Q14.

Comment: I would be happy to do my best to explain why some people feel their religious beliefs preclude then from using certain pronouns in certain circumstances, but you'd probably benefit more from asking someone who believes that way directly. At any rate that is more suited to chat than the comments here.

Comment: I think, depending on how it was interpreted, Q14 could allow a uniform policy of avoiding pronouns altogether, which might satisfy some people. If that was clarified, do you think that could be an acceptable compromise?

Comment: @divibisan: You'd have to ask Caleb directly, but from his writings my guess is yes.

Comment: For this we'll have to broaden the scope away from pronouns and ask what sorts of things religious exemption can be claimed for, generally. US law goes through this same question all the time and there's a lot of interesting precedent there. // Subtopics I've heard so far: active vs passive, balance of burdens.

Comment: building off of my previous comment-- by this logic, any stackexchange about a religion should basically be free to (and most likely will) conduct itself according to the tenants of that religion, yes? does that also mean a set of norms can be created for each religion's stackexchange as though it's its own "nation"?

Answer (score 14):

I want to reiterate the sentiment from my comment: this post is great. Instead of feeling like I'm being attacked for not having the same groupthink as Stack Overflow, I feel like there is space for me to disagree and not be banned.

Here are my remaining issues with this proposal:

1. We need to be clear if neutral third-party pronouns are available to use if someone explicitly mentions a pronoun. Previously several official comments made it seem like this was a violation that will get you banned.

   > Q11: If I’m uncomfortable with a particular pronoun, can I just avoid using it?
   >
   > We are asking everyone to use all stated pronouns as you would naturally write. Explicitly avoiding using someone’s pronouns because you are uncomfortable is a way of refusing to recognize their identity and is a violation of the Code of Conduct.

   > Q16: May I use they/them by default?
   >
   > Yes, but be prepared to make adjustments if so requested.
   >
   > From @Catija (staff) If you use they/them by default, that's fine. If someone requests that you use other pronouns and you immediately continue to use they/them for that person, we may point it out to you. "Penalized" in most cases is generally going to be as minor as a comment being removed or adjusted to meet the request of the person being spoken about. Only in extreme cases of repeated requests to change, will it lead to a mod message or suspension.

   This one of the main places where my speech compulsion fears spread out of. We need to make sure the new FAQ is clear if this stance will be maintained.
2. As others have mentioned, a lot of these ideas and terminologies are new and unfamiliar to many. It's important to have lots of links out to definitions.
3. For Q17

   > If something is obviously unreasonable -- e.g., if they are demanding to be worshipped or asking you to use obscenities when referring to them -- then you are welcome to act accordingly.

   We need to be more explicit here. What does act accordingly mean? Can I ignore it? My big fear here is that I don't know the boundary between real and unreasonable. This is the same thing I spelled out in [my post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/334974/224667) on the original FAQ.

   Note that even though the chances of any individual user running across this scenario is low, we should still be explicit about what the rules are here. We're trying to define the CoC here - the foundations upon which we build the rest of our community. If we don't get things right here, it only goes downhill.
4. > Q29. There are still edge-cases that aren't clear to me.
   >
   > A. There always will be. Use your common sense, be nice, assume good faith but be prepared to revise that assumption in the face of the evidence, and you are unlikely to go too far wrong.

   This one feels so nice, and I want to agree with it so much, but it unfortunately has problems that I think are indicative of community divide here. For starters, common sense is a loaded phrase nowadays. Your common sense and mine will have variations. Likely tiny, but across a large, international population it will be wider.

   Then there is assume good faith. There is a whole post [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/335026/we-need-assume-good-intent-back-in-the-code-of-conduct) that delves into it much more, but it seems like Stack Exchange now has a problem with this phrase. We can't have it in the FAQ but not in the CoC, it's too confusing. I'd love to have it in both, and personally think it makes marked improvements in user interactions, but this "common sense" measure is now controversial.

Overall I want to again reiterate: **this is amazing work, thank you**

Comment: Your proposals seem to leave it wide open for someone to marginalize others by using preferred pronouns for all but them. E.g., "Alice" prefers "she" but always gets called "they" even though Bob, Charles and David, who all prefer "he" do get called "he." That seems to me clearly targeted insulting behaviour; how do you deal with that and the argument that it should be allowed because asking for "she" for Alice or "they" for Bob, Charles and David would be "compelling" speech?

Comment: @CurtJ.Sampson Good questions. This type of behavior is inherently self-documenting. If someone uses they only for one particular person/class, but everywhere else regularly uses more specific pronouns, then a surface investigation will reveal this. This can be shown factually, quantitatively and empirically. Compared to 'is this pronoun real or a troll? I guess I just have to hope the CM is in a good mood today'. I think its an all-around improvement.

Comment: @DavidGrinberg but what sort of computational cost are we incurring with all this? Mods are going to be spending their time reading people's comment histories for their pronoun usage? It does not seem like an appropriate use of time to me at all.

Comment: @Ejaz Agreed, it is an expensive form of investigation. That is one of the reasons I believe this entire policy is bad - it is impractical to devise intent from our interactions here. However if the SE overlords insist on having this policy, we can (hope) that the number of instances that this type of investigation will be low, so the expense of it will be manageable.

Answer (score 12):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

This is something I'd been wondering but it didn't feel important enough to post, and now it does with this effort to rewrite the FAQ:

> We're asking that *when someone indicates what pronouns should be used to refer to them*, you do as they say.

What constitutes the italicized part seems ambiguous, both in the original FAQ and this proposal: whether it's when the other person's profile states pronouns or when there is a direct communication about pronouns.

Assuming it's the latter and you don't need to look up user profiles proactively, [as stated by a CM](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334900/official-faq-on-gender-pronouns-and-code-of-conduct-changes/335182#comment1101050_335182) elsewhere, I'd clarify some wording in the proposal as:

> **Q**. I want to let people know what my pronouns are. What should I do?
>   **A**. Put them in the "About me" section of your profile *for those who want to proactively look up your pronouns. Do not assume others to have done so, however. When someone uses a pronoun you're uncomfortable with, let them know about your pronouns directly.*

*(Italicized parts are my additions.)*

And add a new question:

> **Q**. Am I expected to check somebody's profile before I refer to them using a pronoun?
>   **A**. No.

or if this isn't exactly what's desirable, at least with the same level of unambiguity.

This clarification might sound like common sense that doesn't need to be stated, but having very unambiguous and clear descriptions of the expected behavior helps assuage anxiety when you don't have context on social expectations. Related: [How should I deal with the new CoC as non-native English speaker?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/335225/how-should-i-deal-with-the-new-coc-as-non-native-english-speaker)

---

This'll need to be rewritten again if SE adds pronouns to user cards or some such though.

Comment: Instead of tweaking those two questions (which I felt were adequately answered in the original post), I would recommend just adding an additional question instead – something like: **Q: Am I expected to check somebody's profile before I refer to them using a pronoun?** (I think that's the basic question you are trying to address with your edits.)

Comment: @J.R. It makes sense to replace the second with that one, thanks (edited answer). For the first one, if the only way mentioned is the "About me" section, it implies that is sufficient to indicate pronouns, which in turn implies others are expected to check profiles. This will contradict with the admission that you don't need to check profiles. Do you think the additions to the first question's answer are not necessary?

Comment: I liked the way the original keeps things simple: **Q.** _I want to let people know what my pronouns are. What should I do?_ **A.** _Put them in the "About me" section of your profile._ That's wonderfully succinct and elegant.

Comment: @J.R. To make sure: is it that 'succinct and elegant' is preferred over 'contradictory and misleading [to some]' (which I'm using synonymously to "ambiguous"), or is the original not contradictory nor misleading in the first place?

Answer (score 12):

The problem with the CoC change is not that the company "didn't explain it well enough". Therefore no amount of FAQ is going to fix the issue. They could post 20, or 40, or even 100 FAQ, the problem would remain the same: an attempt to force compelled speech on people (most of which aren't even native speakers) that

- is completely contrary to the way SE sites have worked before (focus on the question/answer, not the person), and
- *will* be weaponized in the future.

Besides, at the point where an FAQ for a single additional sentence in the CoC reached double digits, any reasonable person would have realized that there is something fundamentally wrong with the change.

Comment: I think that for _some_ users no possible interpretation of the new CoC will be acceptable, and indeed for them no possible FAQ will help anything; but that for _some other_ users the new CoC isn't a problem in itself but the FAQ suggested (rightly or wrongly) that SE's attitude to it was too strict or coercive for them. A kinder gentler FAQ might be evidence of a better attitude (either poorly expressed by the other FAQ, or changed since the other FAQ).

Comment: IMO their FAQ clearly expresses the intent behind the CoC change, which is why I believe that this *will* be weaponized. Also, the point in my last paragraph still stands regardless of whether people disagree fundamentally or just slightly with their FAQ: whenever a supposedly inclusive sentence raises questions in the double digits there is something fundamentally wrong with that sentence.

Comment: I am not sure the point in your last paragraph is correct: it could simply be that the change in question raises issues _with which many people are not familiar_.

Comment: What do you mean by *weaponized* in this context? Can you elaborate a little bit? E.g., what would be a possible ***example*** future scenario?

Answer (score 10):

You proposed:

> Q. What if someone wants to be referred to as "the Great and Mighty One" or by an obscenity or something?
> A. If something is obviously unreasonable -- e.g., if they are demanding to be worshipped or asking you to use obscenities when referring to them -- then you are welcome to act accordingly....

I would propose that we be a little more clear as to when a request is "unreasonable" or in bad faith. We could express it somewhat like this:

> Generally, all other things being equal, a person's stated pronouns are presumed unreasonable or in bad faith when such terms fall into any of the following categories:
>
> - Names, such as "Sue", "Bob", or "Godzilla"
> - Titles, such as "King", "President", "Airman Second Class", "Skipper", "High Priestess", "Bachelor of Arts", or "Professor"
> - Forms of address, such as "sir", "Your Grace", "Her Imperial Majesty", or "holy and exalted one"
> - Descriptors of personal, professional, ethnic, or social roles, such as "gamer", "Chinaman", "quarterback", "Irish taxi driver" or "1337 Appalachian warez haxor d00d"
> - Unpronounceable or random gibberish, such as "asdpofasm34534" or "5u034spgsdfg"
> - Mottos, slogans, taglines, advertisements, or similar messages, such as "Jesus saves", "Eat at Joe's", "Vote Cthulhu 2020", or "Bite me Skinner"
> - Common, known troll terminology, such as Apache attack helicopter designations or obscene words
>
> We aren't trying to say that you can't have the pronoun you consider your own. We *are* saying that it needs to be a *pronoun*. If your pronoun already exists in the language in some other role, we need to understand the background behind it and *why* it is the correct pronoun for you.
>
> If you have made up your own new pronoun, it is important to keep in mind *why* that is. Pronouns, in English as well as many other languages, are intended as generic *substitutes* for a name in cases where disclosing or repeating the name is not feasible or desirable. If your pronoun is intended to refer solely to *you*, then it is probably a *name* and not a pronoun. You are free to change your username to reflect this name, or post it in your profile as a nickname or an alternative or preferred name.

In response to comments, no, I don't actually expect to see actual pronoun-background stories offered in defense to accusations of pronoun trolling, but I want to *leave the door open* in case there is a situation/gender/identity that *I didn't consider* or am not aware of. I expect 99%+ of cases of "Hi, my pronoun is Hail Our Lord and Master Jon Skeet the Exalted Fifth-Gender Attack Helicopter Let Us Serially Upvote! His Holy Posts-sfgsdfg-em" to be treated as obvious trolling and dealt with as such. I have dealt with way too many such trolls. This system does *not* apply to things like, "Well, this person doesn't look like a she, so it's trolling". That's where assumption of *good faith* prevails, and one would be expected to use those pronouns.

Comment: Using someone's name over and over happens in real life. I had this guidance counselor in grad school who for some reason could not be persuaded to stop calling me "he" in memos (I was born a female and was presenting as female) simply because of my name being unisex/masc. It was causing my whole department to think I was transgender. It finally reached the point where I grew angry and sent a strongly worded email to them and their superior, and after that they used my full legal name in every pronoun slot.

Comment: "If your pronoun already exists in the language in some other role, we need to understand the background behind it and why it is the correct pronoun for you." //

This is too intrusive and the overhead is too high. Are users supposed to submit their backstory?

Comment: @Ejaz ideally not, that is only for cases where there is significant reason to believe that the person's stated pronouns are not in good faith, for example someone claiming, "My pronouns are idiot/idiotem/belonging to that idiot", or "Hi, I'm an Apache attack helicopter (Apache/Unto the Holy Whirling One/Apache-installed)". *That's* what we are trying to avoid - major trolling or complete misunderstandings of the nature of pronouns.

Comment: I agree that such trolling is likely to be sadly common, as I have seen it occur before. I suppose a clearer question/common would be: through what mechanism will these be reviewed? Do you think such a system might be computationally costly or unwieldy? And, do you anticipate cases where a background story could "justify" something that seemed prima facie bogus (hell, it would still *look* bogus to passersby, so the effect upon them would be the same)?

Comment: @ejaz no, I don't actually expect to see actual stories, but I want to leave the door open in case there is a situation/gender/identity that I didn't consider. I expect 99.5% of cases of "Hi, my pronoun is Hail Our Lord and Master Jon Skeet the Exalted Fifth-Gender Attack Helicopter Let Us Serially Upvote! His Holy Posts-sfgsdfg-em" to be treated as obvious trolling and dealt with as such. I have dealt with *way* too many such trolls. This system does *not* apply to things like, "Well, this person doesn't *look* like a she, so it's trolling". That's where assumption of *good* faith prevails.

Answer (score 9):

If I may be so bold to cite [one of my answers from a few years back](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7340/29904) when RPG SE had an issue:

> ### All pronouns are neutral and should be enforced as such.
>
> I personally think that nobody should be harassed, or be in the red
>   for guessing wrong on how someone wants to be called, and this should
>   extend to RPG.SE. no pronoun should have a negative connotation,
>   whether being misused or otherwise.
>
> ### Unless otherwise stated, all questions are gender agnostic.
>
> This means that 'he/him', 'they/their', and 'she/her' pronouns are
>   correct, and none of them are incorrect. Good answers simply maintain
>   continuity, and don't switch to refer to the same people. The answer
>   may decide to change pronouns if the answerer wishes, but there is no
>   *correct* gender. An answer should never be *wrong* because the gender is 'incorrect', because no gender option is incorrect. If the OP puts
>   in the post that this is a gender-issue, then correct pronouns should
>   be used.

In short, unless it's a gender issue, pronouns are not relevant

Comment: I endorse this (with the weight of my "trans vote", if that matters).

Answer (score 8):

I would suggest changes to this also.

> Q10. Am I forbidden to express my opinion about this? A. In most
>   contexts your opinions about gender, whatever they are, are off topic.
>   In contexts where those opinions are actually relevant -- as they
>   might be in, say, a discussion on Philosophy.SE -- you are welcome to
>   express those opinions so long as you do so respectfully and politely.
>   **But please be aware that many things you might want to say may be
>   extremely distressing to some readers, and you should try to minimize
>   that distress.**

Everything can be extremely distressing to some readers. I, nor you, can never hope to control or predict the distressedness of others. Furthermore, there can be no debate without dissent, and this dissent can be distressing in and by itself. The laws protecting free speech are not useful for protecting speech that everyone agrees to. They have to exist to protect the speech that is not agreed to, and that is held most usually, by the minority.

Now, SE is not obliged to follow free speech rules, that is not my claim, but I would say that it would be a worthy objective to have - to allow dissent and to protect minority opinions - if they otherwise are in accord with the Be Nice policy (as it were)

I would rather see a sentence providing for this.

> Please be aware that dissent and disagreement has the propensity for causing distress - on this topic in particular - both when visiting such sites and voicing your views and opinions.

Comment: "I can never hope to control or predict the distressedness of others": That's why the sentence is there. It is to inform people that this is a topic likely to cause distress, so if you discuss it (in a place where such discussion is on-topic) you should use extra care. The discussion of "free speech" is a non sequiter because the sentence you highlighted doesn't limit or even discourage speech – it simply gives you a heads up that this topic can be hurtful.

Comment: It's true that anything can turn out to be distressing to someone. But some things are _predictably particularly distressing_ and it's reasonable to point out particular topics that are likely to have that problem.

Comment: @divibisan It is - as is - a plea for people to self censor based on the propensity to cause distress to anyone - which if followed to the letter - should mean no more posts at all anywhere. Thus I propose a change to a) make it a shared responsibility between those who post and those who read and b) Toning down the extremity of it and removing the reference to minimize stress (any disagreement maximizes stress - if I were to say something that is the minima of stress, I would have to go for... "I agree totally"...)

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan I agree, which is why I suggest to strengthen that part ("on this topic in particular")

Comment: “I would say that it would be a worthy objective to have - to allow dissent” — As much as recent events might make it seem otherwise, debating pronouns isn't the point of Stack Exchange. If people want to have bad opinions on this issue, they can do it somewhere where it's on-topic.

Comment: @Veedrac ...for instance on SE.Philosophy as the point suggests, no?

Comment: @StianYttervik Not really. As much as Philosophy.SE is a dumpster fire right now, its goal as a site is about neutrally relaying academic philosophy. To the extent that a question like that might still be on-topic (though I haven't found a single instance of such a question), the point of the site is about giving a holistic understanding of the debate, not a podium for people to shout about their own positions.

Comment: @StianYttervik If someone on Phil.SE wants to **neutrally talk about** positions that deny transgender people's transitioned-to pronouns, that's fine, but that doesn't also mean that it's OK to use Phil.SE to enact those opinions as a demonstration of dissent.

Comment: @divibisan that's exactly my approach: gender is not relevant. Don't make it relevant.

Answer (score 8):

For the sake of completeness and understanding, and this doesn't necessarily need to go into an FAQ, but Q6 and Q9 fail to cover a deeper objection.

If you sincerely and without malice believe in objective physical gender, or put another way you don't believe that gender does or should exist outside of congenital sex, there can be two further concerns:

1. Affirming a trans/non-binary identity can harm the subject, and society in general.
2. Being a known representative of e.g. a religious group that does (1) can mislead other members of the group as to the group's teachings.

Comment: How do you think we can address that, without making religious exceptions to all rules? It seems like there should be a way to use gender-inclusive or preferred pronouns without affirming any broader views on reality ...

Comment: @divibisan I don’t think it does need addressing. If disengagement is OK then that’s sufficient. I just wanted to point out there are positions where “it doesn’t hurt anyone to comply” doesn’t work.

Comment: @divibisan Easy! Just declare from the outset that using any given pronoun doesn't imply any agreement with any of its owners opinions about gender/sex/politics/science/religion/whatever. We should include such a public disclaimer for everyone in the FAQ itself. Anyone who wants to could then link to it if anyone forgets.

Comment: If your sincere, deeply held beliefs (religious or otherwise) prevent you from treating other people with respect in public discourse, then those beliefs are incompatible with participating on Stack Overflow / Stack Exchange. Whether or not they are malicious in nature is both unknowable and irrelevant.

Comment: Hello friend--  I "sincerely and without malice believe in objective physical gender, or put another way [...] don't believe that gender does or should exist outside of congenital sex". However, I am trans/nb. I would like to make you aware that primary and secondary sex characteristics, as well as brain chemistry-induced behavior, are altered by the application of cross-sex hormones. If I walked into a doctor's office and let them examine me head-to-toe and run every relevant test, and told them I was not trans, they would diagnose me as intersex (with a disorder of sexual development).

Comment: In fact, these changes are so pervasive and essential as to affect reproductive capacity, which is often cited as the hallmark of biological sex by laypersons. One's risks of future diseases is often (even typically) also altered to correspond to the "target sex" (ie a female taking testosterone has the heart attack risk of a cis male, and vice versa). Medically, failing to include someone's transition status in their care and documentation would likely rise to the level of legal negligence due to the extreme sex-based changes that occur. My understanding is that sexual biologists also (cont)

Comment: classify sex categories based on clusters of variable traits (ie although one trait can be predicted from another with strong certainty, that does not affect the case-by-case categorization of persons with sex traits that typically do NOT co-occur). Not talking about gender theorists or anything like that. I will accept the claim that a trans X should not be blindly considered the same as a natural-born X, despite the social convenience of calling e.g. a female-to-male transsexual with a beard, no breasts or uterus, and something strongly functionally or visually resembling a penis "a man" (c)

Comment: if you wish to take an atypically (vs convention) restrictive view of how many sex characteristics and to what degree must appear within the case. But I will not accept that such a person is appropriately called "a woman" or "female" without qualifier, as they do not medically or socially appear nor function as such, nor would be considered one by biologists specializing in the field.

Comment: Even if you reject all of the above arguments, some persons use "trans" to refer to the neuropsychiatric condition of subjective identification with the other sex, rather than having undergone a medical transition, so under that use someone's trans status is unquestionable (would you, without case-specific data, insist that someone doesn't really have schizophrenia or neuropathy of the foot even if they were diagnosed as such? I would guess not).

Answer (score 8):

One question the FAQ ought to address directly:

> **Q.** Can I disengage from an interaction to avoid using a stated pronoun?

Given my present understanding of the intent, a suitable answer might be:

> **A.** You are always welcome to disengage to avoid conflict, but be sure not to do harm when you disengage. A user who *conspicuously* disengages from conversations simply to avoid using stated pronouns could be subject to correction or sanction.

Moderators might be held to a still higher standard here than regular users, but it would still be useful to have specific advice in the FAQ.

---

#### Background

This issue was addressed by a Community Manager [in a comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334900/official-faq-on-gender-pronouns-and-code-of-conduct-changes#comment1098210_334901) (emphasis added):

> I think there's some misunderstanding! You're always welcome to **silently disengage** if that's what feels correct for you. We actually often find disengaging is the best answer when you're in a situation that makes you uncomfortable. Just be certain you **don't do harm when you disengage** by making a statement that you can not or will not comply with their request. – Catija♦ Oct 10 at 16:21

and the Code of Conduct says:

> If a situation makes it hard to be friendly, stop participating and move on.

I am not aware of official clarification on the subject of discriminatory disengagement.

Comment: I strongly disagree that any disengagement should be considered conspicuous and certain intent inferred. Forcing someone to continue engaging in a situation where they are not socially comfortable leads to disaster. As an autistic person, I promise you, once I've offended someone and the situation has escalated, the best and safest thing for everyone is for me to disengage rather than attempt to explain myself or continue on; it just makes it worse.

Furthermore inferring intent from LACK of action is inappropriate (on a user level-- if someone's a mod not doing their job, that's different).

Answer (score 8):

After reading the earlier CoC, I wasn't understanding what was this fuss about. But this thread here is very useful and clear for a non-native English speaker like me. Also the tone and clarity of the wordings used is easily understandable like mentioned by others.
This is good move in my opinion.

Answer (score 7):

My name is Squeamish Ossifrage, and I go by ‘they’.  I tend to agree with everything in [Aza's assessment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/335242): that my reaction is generally positive, and that there is room for improvement like Aza suggested.  Some additional thoughts:

A number of people have asked: *Why don't we just get rid of gendered pronouns altogether and use ‘they’ for everyone?*

This is obviously tempting, but gender is a big part of human life.  True, some of us don't like society's prescription of gender roles at all (hi!).  But some of us don't like *certain parts* of society's gender roles, like treating programming as an un-feminine thing to be done only by masculine rock star ninjas.

While there are women who justifiably prefer to conceal their gender on the internet, there are also women who vocally object—with feminine names, pronouns, and voices—to this perspective of programming as masculine and solitary, and who make themselves role models for onlookers.  (Obligatory xkcd: https://www.xkcd.com/322/)  Both approaches to attacking gender barriers are legitimate!

It is also legitimate to just be yourself, here to talk about programming or cryptography or parenting or board games or gardening or psychology, without aiming to make a point about gender or to hide from it.  And it can be instructive to observe the relative prevalence of masculine, feminine, conscientious-objector, and other personas on the site.

So while gender is fraught with social complications and multidimensional privilege differentials, and while I appreciate that anyone is welcome to choose their own name or conceal their own gender on the site—and encourage anyone who wants to, to do so!—simply erasing it by policy for everyone is no more a solution to gender issues than feigning colorblindness is a solution to racism no matter how many naive white moderates think it is.

Comment: _"While there are women who justifiably prefer to conceal their gender on the internet, there are also women who vocally object—with feminine names, pronouns, and voices—to this perspective of programming as masculine and solitary [...] Both approaches to attacking gender barriers are legitimate!"_


I don't like this characterization. You have taken the only two possibilities (using an identifiably feminine name, and not doing so) and attached an activist intent to both. Many women merely wish to discuss programming without any consideration for "attacking".

Comment: @Ejaz I didn't mean to suggest that the two stories of intent I described were exhaustive, but I agree with your assessment and I see that what I wrote wasn't clear about that.

Comment: Some *men* prefer to conceal their gender too, because of inherent social biases. Some men identify as feminists, reject patriarchal structures and gender stereotypes, and want to avoid gendered assumptions by other users when participating on a Stack site. Much less of an issue in historically male-dominated fields like IT, but a very real concern in fields where a gender analysis is relevant. Even posting this comment makes me feel unsafe because some users may inappropriately infer my gender based solely on the point I'm making! I strongly support the pronoun policy & this redrafted FAQ.

Comment: @ReinstateMonica when you say "unsafe", what do you mean? What are you concerned might happen, especially since it looks like the account you're posting on was created just for this topic (which I also should probably have done, as I don't need my entire professional network knowing my personal history...)? Good faith question.

Comment: @Ejaz Not a new a/c: if you go to my profile you'll see "Member for 3 years, 5 months". My fear is that some users might decide I must be male (because I talked about what some men prefer) and judge my posts here or elsewhere coloured by that assumption. I've *seen* that happen outside SE, where hostility and social exclusion were entirely based on the person's (male) gender. I want people on SE to respond to what I *say*, without being coloured by assumptions of who I am or what I look like. Especially when discussing the current topic! :-)

Comment: @ReinstateMonica Hmm, I had said that bc I thought I saw a single-digit reputation. I was simultaneously looking at a thread where people were discussing everyone changing their username to Reinstate Monica, and so perhaps looked at someone else's and mentally transferred that information to this thread or something-- in any case, clearly my mistake.

Comment: Anyway, I know what you mean, as I've been in a similar circumstance. But I don't approve of that usage of "unsafe", personally. It contributes to a larger pattern of (some) people calling everything violence and so on... I wouldn't ever describe someone making erroneous assumptions about me on a forum a matter of personal safety unless it was going to affect me materially in real life (including cases of substantial mental health impact). Of course if someone's talking about a matter of their safety, any admin or leader should take that very seriously-- but this usage imho is crying wolf.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're misunderstanding:

1. who "we" are; and
2. what "we" are trying to achieve.

You wrote:

> I take it that Stack Exchange Inc. wants (at least) the following things:
>
> - To have a welcoming environment where no one feels as if they're fair game for rude and marginalizing language.
> - Not to do things that result in a large fraction of the community, or of particular parts of the community (e.g., moderators), feeling alienated.

It's actually the opposite. "We" are StackExchange Inc. And what "we" are doing is creating an unwelcome environment for moderators and users who keep an open mind and a critical attitude regarding the company's behavior and policies, and it seems (and is even hinted) that the intent is making such people leave.

The whole gendered-pronoun business is being used as a Red Herring for that purpose. Statistically, it seems to barely ever come up (other than in the "don't assume my gender" variety). So really, don't sweat it, the matter is covered well enough by a general "be nice" principle. No need for a CoC for that.

Comment: Setting aside whether pronouns need to be mentioned specifically, it's not enough to have a general principle of "be nice". An earlier "be nice" S.E. page explicitly called out "bigotry of any kind", lists a few of the most important examples, and says "when in doubt, just don't." It's very useful to assure people that you're actually thinking about bigotry. Partly because there's a lot of bigotry that doesn't look like the absolute worst. There's a lot where someone thinks it's not even controversial. That framework helps push out bigotry, and hold users to account if they refuse to stop.

Comment: @sourcejedi: You're assuming that the change to the (previous) code of conduct was necessary and beneficial; I doubt that's the case - and given recent developments, my doubts have only deepened.

Answer (score -4):

I think this suggestion still makes the same main mistake that the original CoC change did. It doesn't take into account that pronouns are part of languages, not aspects of people. Gender is an aspect of a person. The association between pronouns and genders is a part of language too.

So it doesn't make sense for a person to state their supposed pronouns. A person can say what their gender is, and it's up to people to use the pronouns that, in their languages, would be correct when referring to someone of that stated gender.

Comment: Gender doesn't always imply pronouns.

Comment: But that's precisely what this post is saying: use the correct pronoun. The complication comes when the gender is neither male nor female since most languages haven't come to a shared agreement for what pronoun is correct in that situation. Therefore, the only polite thing to do is to use the one the person you are talking to suggests.

Comment: @Zoethetransgirl if there's a case where gender doesn't imply pronouns, then it would be correct to write in a gender neutral way

Comment: @Meeep no, it would be correct to use the pronouns the person prefers.

Comment: @terdon I think any language has ways to talk in a gender neutral way, so if there's a situation where neither male or female pronouns would be correct, it would make sense to make a gender neutral statement. As for what such a statement would look like, it depends on the person, some people would use "they", others "he/she", etc.

Comment: @Meeep no, actually. Many languages have gender as an integral part of every single word. There are no genderless nouns at all. In such languages (and these are many: French, Spanish, Greek, Italian...) it is impossible to speak with no gender at all. If I want to refer to the door in Spanish, I _need_ to use _la puerta_ which is feminine. While there are indeed ways of making the language used to address humans more gender neutral, such languages make it very hard if not impossible to totally remove gender from your speech or writing.

Comment: @terdon So there's no way in these languages to talk about someone of unknown/unclear gender?

Comment: @Meeep yes, as I said, there are ways when addressing a human, although as far as I know, nothing with the long history of singular *they* in English. It's just impossible to remove gender from the language entirely since all nouns are gendered.

Comment: @terdon I'm Polish, and although here words have grammatical gender too, it can be treated separately from human gender. For example, the word "person" is gendered female, but you could use "that person" about a guy, and it would be totally correct, even though the statement would be grammatically female. Is it different in the languages you mentioned? Do they say nothing at all if they have to refer to someone and they don't know that person's gender?

Comment: @Zoethetransgirl When you say that gender doesn't always imply pronouns, please understand that you appear to be using both those words to mean very different things from what they normally mean, ones unlike how the vast majority of the world uses those two words. Hence widespread confusion. That's of course your right, so please don't think I believe otherwise. But universal understanding will not come in a day.

Comment: @Meeep no, I mean exactly like what you describe in Polish. I was just pointing out that the existence of grammatical gender adds a whole extra layer of complication to the issue of genderless speech.

Comment: @terdon I don't think it really adds that much complication. Grammatical gender and human gender can be viewed separately, that's why in Poland you can say "that person" (which is grammatically female) about a male, and it's perfectly ok. Even in very gendered languages, people already have various ways to refer to someone with unknown/unclear gender, so it makes no sense to have CoC rules which interfere with that.

Comment: @Meeep It does add complication. It is widely understood that language forms your ability for thought. "Language & Cognition" is even the name of a journal. If you say "everyone should use a gender neutral pronoun" - that might be extremely unfamiliar to someone whose language is made up of only gendered nouns.

Comment: @StianYttervik I think you're actually agreeing with me, maybe I was unclear earlier. I didn't say that everyone should use a gender neutral pronoun, I said that everyone should talk in a way that would be correct in their language. If, in some language, people use gendered nouns even when referring to people of unknown gender, then that's what they should do.

Answer (score -4):

Freedom of speech has been mentioned a lot during the discussions of this issue, so I think it is important to add the following emphasis in bold:

> **Q8.** But free choice of language is important to me. This rule impairs my freedom of speech.
>   **A.** **Only the government is prohibited from restricting your freedom of speech. As a privately-owned website, Stack Exchange is allowed to set its own rules, including rules restricting certain language.** By participating here you're agreeing **to Stack Exchange's rules** to treat others with politeness. That includes not complaining that they're idiots (even if you sincerely think they are, and even if you're right). It also includes not misgendering them, however sincerely.

[Source](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/39732/10132)

Comment: You could also mention users addressing "Freedom of Expression" which grants people the right to express themselves, not restricted by a language police.

Comment: @Houseman it kinda does, actually. Such rules only refer to censorship by governments. If you come into my house and I tell you I don't like what you're saying, and kick you out if you insist on saying it, [that isn't a free speech issue](https://xkcd.com/1357/). Free speech, and freedom of expression, are simply not relevant in the context of an internet platform hosted by a private company. I am not happy with SE's compelled speech approach, but casting it as a violation of my right to free speech is just silly.

Comment: @terdon :  It's not inherently about governments at all.  If I say that you have absolute freedom of speech in my household, then I am telling you something about me as a host, not (or not only) about the local government.  Indeed, I would consider it a very serious thing to say that to a guest!  You don't have a *right* to free speech in my house, but it might (or might not) be desirable all the same.

Comment: It’s not a violation of the law in the US and other countries that protects freedom of speech. But freedom of speech is a much broader concept that goes beyond law and what the government can and cannot restrict. There’s no law requiring private institutions to grant you freedom of speech, and arguably there’s no precedent, but that doesn’t mean that there is no ideal.

Comment: Free speech is a *philosophical* concept.  Just like "no bigotry" doesn't mean "you only need to avoid the categories of discrimination explicitly forbidden by law."  This answer is nonsense.

Comment: @Wildcard How is this answer nonsense? StackExchange is free to set whatever rules they want for their website, including speech restrictions. If someone wants to violate those rules, StackExchange is allowed to take action against them.

Comment: @pacoverflow it's nonsense that "Freedom of speech only means that the government cannot restrict what you say." Just like it would be nonsense to say "Bigotry only means discrimination that is legally forbidden." I am not claiming that SE cannot legally restrict speech. I am claiming that your limited definition of "freedom of speech" is nonsense. You could state, "*The US Constitution's protection* of freedom of speech only forbids governmental restrictions on speech, not restrictions by private parties." But that is irrelevant to the statement "Free choice of language is important to me."

Comment: @Wildcard: This is a website hosted by a privately-owned corporation.  Practically-speaking, nobody has any claim to "free speech" here, because the corporation has no mandate to host *anyone's* speech.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, I don't dispute that.  However, the claim here that freedom of speech *only* means [stuff], is false.  If your comment were put in place of the entire bolded portion of this answer, that would be far more accurate (though likely unpopular as it would be belligerent in that context).  Really, **"freedom of speech" is not even a *statement*, it's a nounal phrase,** so any sentence of the form "freedom of speech means [statement]" is nonsense just in programmer terms—it's a type error.  You can't interpret a noun as a statement.

Comment: @Wildcard: It's a valid distinction, but ultimately irrelevant.  The simple fact is that free speech protections don't apply here.

Comment: Good edit. I'd drop the "only the government..." sentence completely, though. People are generally well aware of where public allowances end and private rules begin.

Comment: @Houseman I will keep it in, because I'm not so sure people are generally aware of that. If that was the case, this question might not need to be in the FAQ. I made another edit though.

Comment: @Houseman I'm just going to remove the last line, as I think that concern is covered by Q11 and Q12.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Freedom of Speech as provided through the US Constitution doesn't apply, but Freedom of Expression as a Human Right does (https://freedomhouse.org/issues/freedom-expression).

Comment: I'd suggest: Q8. "Mah freeze peach!!" A. Like many venues you are expected to maintain a minimum standard of behaviour. This is not 4chan.

Comment: This answer gets a -1 from me. **Freedom of speech is an abstract concept that does not require a government to exist.** @terdon "But it's legal for them to censor whatever they like!" is a terrible argument. Just because it isn't illegal does not mean it isn't still a bad thing. [This should be required reading.](https://i.imgur.com/8tsdWve.png)

Comment: This answer and a lot of the comments appear to be conflating the first amendment (A US-only piece of legislature) with the abstract concept and ideology known as "free speech". *Yes it's legal for them to censor*, and *yes we can criticize it.* Do you really want a handful of megacorporations controlling what you can and can't say on the internet? Will you still be saying "private platform" when The Party actually turns out to be Google?

Comment: Nobody here is claiming the freedom of speech issue is about the USA 1st amendment. Freedom of speech is a universal right. We know that this commercial website *can* restrict speech.

Answer (score -10):

While a good effort, I don't think this adds anything over the existing FAQ. It's just addressing some common arguments, which is probably a mistake as it makes it sound like there is a debate to be had here.

The FAQ is clear and concise. No need to get into lawyering it just to placate people.