# Feedback post: Moderator review and reinstatement processes

Tags: discussion, moderation, moderators

**Update (2020-06)**: A new revision to the reinstatement process linked below has been posted. Please go to [Feedback post: New moderator reinstatement and appeals process revisions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/350184/feedback-post-new-moderator-reinstatement-and-appeal-process-revisions) for an intro and discussion on the new changes.

---

The Moderator review and reinstatement processes posted 21 October 2019 have been discussed with the moderators and the two posts below reflect the agreed process for removing or reinstating moderators from now on. While these processes may change over time as they're put into practice, for now they are considered finalized and are available for use.

- [What processes exist to issue formal warnings or remove moderators?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336173/what-processes-exist-to-issue-formal-warnings-or-remove-moderators)
- [What is the process for a moderator to request reinstatement or appeal a removal?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336175/what-is-the-process-for-a-moderator-to-request-reinstatement-or-appeal-a-removal)

There are two review policies - one (Action Review) is the older policy from 2012 and one (Conduct Review) is the new policy. There is one reinstatement policy for all former moderators who wish to be reinstated.

We expect that some of you may have questions about the processes and want some clarifications. **This post is a place for you to ask them.** Please do not post questions about the process on those posts - they will be removed.

We very much respect the value of meta discussion but would like to keep the process posts clean and not have to delete all of the discussion to make the actual policy clear. Having the discussion here makes that easier. We have cross-linked the posts so that they're easy to find.

#### For ease of response and voting, please limit each answer to one specific concern.

Comment: Are there specific guidelines re interacting with the press (by either party)?

Comment: @mjwills have you seen https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/335708/under-what-circumstances-will-stack-exchange-inc-share-private-sensitive-infor/335749#335749 ?

Comment: @sourcejedi Thanks, very helpful. I wonder whether it may be prudent to be explicit that that policy is in effect in this context.

Comment: Genuine question, when can we expect to get responses to the questions/concerns raised?

Comment: @Script47 Gonna depend on the question. Some of them we're already answering. Some of them will take some time.

Comment: It ain't much and I don't have a big reputation but I kindly ask for Monica to be reinstated.

Comment: Slightly off topic, but how is it decided who gets the unhappy task of posting "questions" like this and exposing their reputation to damage from massive downvoting?

Comment: @KMan Kinda depends. For this, I was helping JNat so he posted the policies and I posted the feedback post - but as you can see, JNat's been the one primarily answering questions in the answers below. For the new FAQ, I was the primary person working on reconciling the existing FAQ posts to create the new FAQ and Cesar was helping and had posted the prior FAQ.

Comment: @Catija Is there a planned timeline you can share when a followup to this is posted? Can we expect any changes in the process, and/or an announcement of the final process, and is there a timeline for either?

Comment: @Script47 Well it's been a few weeks and only 1 of the top 13 posts has a staff answer. I guess that's your answer.

Comment: @Catija I haven't heard anything on the feedback that was left -- do you have a timeframe on when we can expect to hear something?

Comment: So, when will we get an answer to the remaining questions? It's 6th December 2019! Will you answer them before 2020? Or do we have to wait till 2121?

Comment: [As of 2019-12-06 16:53:44Z](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/336177/7), this question lost the featured tag without an answer to most of the questions posted here. Does that mean that all contents here will be ignored? And all unanswered questions will remain that way?

Comment: @Catija Bumping my previous request for when we can expect to hear something on all of the feedback we gave. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336177/feedback-post-moderator-review-and-reinstatement-processes/336275#comment1123049_336177

Comment: @GeorgeStocker Not quite sure what you're expecting... not trying to be flippant but... I mean... we've given lots of feedback to the queries below. There are parts of this process that are opaque even to CMs. Once the mod council is in place I will attempt to get some changes made ... this is particularly a need since there's only four CMs left... but there's only so much I can do.

Comment: Bit of a hack - but considering that there's a new process, this post is obsolete. Feedback on the other post please!

Answer (score 1385):

I know that my answer will overlap others, but enough people are waiting for me to comment on this process with an eye toward my case in particular that I'm going to post anyway.

**The new removal process, while better than what was done to me, lacks important safeguards present in the pre-existing Moderator Action Review Process.**   Most importantly, it lacks the interactive phase where the accused can respond to comments raised by others.  It also **lacks transparency**, being handled entirely by two CMs out of view of anybody else including the accused.  It also **does not allow the accused to challenge specific judges** for substantiated concerns of bias; it relies on CMs to recuse themselves, but the moderator has no say or even knowledge of who acted.  If there were more trust between the community and SE this might be surmountable, but in the current climate that's an awfully big assumption.

**The new reinstatement process is even more flawed:**

- **There is no transparency or ability to audit.** The moderator submits a petition into the void and eventually an answer comes out.  If I were to submit an application, a CM or Director could simply veto it and then say "we went through a process so we must be right".
- **The moderator cannot challenge judges.** If a moderator has been removed, chances are that there were some interactions with some community managers and/or members of the community strategy team that would prejudice an appeal.  A moderator should not be subject to summary judgement by the employee who ruled on the removal in the first place, and the moderator should have the opportunity to raise specific concerns about anybody.  The moderator should know who the judges are.
- **The process starts from a presumption of guilt.** If a moderator went through the paired removal process and actually received the information about charges and warnings called for in it, then the moderator has a starting point for an appeal.  But if that *didn't* happen, the moderator is forced to guess.  "Guilty until proven innocent" is not a sound judicial process; this process should not apply in cases where no sound *removal* process was followed.
- **There is no dialogue, no hearing, and no opportunity to present witnesses or evidence.**  The interactive aspects of the pre-existing removal process (MARP) are missing in both the new removal process and the reinstatement process.  While synchronous chat for worldwide teams is a major hassle, there needs to be *some* way to include the moderator in a *discussion* of the situation.

Both processes involve **annotations**, which should be shared with the moderator and subject to challenge.  I can only imagine what unsupported annotations a CM or Director may have added to my account, for example.

---

The new removal process, if properly followed, would have given me a fair chance, though the concerns about transparency and bias remain.  That process would have required SE to share information about the specific complaint with me and, at worst, would have resulted in a warning.  **But that's not what happened,** and against that backdrop, the **reinstatement process would not be fair in my case**.  I shan't submit to it.

Comment: I think your last sentence is what they were hoping you would say.  It certainly lets them off the hook.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I think they were hoping I would submit to it, so they could then say "no" and claim they followed a process.  I'm not letting them off the hook, but this process won't be my path to getting this fixed.

Comment: The flaws noted here are important, but probably manageable for someone who went through the initial removal process. For someone who _wasn't_, the process fails badly at both ends. It starts with a no-context appeal request, and if it ends in reinstatement there's apparently no further feedback. Given that your case incited this, it's at best a baffling failure to consider how you'd be affected. More cynically, it's a process which would let you quietly return as a moderator without admitting guilt, while still letting SE apply conditions and avoid telling you why you were removed.

Comment: An update about the process not including discussion. It's not written into the document at the moment, but it has been supported as part of the flow: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336177/feedback-post-moderator-review-and-reinstatement-processes?page=2&tab=votes#comment1111637_336239

Comment: Hi Monica, `The new removal process ...  lacks the interactive phase where the accused can respond to comments raised by others.` No I think that *is* in there ([see here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/336178/139866)). The Discovery phase is usually trivial, apparently, and can run without input from the moderator -- e.g. if a user complains to SE that a moderator deleted one of the user's comments -- this is the most common case and SE can (and maybe wants to) be able to quickly dismiss it without communications-overhead with the moderator ...

Comment: ... *if* that discovery phase is non-trivial then there's dialog-with-moderator built-in then before the confirmation phase starts, i.e. `If CM1 determines a CoC or mod agreement violation occurred, they will contact the moderator about whom the complaint was raised and inform them of the ongoing process, prompting them for their perspective/context/reasoning, and add this to the documentation to be reviewed in the Confirmation Phase`

Comment: You added, `the reinstatement process would not be fair in my case. I shan't submit to it` -- I (personally) wish you'd assume good faith on the part of SE, though I see why you might not. If you were reinstated that might be the best-case possible outcome, and maybe the only restitution they might easily be able to offer. That might depend on there being some good-will. Given what you wrote in comments on your blog, a suitable "precondition" (that you could be happy to suggest!) might be to stay out the TL. I guess you could ask them informally (if you're still on speaking terms) whether ...

Comment: ... it's worth applying for restitution. Another issue might be a pronoun policy as it's applicable to moderators, which might not have been set in stone yet as far as I know, perhaps they still need to define that more clearly before you'd be able to agree with them (during any eventual reinstatement or reconciliation) on how you might agree with that.

Comment: @MonicaCellio They can't just say "no, we followed a process". According to the process document itself, "the reasons for it will be stated back to PM" in all cases where the PM does not know the reason where their request was declined. After that, you can simply submit another application for reinstatement with that prior knowledge.

Comment: @ChrisW after all that SE has done, including unrecanted public smearing, I would be foolish to assume good faith from them.  It is way too easy for them to misuse this process to smear me even more.  Dialogue only happens at their initiative, unlike in the original removal process where all the mods on the team discuss the matter together.  And since I had *already* said I would stay out of TL (and did so), if that had been sufficient for them we wouldn't be here.  If things have changed and that *would* have been sufficient, they should reverse their faulty decision.

Comment: @JL2210 "reason for denial: original reasons still apply".  That wouldn't help.

Comment: @MonicaCellio I can't argue against that. We can hope that they have some consideration for you and don't say that. You never know until you try.

Comment: Monica, there are **NO** annotations on your account at all in the last three years.

Comment: @Catija I mentioned Sara because the process runs through Sara's team.  Sara has the authority, in this process, of unilaterally denying an appeal.  I think that's an important factor and you've edited it out; further, my answer now casts doubt on the CMs, and I'm pretty sure they aren't the ones who acted badly here.  But thank you for letting me know that there are no annotations currently; I obviously couldn't have known that when I wrote this answer.

Comment: No amount of harm ever makes calling out people on meta and accusing them of things acceptable. That's been our policy for years. We've allowed it to some degree because we understand this situation is complicated and frustrating to people but in this case it's both incorrect and being used as reasoning for not going through the process. We would not have made this available to you if you would be immediately vetoed. I know that's difficult to believe but I repeatedly confirmed that was the case last week because doing otherwise would have been cruel. The deck isn't stacked against you here.

Comment: @MonicaCellio Feel free to edit as you see fit. Please don't add Sara's name back in. Considering what I've just stated, I could imagine that removing those sections of the answer would also be an option.

Comment: @Catija SE can claim that all they like, but the actual process lacks the transparency to allow me to audit the results.  Also, all the other stuff I said -- given what got us here, going through this process would be like building on quicksand and guessing about where to pour the foundation.  (And I honestly don't see how referring to a very public record is "calling out" someone inappropriately, but I'm not going to get into an edit dispute with an employee.)

Comment: @MonicaCellio I think the way that SE treated you is atrocious and indefensible. That said, while I believe it was unintentional, your behavior did hurt people. I think even more mods (the only users who have seen the majority of the full story) would come to your defense if you would admit that you unintentionally hurt people.

Comment: @StrongBad the positive requirement for pronouns entered the CoC no earlier than September 18. I've reviewed the transcript that was leaked to Reddit and I don't see anything unreasonable from me. It's clear that some people objected to my Teams post from *January*, but not enough to have caused multiple CMs who saw it to say anything to me about it. I'm sure there's older stuff that has unintentionally hurt someone, *just like others have hurt me* (not always unintentionally), but writing around pronoun problems was permitted until a few weeks ago. Also, I *left TL* to avoid any hurt.

Comment: @MonicaCellio "writing around pronoun problems was permitted until a few weeks ago" I think this is where there is some disagreement. While the CoC did not say anything other than be nice until a few weeks ago, writing around pronouns for one group of people is not nice and was therefore always against the CoC. Hunting for the minimum accommodation you need to make to satisfy the CoC is not good moderator behavior in my opinion and is also not nice. None of this is to imply that you were intentionally trying to hurt people nor does it excuse SE's response.

Comment: @StrongBad and once I understood that inconsistency issue, I agreed to *treat everyone the same*.  That's clear in the transcript and it's what I've been careful to do since that conversation.  (It's not a big stretch; I write gender-neutral wherever possible already.)  My questions weren't about "hunting for the minimum accommodation"; they were about finding something that would be acceptable to everyone, taking *my* needs and identity issues into account as well.  I'm allowed to have those too, right?

Comment: @MonicaCellio of course you are allowed to have your identity. All I am saying is that your actions hurt some people. Until I see you take responsibility for that, I (and I think other mods) will have trouble fully supporting you. I think we are all in agreement that SE screwed it up.

Comment: @StrongBad it's never been my intention to hurt anyone.  When I became aware that people were hurt for reasons I couldn't understand, I withdrew.  I don't know what else you want me to say.

Comment: @MonicaCellio basically that is what I was hoping you might say, but maybe expanded a little and not buried in a comment chain. Right now a lot of people don't realize you unintentionally hurt people. When you realized it, you withdrew, which was great since if you don't know why or how you are hurting someone, stepping away is a great first reaction. I hope, and believe, you are willing to work to better understand the issues so that in the future you will be able to reengage without hurting people. Most of your posts have focused on the bad SE response ...

Comment: ... and rightfully so when you are immediately under attack, but we are getting to the point where we need to hear that you had some responsibility in this also.

Comment: @StrongBad I'm not sure I'm following here. Who did she unintentionally hurt? Where is her responsibility in what happened? What are you trying to imply?

Comment: Also, there's a context in which lots of people were feeling hurt by each other, but somehow I'm being singled out?  I'll own my part in that but it's *not* the full story by any means @StrongBad.  (Also, not a CoC violation...)

Comment: @MonicaCellio It feels like StrongBad has been fed a lot of second or third hand information and is now accusing you under hearsay.

Comment: @Trasiva I am pretty sure I was there. And yes, I believe Monica was singled out and her behavior is not the full story. I really wish it was the full story and SE didn't pull the crap they did. I am admittedly focusing on a small part of the story because it is the piece that prevents me from backing her 100%.

Comment: @StrongBad I believe the question was; which part of the story are you focusing on, and how was that hurtful. This information is very important when debating the validity of the entire argument.

Comment: @StrongBad - So, to clarify - before you would support requesting that SE take steps to mitigate the harm of The Register article (i.e. issue an apology and a retraction), you need to see that Monica accepts responsibility for her ill-treatment?  If I've got that stated correctly, your position is coming dangerously close to victim blaming.

Comment: @ConcernedClient No! This question/answer and comments are about the reinstatement and removal process. I have tried to be clear that 1) the way SE treated Monica was atrocious and indefensible, 2) that Monica did not intentionally try and hurt people, and 3) that Monica's stance on pronouns and her usage of pronouns did hurt people. Both myself and others have spent a lot of time on 1 and 2, here I am trying to focus on 3.

Comment: @StrongBad Understood, thank you.  For what it's worth, it's my position that the situation with The Register needs to be addressed properly and first, before any discussion about internal SE (the community) issues can produce substantive results.

Comment: @ConcernedClient I think they can be tackled in parallel, but your view seems reasonable enough. As Monica is the one most directly impacted by these issues, I wish SE would respect her enough to allow her to provide input into their priorities. But at the end of the day (and I really wish it would be just a day) SE has a lot of things to fix. They are making progress on the foundation and hopefully they will eventually get to the finish line.

Comment: @StrongBad clarification: some people felt hurt.  And ConcernedClient, yes the public maligning of me is by far the biggest issue here, both in The Register and across SE (including in a post featured for several days).

Comment: @StrongBad I don't get your point. I guess most of us say something that hurts somebody else every day. What makes you think we don't realize that our best moderators can do it once a week? I would not believe you if you told me otherwise. So what? That is not the problem.

Comment: @MonicaCellio I am not sure what that comment is replying to, but I hope you are not trying to debate the nuanced difference between being hurt and feeling hurt.

Comment: @Goyo I am trying really hard not to disparage Monica. No one deserves that and she doesn't deserve it especially since there was no malice in her actions. Instead of trying to find faults with my arguments based on things I probably shouldn't be saying given the extent to which my hands are tied, maybe you can step back and just hear that someone who was there thinks there is more to the story than is being said publicly. That Monica's actions and stance on pronouns hurt people.

Comment: @StrongBad  So let's get this straight. Because people were hurt, and Monica (by your own admittance) stepped back...you want what? An apology for course correcting?

Comment: @StrongBad I still don't get it. I take for granted that Monica's actions and stance on pronouns hurt people. Her own account of the events made it clear to me. That does not make any difference in my views regarding SE actions.

Comment: @StrongBad Okay, so Monica's actions hurt people... So? Let's say a hunter is hunting for rabbits. Somehow, a child's pet rabbit got into the woods.  The hunter kills it. Was the child hurt by the hunter's actions? Yes, absolutely. How responsible is the hunter? 0%. Same thing if a driver, obeying all traffic laws, kills someone who suddenly jumps out into the street. Causing harm is insufficient to assign blame. It must also be shown that no reasonable actions or inactions could have averted the harm.

Comment: @StrongBad - I don't believe they can be addressed in parallel.  The statements to The Register were unprovoked, unnecessary, and unprofessional.  The "new" policy on statements to the press is telling in its simplicity ('No comment').  Every professional you could find already knows this, a Director-Level employee did not need a policy to make this wrong.  Until SE addresses the public harm, there is no point in giving any tiny amount of trust to an internal process.  I certainly won't participate here under my real name ever again, and have removed SE from my CV.

Comment: @StrongBad If holding a particular opinion on a controversial issue is now automatically construed as hurtful behavior that the person holding it has to apologize for, that seems like a very dangerous precedent. Besides (and I'm being hypothetical here), if we accept that, couldn't Monica just say that she's offended by their position? Why is the fact that they may have been offended by Monica's position more valid or important than the fact that Monica may have been offended by theirs? I for one would hate to see us settling disagreements by trying to determine who's more offended.

Comment: @StrongBad If that's really what Monica's being accused of (unintentionally hurting people by holding a particular opinion), that seems like thoughtcrime. I'm not taking a particular stance on pronoun use here, I'm just saying that I think that it's important that we be able to discuss the issues. Are we going to shut down any debate of any potentially controversial issues now based on the fact that someone, somewhere, might be offended?

Comment: @EJoshuaS There are certainly some opinions that cannot be expressed in communities with a CoC aimed at inclusivity for minorities. One obvious example is "<people of some race> are inherently, genetically less intelligent." This is not just a "gotcha" example; Curtis Yarvin is an example of someone in the tech community who has previously made statements like that, and who was subsequently banned from some tech conferences (and, controversially, _not_ banned from others).

Comment: I don't know how to resolve the tension between our distaste for the idea of "thoughtcrime" and the fact that the expression of some thoughts really is hostile and harmful to some people. But I do think it's reasonable, at a minimum, for communities to voluntarily adopt CoCs that prohibit the _expression_ of such thoughts.

Comment: @KyleStrand Thought crime is not the same as speech crime. It's about policing their thoughts, not their statements. It involves directed prodding to discover one's true beliefs on the matter. There's a difference between proclaiming your bigotry to the world in order to get a reaction and quietly holding on to them, and only letting them out when someone directly asks you your position.

Comment: @KyleStrand there are opinions and expressions of opinions that we should agree we ought not host.  At the other extreme, "somebody might disagree" is not sufficient reason to bar an opinion.  Diversity means encountering perspectives with which you are unfamiliar or disagree; through the resulting discourse we all learn and grow.  Where between these two endpoints to draw the line is a matter of much debate; the line seems to be moving much closer to the latter now.

Comment: @Catija "No amount of harm ever makes calling out people on meta and accusing them of things acceptable. That's been our policy for years."  So, where's the remediation for Sara **doing exactly that** to me?

Comment: @Sean, I don't want you to get in trouble or to get this post locked when people are actively voting on it, so I'm going to roll back that edit.  I agree with you but we have been overruled and I don't want the blowback.

Comment: `If things have changed and that would have been sufficient, they should reverse their faulty decision.` I guess that implies you'd like a return to the *status quo ante*, I hope you and @Catija figure a (friendly?) compromise. I suppose this is post-traumatic for you and you fixate on (replay) the *past* stressful event and its agents: which people do post-stress. I kind of make a religion of knowing and handling stress, You and I met in Temperance, that's where I'm from. And so many people's upvoting your posts is delightful solidarity, but a flame war -- IMO likely intoxicating like the TL.

Comment: @KyleStrand *There are certainly some opinions that cannot be expressed in communities with a CoC aimed at inclusivity for minorities.* This isn't that, though. Monica wasn't promoting an overtly prejudiced or fringe opinion. In fact, it's not even clear exactly what policy she violated, given that the current version of the CoC specifically permits what she was asking to be allowed to do in the first place. As far as I can tell, she was fired for... uhh... a hypothetical violation of a policy that was never written? Disagreeing with the policy SE was thinking about writing but didn't?

Comment: @EJoshuaS I'm not trying to defend SE's position. I'm responding to your comment that punishing Monica for "unintentionally hurting people by holding a particular opinion... seems like thoughtcrime." Whether an opinion is permissible in an "inclusive" community is not necessarily related to whether it is a "fringe" opinion. I am merely trying to demonstrate (by comparison to a different opinion that was once considered neither "overtly prejudiced" nor "fringe", but is now considered unconscionable) that, indeed, some opinions *are* punishable by exclusion from a "safe" community.

Comment: @Nacht It has been said multiple times by multiple ex-moderators that Monica's statements "hurt people". So her "thoughtcrime" was in fact only punished once it became "speech crime". I am not saying the punishment was appropriate or even that any punishment was necessarily deserved; I just don't believe that a generic "thoughtcrime shouldn't exist, therefore bigotry shouldn't be punished" argument holds water.

Comment: @ChrisW well, the *status quo ante* is: "is a mod without prejudice" + "not publicly smeared".  They can't completely do the latter, but they can take substantial steps to reduce the harm they have done.  That they won't do that, when the evidence that the public statements are false is quite clear, is quite upsetting -- they prefer sticking to their story over mitigating the *actual harm they have done to a dedicated user*.

Comment: @KyleStrand during that TL discussion there was an awful lot of "your actions *would*  have been ok except we know why you're doing it and that makes you wrong".  The original version of the CoC change that was shared with mods had language about judging intent; I think the first posted FAQ had that too but haven't double-checked.  There is clearly a thoughtcrime aspect to this *too*.

Comment: @MonicaCellio The first version of the FAQ had "intentionally avoiding" in it.

Comment: @MonicaCellio My advice: get legal council and go after SE.  The only thing a company really understands is profit and loss.  if you want a resolution then force their hand otherwise they could care less which is evident in their posts about the debacle.

Comment: @Catija you said you confirmed Monica wouldn't be *immediately* vetoed. But surely you know more than that already. Are we expected to believe that SE hasn't already thought through what the outcome would be if Monica would formally initiate this process (and the respective site mods don't object, which seems unlikely given many of their public statements)?

Comment: @MonicaCellio That certainly sounds ugly, and from what I've seen I don't doubt that you were indeed told things along those lines (though I don't have access to the TL, and I haven't read the leaked transcript). I still want to emphasize that EJoshuaS's concern about a "dangerous precedent" cannot be resolved by simply rejecting the ability of communities to adopt any rules around what opinions may be expressed within that community. (Equally, I think it is crucial that communities exist where _any and every_ opinion may be expressed or even espoused; but Stack Overflow is not `r/TheMotte`.)

Comment: @StrongBad: *"Monica's stance on pronouns and her usage of pronouns hurt people."* Hold on a second. Do you really mean her *usage* of pronouns, or her *lack* of usage of pronouns? Also: her **stance** hurt people? Even though she had been perfectly abiding by the rules regardless? Do you realize what you're saying is is that you [<- generic] think people deserve to be *punished* *even if they're abiding by your own rules*, solely because they *disagreed* with you? Meaning: obedience is *not* enough for you; agreement is also mandatory? Are your serious here?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1389/discussion-between-terdon-and-mehrdad).

Comment: Hi @MonicaCellio It is I, your friend Ellie over on LiveJournal and sometimes here on SE. Apparently the use of gender neutral pronouns is not acceptable behavior based on the new CoC. Similarly, choosing to disengage is also not acceptable as stated in the new CoC. I have always thought you were a great moderator but I would feel very sad if your health, happiness, and public reputation were negatively impacted by your volunteer activities on SE, where you freely, generously give of your time. That is your decision though. You have my sympathy and support.

Comment: "writing around pronouns for one group of people is not nice" - I think the crux of the issue is that this is an misinterpretation of Monica's behavior and motivations; as far as I understand, her style of gender-neutral writing avoids gender-specific pronouns indiscriminately (so no specific group of people is targeted), and her motivation for doing so has always been to be respectful, not out of protest. She raised concerns about the wording of the policy, and this being a sensitive issue, after some back-and-forth, someone jumped to the conclusion that the underlying motivation was bigotry.

Comment: Monica has been a fine moderator on numerous sites. My only concern is that she (and others) might be limited to moderating "x" number of sites (their choice). But even if she were a bad fit for one site, there are numerous others that would have her.

Comment: Monica, Keep Going! You deserve the truth! Fight for yourself

Comment: @StrongBad it is almost impossible to talk about important matters for a long time with a large group of people without some of them feeling hurt at some point. That someone feels hurt doesn't mean the other party did something bad. What did Monica do that she has to apologize for? I have been reading about this and I still don't get what is that she did that was so bad? She said she likes to write gender neutral in general. People were trying to force her to use genders in certain cases.(cont...)

Comment: (cont...)For me that is insulting, because basically what they said is that she was discriminating on purpose and they were not hearing her side of the argument. From what I understood they were saying Monica had to use genders when someone had stated their prefered gender, otherwise that would be discrimatory. So talking in a gender neutral way is discriminatory? I could accept that if Monica talked every day with 2 or 3 people only, maybe up to 10, and she knew them enough not to make mistakes. Not when she is such an active member of the community, interacting with soo many people.(cont...)

Comment: (cont...) You are trying to force her to remember the gender preference of fantasy names, (because names here are fantasy, no real clue as to what kind of person is in the other side) of gazillion people. And what if she made a mistake and remembered wrong? What if she manages to remember 2 or 3 genders, but she doesn't remember the prefered gender of 1 other person, because she doesn't even know it, because she wasn't there when this person stated their prefered gender.(cont...)

Comment: (cont...) Then this person would feel discriminated because Monica used the proper gender for the other 3 people and not for this one person. What I understood Monica wanted was to be able to write gender neutral, to avoid all these problems and also because it is really a lot to ask from one person to remember so much data of so many people. I can't remember the name of people I have met in person, you want her to remember the gender of someone she hasn't met, in relation to a fantasy name that give no useful hint for memory, and not to mess it up.(cont...)

Comment: (cont...) And when she asks to do something more simple, use gender neutral, which is not so simple either, so she never messes up and avoids hurting anyone, you say she is being hurtful and mean? (not on purpose, but she did it, according to what I understood you said) And now has to apologize? If i undestood this wrong please tell me, because I don't see yet what she did that was so wrong, which btw doesn't seem wrong at all to me, it more seems to me like everyone else had decided to bully her for asking to do something in certain way, to avoid hurting people in general, (cont...)

Comment: (cont...) which was even abiding by the rules at the time and then created a smear campaing that has probably caused her a lot of stress and pain, and stills gets people like you talking in shades. If you think she did something wrong, say it clearly, like a lot of people asked here, so we can all talk from the same place, and not in shades, which only helps to continue smearing her reputation. In my opinion SE should offer public apologizes and reinstate her, and she shouldn't have to do anything to accomplish it. (cont...)

Comment: It took a long time to develop the concept of innocence until guilt is proven. There is a recent trend, especially on the left, of accepting guilt as equivalent to accusation of guilt and letting unfounded points of view dominate while putting the accused in the impossible situation of having to prove a negative. That is, how can one prove 'nothing' as in 'I did nothing?' This site is not capable of developing an alternative reality system of jurisprudence without paying heed to history. Instead we are treated to poor judgement based on autocratic fiat, a depreciated model of government.

Comment: @StrongBad At this stage, it really doesn't matter what Monica did or did not do. The process has been so opaque that I as an outside observer cannot evaluate its fairness. I see comments in the press from SE that are completely at odds with what I've seen from Monica when she has moderated our forum (Worldbuilding); I hear her side of the story, which sounds pretty much like a reactionary stance to a completely reasonable position. There's no decent information from SE on this topic -- we don't even know that pronouns had ANYTHING to do with it! They've never said!

Comment: A wall of 'information' and as always one option is the consensus reality. I have never felt I've been given a complete picture that makes this anymore than a heroes and villians story backed up by the inevitable up and downvote storm intended to support the theory.

Answer (score 529):

## The reinstatement process is broken as written.

The process is rigged against the previous moderator (PM).

> Community Managers (CMs) can recuse themselves if they feel they can't be impartial.

There needs to be a way to recuse CMs who can't be impartial but won't recuse themselves. CMs recusing other CMs? The PM recusing up to a small number of CMs? The moderator teams for the target sites?

> The process is concluded here.

This is **unacceptable**. The PM never gets a say in this whole process other than applying. They have no way to argue for themselves, set preconditions of their own, or even say "Hang on, the reasons you gave me are factually incorrect/too vague to mean anything!".

> If a precondition is set, CM1 will communicate this back to PM

Wait, that's done *after* talking to the mod team? That seems pointlessly opaque: what's wrong with telling PM "Is $thing okay with you? If so, we'll ask the mods if they want you back on condition you do $thing" first?

> reinstatement is possible under the agreement that a reasonable and attainable precondition should and could be met

This is vulnerable to "Have you stopped beating your wife?". It may be okay if the conditions are strictly about the future, e.g. "PM will never call a user a doo-doo head". It's certainly not okay if the condition can be "PM will stop calling users doo-doo heads" (implying that they did so) or worse "PM will apologise for calling users doo-doo heads" (when PM denies having ever done so).

> access is restored

This is the *best* possible outcome for PM. There is no outcome that involves an acknowledgement that the removal was in error (e.g. a miscalculation of inactivity duration, a mistaken belief that PM had broken a rule), let alone an apology or reparations if applicable.

> subject to summary removal for non-compliance

Who evaluates compliance? This could easily be gamed.

Comment: If preconditions are communicated to the PM prior to consultation with the current moderators and the current moderators have additional preconditions, then PM will be given two, potentially conflicting sets of preconditions and be aware that the second set of preconditions were specified by the current moderators. That seems less desirable than holding off a week to tell the PM about the preconditions.

Comment: If a former moderator who goes through this process has their own preconditions, wouldn't that generally be a barrier to continued participation with the CM team?  I mean, at the end of the day, all of the bits and bytes still flow to Stack Exchange, and someone wanting to come back to work with the CM team would have to accept that they're not *really* in control of their destiny.

Comment: (It's also the same reason that I don't think it makes ***any*** sense for Monica to ask for reinstatement, nor for others to ask for it on her behalf.)

Comment: 'This is vulnerable to "Have you stopped beating your wife?"' to me that seems to be by design (and rightly so). If it has been determined that PM hasn't violated a rule, then there will be no precondition. But if it has been determined that there was a violation, then it's reasonable to request that PM acknowledges that before being reinstated. If PM still denies that they did *the thing* even though it was determined that they in fact did it, the promise not to do it in the future is not worth much.

Comment: Great point about the voluntary recusal being problematic. (I wonder if, say, Sara Chipps would recuse herself from Monica's case. It would be a most interesting test case.)

Comment: Another rigged part of the reinstatement process is step 2.1: "If CM1 finds any annotation that states reinstatement is deemed impossible, the request is denied [...]". This seems incredibly vague and arbitrary - so there's an annotation like "never reinstate her lol" about Monica, she can never be reinstated? Hopefully it's not as frivolous as that, but having non-transparent annotations that can immediately stop the process after the first step seems like an easy way out for SE.

Comment: @J.R. - for me the better question is, that since Sarah was undoubtedly the person who made the call to demod Monica (and given that she is a director and the other CMs are not) **why on earth would we expect them to go against her when it would threaten their jobs and livelihoods**? If my boss asked me to review one of their decisions, I'd say "*great idea, boss*" because I'm not a moron.

Comment: You raise a valid point, @tim, although it depends on any preconditions supplied by the company and/or moderators being fair.  If, e.g., someone is demodded because a director is having a horrible day and needs to vent on someone, then given the precondition that they must publicly state that they will never again eat live babies while tap-dancing on global television (when they have never done so in the first place), then it becomes problematic.  (A silly example, I know, I just wanted an example precondition that clearly has no basis in past actions, to illustrate the flaw. ;P)

Comment: @tim When someone has behaved badly, it is indeed very important that they admit their mistakes and try to rectify things before you give them your trust.  Will anyone from Stack Overflow do that?  Or is this something they just want other people to do?

Comment: @Richard, exactly. In clinical psychology the concept of recusal is more general than what you see in litigious situations. Clinician's are trained to know there are situations that they should never enter into (counseling family members, counseling multiple members of a family) because even under the best of intentions, fully believing that you can be impartial- you will not see when you have lost that ability; therefore, unrepairable harm can occur. This is unethical. You can loose your license for unethical behavior; so the plea "I thought I could have been impartial" is indefensible.

Comment: @Lmidh - Except that SE are the only ones policing SE. The idea that anyone would tell their boss to recuse themself or go against their decision is laughable.

Comment: @Richard- Agreed, that's why SE recusal, as stated, is impossible to operate in an ethical or fair way; therefore the entire proposal, as stated, is unable to operate in a fair or ethical way. The idea that the proposal is good or fixes anything is indefensible because it isn't even logically sound.

Comment: It seems the Moniker truck has traction, but as regards the 'Like dumpertruck' meme popular among semi counter-culture coders a while back, what do there numbers actually meanme?

Answer (score 391):

Thank you for taking the time to put this process together. I know this was dozens and dozens of hours across 7-10 people, If I understand your internal structure correctly.  I wouldn't be surprised if you've spent 500 people-hours on this issue already, and I understand the desire to 'ship it and iterate'.

Please take a moment to pause, and think: What do these processes optimize for? What does shipping these processes now optimize for?

The answer you have internally is different than what we're seeing.

Here's what we see:

Trust is at an all-time low. I wouldn't be surprised if for some people there was less than zero trust -- that the level of trust went negative, as if you need to improve trust *just to get people to neither trust or distrust you*.

Personally, I'm at zero trust right now.  This is not an attack; and it's not you individually, it's you collectively.  I know most of the SE staff involved in these affairs on a first name basis, and I respect and cherish our interactions. The ones I don't know on a first-name basis, I've still had net-positive interactions with. In short, I am pre-disposed through our interactions to trust you, but currently do not.

I tell you this not to raise your hackles, but to hopefully share my feelings with you and show you another perspective.

These processes are a bit like putting the cart before the horse.  These are pretty good processes for a high-trust environment, but you don't have a high-trust environment, and putting these processes in place right now won't make the environment higher trust.

If anything, putting the removal process in place right now will result in lower trust, and without taking in the substantive feedback of your community and moderators, you will further erode any remaining positive trust you have with members of the community.

So, take a pause.  Regroup. Have a meeting. And in this meeting, figure out what you want to do: Do you want to put this process in place, *tout suite*? Or do you want to restore trust with your community?  If SE employees reading this trust me, please hear me on this: *Putting this process in place will damage trust, not restore it*.

I'd love to get on a call with you to listen to the issues you have and to help you solve this problem,  and I believe there are concrete actions you can take now that will restore some trust [and other actions you can do to further restore trust](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/390495/16587).

Comment: "I wouldn't be surprised if for some people there was less than zero trust -- that the level of trust went negative, as if you need to improve trust *just to get people to neither trust or distrust you.*" I have less than zero truest indeed.

Comment: As always more diplomatic and solution oriented then most of us. Here's hoping they take you up on that. Also, the less then zero trust is true for many of us. We trust the individual CMs, but the company gets no benefit of the doubt right now. In fact, senior management is 0 for 5 when it comes to doing what they say.

Comment: *tout suite* -> *tout de suite* ;)

Comment: @alephzero To be fair, they might be forced by higher ups to find a solution to this mess without admitting any guilt and without apologizing. Thousands of hours wouldn't be enough.

Comment: You know, this entire answer was a sight for sore eyes.

Comment: @EricDuminil *"... without admitting any guilt and without apologizing."* Easily done. **"We have concluded it is in the best interest of this community to reinstate Monica Cellio to her previous status without conditions."**  And do it, unilaterally. With no further explanation. Just like in court, most settlements pay cash without admitting any wrong-doing and without making any apology that would implicitly constitute an admission of fault. I am not a lawyer, but I've worked with more than my fair share of them.

Comment: @Amadeus That's true, but it's also only half of the problem (cf. TheRegister).

Comment: @EricDuminil They could accompany that with any new policy change desired (which includes a good one, though that is not in evidence yet). By just doing it, sans process, it becomes Monica's choice whether she wants to then resign or not, they can't stop her if she does, but then they can also claim it was entirely her choice, they restored her to her pre-firing status unconditionally (no conditions on her, and none on them either).

Comment: @Amadeus: I fail to see how it would solve the problem of Point 4 in this [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/336526/390071) (TheRegister article). As far as I can tell, it seems to be the biggest problem.

Comment: @EricDuminil it doesn't, that would take a separate action, or no action. Reinstating Monica would defuse the situation. They could publish a non-apology retraction in The Register, claiming their contact did so without the permission of the board of directors and did not represent an opinion of SE.

Comment: "hese are pretty good processes for a high-trust environment, but you don't have a high-trust environment, and putting these processes in place right now won't make the environment higher trust." very well said.

Answer (score 339):

The two new processes are palliative at best. I would NEVER want to be a moderator with such procedures in place:

1. There is no community oversight of any community manager's action, and frankly, I do not trust the CMs to never make mistakes and do not see why the community should. The oversight could be performed by other mods under NDA, and be not binding. Both parties need an impartial voice guaranteeing that the process was followed and that the decisions were not too controversial.
2. CMs retain absolute power, including the ability to ban a moderator indefinitely without giving any reasonable reason or appeal. This is unnecessary.
3. Any annotation that says a diamond can't be restored prevents it, indefinitely and with no limits. There are no appeals or guarantees of reinstatement in case of mistakes. This should be corrected (in fact, I don't see why it should be allowed at all).
4. CMs are responsible for inevitable mistakes in judging moderators and are also responsible for deciding whether they made a mistake. This should not be the case, and community oversight is essential to align the incentives.
5. There is no oversight for emergency demodding and nothing to prevent its abuse.
6. Substantially, there are no guaranteed timings. You can delay responding to anyone as long as you want. This should also be corrected, especially in the case of emergency demodding.
7. Accused mods are merely informed that the process is in place once their guilt is "determined". This is "guilty until proven innocent". By talking to @Catija I know this is not as intended but it needs to be fixed: mods should be contacted before any determination and the accusation and the evidence supporting it needs to be shared too, so they can defend themselves.

While I appreciate the effort in writing this, it's clear to me that you have not demonstrated the intention of creating a fair process - this apparently codifies the previous "non-process" in a process that fails to solve the more substantial problems. Instead, it should make more effort to increase trust in some form, and make sure it does not codify that you do not trust us, instead.

You should extensively review it or scratch it and build a process that enshrines mutual trust.

Comment: We are suffering from day to day. [**hide_the_pain_harold.jpg**](https://hungarytoday.hu/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/18ps27.jpg).

Comment: You're not wrong, Sklivvz, but I can't really see a better way either. How could the community provide oversight of CM actions? There will be times when the actions of the "bad" mod can't be shared with the community without shaming them publicly. This should basically be like the process of user suspension which is handled by mods with no community input. The problem is that we no longer trust SE to act fairly. If trust hadn't been lost, this procedure would be fine. Without trust, no procedure can be good enough. I don't really see a way around this.

Comment: @terdon there are plenty of ways! (a) the accused mod should see all the evidence against them and be able to present counter-evidence. This would prevent cases like Monica's where she's not even able to disagree because the accusations are so vague and no evidence was presented. (b) some random community moderators could be included in at least reviewing the evidence under NDA and be able to agree or disagree publicly about the outcome. Just two random thoughts, but if there was an interest in having a process based on trust there are 1000 ways.

Comment: Hmm. Yes, those are good suggestions. I was thinking of "community" as "the community that elected this mod". But allowing the mod to see the evidence (except when provided in confidence) does seem like a no-brainer, really. I hadn't realized that wasn't part of the process!

Comment: In absolute generality, a necessary condition of a good process is that the incentives align with the outcome. All parties should have incentives that create a balanced outcome, preventing mistakes, and reinforcing trust. At the moments the incentives are objectively broken. For example CMs have no incentive in finding mistakes in their own work. Sometimes they don't even have the possibility (e.g. an annotation is unappealable even when totally wrong)

Comment: I don't normally do this, but this is one thing I would categorically disagree with you on.  Community-elected Moderators are appointed to represent the community, but have always been beholden to the rules the company sets for them.  This also means that CMs have the privilege of serving as benevolent dictators over the process.  Asking the community to adjudicate a situation like this is akin to making moderation *more* of a popularity contest rather than it being at least somewhat more in-line with what an outside observer could expect.

Comment: That isn't to say that I don't see your point; I think what you're trying to get at is to make it more of a trustworthy process.  I think my only real sticking point is that you're not thrilled that CMs hold absolute power...when in actuality they do.  Resolving *that* tension is something that goes above this process' pay grade.

Comment: @Makoto I think CMs should be free to make their own decisions, but I think they should NOT be able to do so *secretly*. Non-binding oversight is one way.

Comment: @Sklivvz:  I mean...this *isn't* a public trial.  This is honestly the company providing clarity around a policy which they admitted wasn't followed or in place or *both*, and we're still getting the same judges and the same hard reality check we had before this whole debacle kicked off.  The company can make decisions about whether or not a moderator can remain a moderator.  Expecting any less is a bit odd since this isn't a public trial.

Comment: Again, the opposite of a secret trial is not necessarily a public trial. Plenty of trials are conducted behind closed doors to guarantee privacy, yet with oversight by the public to guarantee fairness.

Comment: My biggest problem with this is that it doesn't seem to involve the other mods for that site ("team") at all - not in gathering information and context, not consulting them... Why not?   It does reinforce the problem that we don't trust the CMs to handle this.

Comment: @Sklivvz I really liked the one line summary as you had it before the last edit: "You should scratch it and build a process that enshrines mutual trust."

Comment: @DeNovo Thanks, I've incorporated your feedback

Comment: That's such a nice idea that I'd have to agree. And there is an even better approach: "build a process that *does not need mutual trust*." But one that works even without. Taking a hint from democratic institutions that need to be balanced *against* each other in the face of antagonistic interests and ambitions. We saw the ousting of the 7th king Superbus a benevolent dictator/king and now look at processes modelled after a failed republic. Why not just skip that?

Answer (score 220):

The new process was created in response to the lack of process that led to the firing of Monica. So I think it is fair to ask in what ways the events around Monica's firing violated the tenets of this new process, and what SE is planning to do to correct their mistakes. I think SE should state publicly in which ways the rights this process grants to moderators were ignored by the previous events. We have read an apology by SE, but that was a bit fuzzy on exactly what SE thinks they did wrong, and it doesn't really leave me with the impression that SE necessarily understood just how much they screwed up. It would help to restore confidence if SE would actually state what went wrong, and how the new process addresses these mistakes.

One important principle of the new process is that there should be a warning, and that this warning should contain clear and actionable feedback. This is to me maybe one of the most important parts, and one I personally consider one of the aspect that were not followed at all in previous events, to my limited knowledge.

I think the process itself is fine, and I'm glad to see that SE incorporates the feedback it received from the moderators. But the process still requires us to trust SE, as it's entirely in the hands of SE employees. Which is probably the way it has to be, I don't really see any other viable options. But that trust is something SE has to earn again, and while the new process is a good step, it doesn't necessarily fix the fundamental issue behind the botched firing without process. Resolving the situation with Monica is a prerequisite for quite a few people to earn back that trust.

Comment: I kinda want to chalk this one up to the fact that there _wasn't_ a clear and followed policy which led to Monica's abrupt dismissal.  The absence of a policy would, in my mind, be enough to see to it that things like this "happen" without what others would consider due process.

Comment: @Makoto Then the right course of action would be to reinstate Monica instead of "standing by the hard decision" to abruptly fire her without due process.

Comment: @ColleenV:  Sorry, this process isn't about Monica.  This is about **making sure that some *other* moderator doesn't get treated as badly as Monica did.**  That's how I'm reading it, anyway.

Comment: I will note that there *was* a process, and that it was completely ignored.

Comment: You're functioning under they assumption that they believe they did something wrong.  I haven't seen anything to suggest, at least specific to Monica's case, SE believes that. Which I guess in the end is their right. It's their company, their rules. I don't like it but if the bosses have spoken then...

Comment: @SolveIt Yea, every time I read one of these posts I keep thinking "What's the point of creating a new policy if the old one wasn't used?"

Comment: @Mast - Ah, but they'll follow it this time, honest.

Comment: There are other options. See [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336246/is-it-time-for-stack-exchange-inc-and-the-community-to-legally-separate-amicabl) and [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/336303/628364) for two possibilities.

Comment: Based on my reading of the proposed process, it *allows* for exactly what happened to Monica to happen again.  Step 1: CM decides there is a problem.  Step 2: CM unilaterally removes moderator status.

Comment: @Richard I haven't read anywhere that they intend to follow the new process any closer than the old one. To my knowledge, they just said "we didn't follow process, so let's make a new process".

Comment: @Makoto If Monica had *just* been fired I would agree. But Monica was fired over the CoC, which was being amended. That SO had a knee-jerk response in firing her is a secondary concern. If she can be fired as a moderator for Kafkaesque reasons, every user is at risk of punishment. If SO will not treat her equitably in a process they set up in response to their own admitted screw-up, what hope do we have that we will be treated any better?

Answer (score 194):

These processes miss the point.

All of the company's current big issues with the community boil down to one issue: The company lost a lot of goodwill and trust.

Without trust, review processes that work must rely on transparency and consistency. A written process theoretically creates some consistency, but unless it's accompanied by transparency or trust, in practice people won't know if the process is followed correctly, fairly, and impartially.

Keep in mind how all of this looks: The company fired a moderator, refused to let her know why, then the company posted some seemingly false and slanderous accusations against the moderator, missed 4 separate opportunities to apologize and own up to their mistakes, and now, weeks later, graciously allows the moderator to ask to be let back in, if she promises, so to speak, "to stop beating her wife".

This looks bad. If what actually happened is any better than the above summary, the company should be desperate to create more transparency.

Comment: This, but the collapse didn't begin with the loss of trust. Losing trust was a consequence of changing the site's primary focus from programming to socially engineering programmers.

Comment: I see no reason why a rational person would engage with this site. It is built ENTIRELY on contributions from un-reimbursed volunteers.  These volunteers serve at the whim of people with a political agenda diametrically opposed to the very premise of meritocracy.  Or in the words of WOPR from the movie 'War Games' -- The only winning move is to not play.  I will continue to farm SE for answers.  I will not contribute ANYTHING that could be used against me in the kangaroo court they have established.

Comment: @Terry its not even a kangaroo court - they implemented a star chamber.

Answer (score 171):

### There is no protection against directed findings

The only people who can take decisions on moderator removal and reinstatement are community managers (CM). All CM are part of the same corporate hierarchy. The same person, or a very small set of persons, decides whether all CM will keep earning their living tomorrow.

This means that Stack Overflow, Inc. management can direct findings, either overtly or implicitly. If a CM knows that their boss wants a moderator removed or reinstated, but their personal conviction goes in the other direction, they'll have to make a hard choice between going with their conscience and keeping their job.

A fair process must:

- avoid such conflicts of interest and loyalty;
- in such a way that everybody involved (especially employees) can be sure that there will be no retaliation;
- and in such a way that the community can trust that the people involved felt safe against retaliation.

This is a difficult governance problem. There is both a high need for confidentiality (especially so that if a moderator does something wrong, the victims know that they won't face retaliation) and high trust (which is hard to guarantee without openness). There is some inspiration to be had with whistleblower processes which face the same difficulty.

I don't see how this problem could be solved without involving non-employees in the process. There needs to be some independent oversight. In the first few years of Stack Overflow, Jeff was the benevolent dictator. It worked because Jeff was “one of us”. Those days are long over. SOI is a mostly faceless corporation that has already demonstrated that it does not have the best interest of the community in mind. This cannot be resolved by company-internal processes.

Comment: Excellent answer.  You do a good job explaining the exact reasons why the standard corporate approach for granting positions is incompatible with the justice system they are trying to establish, something I briefly alluded to [in my answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/336253/307622).

Comment: Gilles, my edit would probably be rejected for being "too minor" so I'm not gonna make it, but I believe you meant "Those days" instead of "These days". If this is the case, would you please fix  it and then flag my comment for removal. :)

Comment: @286110 [Should it be “those”, really?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/516166/these-days-are-over-vs-those-days-are-over)

Comment: [Legally separating Stack Exchange, Inc and the community](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336246/is-it-time-for-stack-exchange-inc-and-the-community-to-legally-separate-amicabl) could really help making these conflicts of interest go away.

Comment: @Gilles I'm not good with English grammar here, but the period deemed good here by you is the period that coincided with Jeff as the benevolent dictator, and since we are way past that period I think "those" fits here instead of "these".

Comment: “SOI is a mostly faceless corporation”.I don’t think so, majority of recent actions were done by the Director of Public Q&A or her subordinates(most likely by her order).If Jeff was the benevolent dictator, Sara is evil dictator of Public Q&A. She has support from top management, that seems do not understand the damage causing by her actions.

Comment: There are a few people on [topanswers](https://topanswers.xyz/) thinking about starting a *nix community. If there is any chance that's something you might consider getting involved with, we'd appreciate the opportunity to have a chat.

Comment: @JackDouglas I am aware of topanswers, I wasn't aware of communities beyond database, thanks for letting me know. Where are the discussions happening? Is there a summary of where topanswers is at in terms of features? Last I looked it didn't have downvotes, so it wasn't ready to host quality content.) Have you advertised in [/dev/chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/26/dev-chat)?

Comment: I like to have the general discussion [here on TA](https://topanswers.xyz/meta?q=530) but I'd be happy to discuss with you anywhere else that suited you — and I will bring it up in /dev/chat, thanks. Regarding downvotes, we are ready to add them as soon as we are sure they are more of a benefit that a hindrance. We are having that discussion [here](https://topanswers.xyz/meta?q=243#question). Several of us, like yourself, have been moderators on SE for many years, and opinion is divided — and I'd love to know how many top two answer positions would be different on SE if downvotes were removed.

Answer (score 155):

**This does not address the core issue**

This must be called out, again, and again, until an answer is recived.

Monica was suspended without a warning, and [accused of violating the CoC](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334551/an-apology-to-our-community-and-next-steps/334605#334605). [This has been brought up time and time again](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/334269/408593). No process, not matter how detailed, can work where the party is presumed guilty, and until SE, either reinstates Monica and apologizes for slandering her, or provides evidence to back their claims, or Monica declares SE has managed this privately and she is satisfied, no process that is created will have any validity, or indeed moral authority, as the issuing party has shown itself unable to engage the community with the necessary transparency to convince me that *any* process will be followed. Especially one like this, that relies on CMs, rather than the users.

[Monica remains unsatisfied](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334551/an-apology-to-our-community-and-next-steps/334646#334646)

Comment: This is not about Monica specific, period.

Comment: @Luuklag Yes it is. Its impossible to disentangle the Monica's treatment from this attempt to justify it post-fact. Here's a pretty decent explanation of why: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/336117/408593

Comment: repeatedly asserting "This is not about Monica" is merely an attempt to control the debate through intimidation.  Either there is a debate between two sides who disagree but respect one another, in which case both sides must engage with the other's points, or there is an autocratic entity that controls truth and compels speech.  Repeatedly asserting that others opinions are not valid is not inclusive and does not advance the values on which SE was built.

Comment: If this is not about Monica, then it's about the intent to do to others what they did to her.  That is even worse than it just being about her.

Answer (score 122):

The last process we had was completely ignored. What happens the next time a CM decides there should be an exception?

Comment: According to JNat, [*it won't happen because there's a process to prevent it*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336177/feedback-post-moderator-review-and-reinstatement-processes?page=2&tab=votes#comment1111911_336224).

Comment: The new policy allows for retroactive following by claiming the removal was an "emergency". A term which is conveniently undefined.

Comment: Coming from StackOverflow background: "FEATURE FREEZE! We only accept emergency hotfixes now!!!" Cue every feature being rebranded as "emergency hotfix." Sounds familiar? But sure, This Time It Will Be Different.

Answer (score 121):

In the restoration process, Discovery phase, step 2.1,

> If CM1 finds any annotation that states reinstatement is deemed impossible, the request is denied....

Under what conditions would such an annotation be added to the former moderator's account? Neither the Moderator Conduct Review Process nor the Moderator Action Review Process seem to indicate who has the authority to make such an annotation or what circumstances must be found to exist for such an annotation to be made. Is such a clause intended only for the worst of the worst, the remorseless "serial killers" of the moderation world, or is it intended as a standard annotation to be used in most cases of moderator removal?

Comment: Almost duplicate of [yonder answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/336188), but this is more comprehensive.

Comment: Yes. these annotations should be considered *extremely* rare and particularly substantiated. They should not be considered standard at all. The bulk of (unrequested) moderator removals are for going dormant and failing to respond to emails checking in. None of these would include an annotation like this.

Comment: @Catija I'm sure that's the case, but nobody was worried about the typical removal anyway. The whole point of having a process is to fairly deal with difficult cases.

Comment: @Catija This procedure, from our perspective, is to protect us from you. Such annotations should make no difference at all, since if a moderator should never be reinstated there'll be reasons for that _beyond_ "you've got a User-Is-Evil flag, sorry-not-sorry". This step should just be completely removed.

Comment: @Catija so an "ordinary" CoC violation (one that is not extremely grievous), like calling someone an idiot for posting an off-topic question or using the old cover sheet on a TPS report, would not result in such a bar? Or is this intended to cover non-CoC violations versus *any* CoC violation (with any CoC violation resulting in a bar)?

Comment: I fear (*read: lack of trust*) that this step 2.1 is there for one and only one purpose: so that after ratification and before reviewing Monica's case, someone can add an annotation stating "reinstatement of this former moderator is impossible", thus not just permitting but *forcing* CM1 to deny reinstatement and end the process right there, in order to avoid the embarrassment (for SE) of what a genuine reinstatement review would entail

Answer (score 99):

> #### Initiation
>
> The process is started when the Community Management Team is made aware of an issue. This can be a complaint against a moderator, or the Team being made aware of a security issue (like a moderator's account appearing to be compromised).
>
> #### Emergency Removal Phase
>
> The CM (CM1) who "stumbles upon" the issue will take care of it.
>   Moderator access should be removed immediately, to limit the potential for any further damage. Available info is documented.

This looks like what happened to Monica. I can understand why a security issue or compromised account would warranting immediate, unilateral action; however, I'm still bothered that "a complaint against a moderator" is grounds for immediate removal.

I suppose this explains why calls for Monica's immediate reinstatement have seemingly been ignored and gone unheard. SE still feels like they made the right move; now they've put a process in place that conveniently justifies and codifies their prior actions.

[Complaints against moderators](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3302/i-demand-resignation-of-a-moderator-who-deleted-my-on-topic-comments) are part of the business of moderating. You can't please all of the people all of the time.

I'm very disappointed in the way this is heading. Had the procedure said that, in the case of complaints, the Emergency Removal Phase ***will** be skipped* (instead of ***can** be skipped*), my concerns would be allayed. However, as written, I don't like how skipping is merely an option.

Comment: "In the event of a security issue, the Emergency Removal Phase is initiated; in the event of any other complaint [...], that step can be skipped" This seems to indicate that emergency removal will be used for security issues only, with regular complaints using the non-emergency process.

Comment: @DavisB - I suppose I'm concerned about the wording there. If the procedure said _**will** be skipped_ instead of _**can** be skipped_, my concerns would be allayed.

Comment: might want to edit the question in that case, to make it clear that the can/will distinction is your objection here. Otherwise it just looks like you missed a few lines in the policy.

Comment: @DavisB - I took your sage advice and have edited my post accordingly.

Comment: "We made a decision to act quickly, which I personally approved, but in doing so skipped several critical parts of the process." [cto apology] Does that help? From the list of anticipated reasons it seems pretty clear to me emergency removal is about time-critical stuff. "This feedback should always be the first option if the moderator could have simply failed to perceive their actions as problematic." [policy] I'm not seeing your reading of the policy.

Comment: I'm kinda happier with the blanket "extremely out of character" and "other unanticipated incidents", than trying to go into greater detail to map out what it looks like for a trusted moderator to suddenly become damaging to the site or users. I'm put in mind of this [alledged example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phineas_Gage). **Content warning** for extreme injury, also philosophical discussion and historical debate.

Comment: ...Semi-relevant question, what happens in the case of complaints against community-facing company employees?

Comment: Moreover, why can't emergency halts be accomplished by a suspension rather than the much more severe demodding?

Comment: @Numeron: A suspended mod can unsuspend themselves, if memory serves, and in fact I believe this has actually been tested by mods in the past, just to see what would happen. That is, the software does not treat suspension as a temporary demodding: they still retain the mod power to issue and remove suspensions of any user. Diamond removal is, for technical reasons, the only way to actually stop a mod from using their privileges.

Comment: That seems like a bizarre and somewhat serious oversight, @NathanTuggy. o.o  I'm curious why it's set up that way.

Comment: @JustinTime: It's never been considered important enough to fix, since the designed way to temporarily halt a (potentially) rogue mod is just to remove their diamond (and then suspend if still necessary), then put it back when done. Mod tools in general, since they're in-house software used by probably less than a thousand people *ever* (~600 current moderators, a few hundred past moderators), are kind of rough around the edges.

Comment: Fair enough, @NathanTuggy.  Still comes across as a bit weird, though, even if there's a good reason for it. ;P

Answer (score 82):

What constitutes an "emergency" for removal purposes?  While an emergency by its very name indicates that things must be expedited to prevent ongoing harm, I think that this needs to be defined better, so that the vagueness of one word in a policy cannot be used as a sole justification for a removal.  I certainly hope that expressing disagreement is not an "emergency".

I don't know if a list of things that constitutes an emergency is desired, or a list of things that are *not* emergencies, or both.  But this needs elaborating.

Funny how no one really thought about what constitutes an emergency before.  But just thinking about why we need this: it's about something many others and I have pointed out plenty of times recently.  It's a matter of trust.

This is just one case of needing to "get it in writing".  The times when people need to get it in writing are when working with other parties/groups where the trust level isn't high enough given the importance: the mortgage company when getting a home loan, contract review, credit card companies, lawyers, etc.

With trust firmly in place, so many people wouldn't be questioning, nitpicking, and just generally being cynical about all Meta interactions.

In addition to getting the process right, do the right thing and regain the community's trust.

Comment: +1.  Was Monica's removal an "emergency" according to this new process?  (If so, it stretches the definition of "emergency" to "because a SE employee wanted to do it now...")

Comment: Emergencies generally center around possible account compromise (and actions that look like it), misuse of private information (PII, particularly), or even mod-only userscripts that have gone awry and are removing content while the mod sleeps. These are serious security threats for which a diamond removal can't be delayed due to the special access the diamond grants.

Comment: @Catija Can we take that as a "no"?

Comment: @Goyo Either way, I'd like to hear SE's official position on this.

Comment: I don't think that defining emergency is that important.... what *is* important is that any emergency measure is only temporary, e.g., limited to at most one week and thereafter either confirmed by a regular process or automatically undone.

Comment: @SolveIt definitely a no

Comment: Definitely more of a "can't comment because lawyers are involved", IMHO.

Answer (score 78):

I mentioned this on the Moderator Team site, but never had time to come back to it and follow-up:

For a re-instatement, will the information gathered during the Discovery phase be shared with the former moderator?

It seems to be mentioned in the removal process that the moderator will be informed of what's happening, but it's not completely clear there, and it's not mentioned in the re-instatement process that the former moderator will be told specifically why they were removed.

Comment: This was the first thing that came to my mind as I read through the processes.

Comment: Yeah, complete transparency would seem to require this, albeit with redactions where necessary to prevent sharing of sensitive information (although the need for that should be minimal, as the focus should be on the moderator’s own actions, and there are no privacy concerns in sharing one’s own actions with them).

Comment: Do you mean in the case that the request for reinstatement is denied?

Comment: @Catija I meant in any case...  Ideally a mod would be given the specifics when they're removed, but in cases where that doesn't happen "on the way out," it should be part of the process to come back.

Comment: Oh, you specifically say "for a re-instatement"... If the reinstatement is deemed uneventful and just passed through the process and confirmed, is there a reason to mention anything found in Discovery?

Comment: @Catija A reason ?  It's called being honest.  Not "mentioning" things found in discovery is called "covering up things".  The expression "honesty is the best policy" leaps to mind, although not in terms of recent SE management actions.

Comment: @Catija In my original comment in the Moderator's Team, I was specifically referring to the re-instatement process because that's where I thought the term "discovery" was most appropriate.  And to me, "Discovery" implies that both parties have all the information.  Ideally, both parties would have the information during a removal, but in addition to the current Monica situation (where she wasn't told why), I can imagine a re-instatement where the former mod doesn't have all the info, e.g. if it's after a long-ish period of time.

Comment: @StephenG I’m gonna to need you to explain... an example, maybe? When is a time that a mod requests reinstatement, that reinstatement is granted without debate... what is there to disclose?

Comment: @Catija Seriously ?  The reasons for the removal (including whether they were in error or a deliberate act of malice or seemed justified and if so why) *and* the reasons for the reinstatement.  People need to see that justice is done and why things happened.  I am flabbergasted that you need this explained to you.

Comment: @StephenG I think we’re coming at this from two different assumptions... most of the time the reason for reinstatement is “because they asked to be reinstated.”

Comment: @Catija I think you're right in that the two of you are looking at it from different POVs. You appear to be looking at it from: moderator asked to resign and asked to be reinstated. StephenG appears to be looking at it from the point of view: moderator was removed not at their request and has now asked for reinstatement (possibly not knowing why they were removed). In the future, moderators will, hopefully, have had the reasons for removal communicated to them during the removal process. At this time, that is not necessarily the case for any moderator who was previously removed.

Comment: @Catija Moderators elected by the members and removed by the elected moderators should **not** be reinstated without explanation to the members - this challenges the (alleged) trust relationship that is supposed to exist.  Likewise elected moderators removed by SE management and subsequently reinstated need to have a clear explanation (which they are free to publish) explaining why they were removed and why they were reinstated (and what remedies were applied).  This is natural justice for moderators, the members who elect them and the managers.  Justice is open, not secret.

Comment: @Catija, policies like this should be written with the exceptional case in mind. In the more mundane cases, people will naturally take shortcuts and/or combine steps (like combining the communication about being reinstated with the message about what was found during the discovery phase).

Comment: @Catija Here is a decent example. A community manager has a bad day and  demods 5 random people they are prejudice against and then try to cover it up by claiming those 5 people violated policies without any evidence for that. When those 5 mods are reinstated (assuming anyone figures out what happened), they should be notified that it was a community manager being a jerk and that the person has been scolded or reprimanded or maybe even outright fired. It is an extreme example, yes, but feel free to insert any idiotic reason onto a trigger-happy CM having a bad day and a get a good example.

Comment: @Catija If a user was banned or kicked out of any group and they don't know why that either means the ban was in error, or the user didn't learn from what happened. For the same reason you get an email telling you why a suspension has occurred from the moderators, a moderator should be told why they were demodded - period either when reapllying or at the time of demodding. The only exception would be the incredibly obvious cases where a moderator was demodded because they asked or because their bot broke and it was ***temporary*** hotfix.

Answer (score 78):

Regarding the reinstatement process.

> Community Managers (CMs) can recuse themselves if they feel they can't be impartial

Is it the case that a CM should also generally recuse themselves if they were involved in that moderator's removal process?

Comment: That might be ideal, but there are not that many CMs.

Comment: This is like filing an appeal to a court, only to find you are facing the same judge again.

Comment: Yes, this is absurd. What moderator who feels they were justified (or wants a certain state of affairs) would *ever* recuse themselves? It shouldn't be voluntary—it should be essential. No moderator involved with the original decision should have *any* say in anything to do with the reinstatement process.

Comment: @JasonBassford Manager. CMs are staff, community managers, not moderators. There's only seven of us and four or even six could have been involved in the process of removing a moderator since the first event leads to a warning and the second to removal. If it was six, that leaves only one person on the CM team... and at least two, if not three are required for reinstatement. We can not require that they all recuse themselves.

Comment: @Catija In that case, it's impossible for the process to be impartial. You've pretty much said that the process is a fait accompli.

Comment: @JasonBassford Except for one thing... it’s completely hypothetical. No mods have been removed with the process at this point and the existing process for mod removal has been used once. So saying that it’s impossible and we can’t be impartial when it’s not even a concern... these processes may change over time as we put them to the test. Your concern may be completely valid... but on the time scale I’ve seen (one removal in 7 years), I think we can see how it goes?

Comment: @Catija But that's not how due process (or planning) works. As an earlier comment said, if you appeal a decision from a judge, the legal system does not have the same judge rule on your appeal. It's only common sense. I don't see how my concern could *not* be valid. You are also splitting hairs—because you know perfectly well that Monica was removed. Saying that it wasn't with *the process* is a convenient blinder to the issue. You've had her wait, on the premise that it's for this process to come out. Saying now that the reinstatement process doesn't cover her situation is disingenuous.

Comment: @JasonBassford Well, fortunately, all seven CMs are available even by your standards to address Monica's request, should she make one.

Comment: @Catija is [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/99341/188189) out of date then as it lists 12 people, not 7.

Comment: @Catija My point is that not all seven *should* be involved. It should be much less than that. Assuming it's even possible at this point for anything about this to be impartial.

Comment: @RobertLongson Community Team != Community Managers

Comment: @Catija That question says _Who are the Community Team (sometimes referred to as the Community Managers or CM's), and what is their role?_ and the answer doesn't say _Community Team_ doesn't mean _Community Managers_. I guess that is what confuses Robert. If that answer is wrong, it should be corrected.

Comment: @Catija perhaps the real issue then is having 5-6 people all crammed together deciding if a moderator is removed or not. Or maybe there needs to be more people involved so that way an appeal *can* be impartial. I believe the problem everyone has is that there is nothing tangible to prevent outright malice from a community manager or series of community managers from demodding random users with no ability to appeal.

Answer (score 78):

The real, essential problem that I see (that actually might not be able to be resolved, because of the underlying conflict of interest between company and community):

- Moderators get to their position via a democratic process, an election within the **user community** of a specific site on the stack exchange network. ( And note: "all" users are asked to vote. It is not like the moderator community decides for new padawans, invites them and later announces "they joined the force". )
- Yet, "firing" them is something that **solely** happens within Stack Exchange Inc.!

I understand that the *company* is running the servers, and I understand their need to able to act immediately to emergencies such as compromised user ids.

But for any other kind of depriving a moderator of his status, the *user community* should have a say. At a **minimum** by having all other elected moderators being able to *vote* on that. The idea that solely CMs working for Stack Exchange Inc. determine what is going to happen isn't convincing. Any more.

In the past, the moderator status was subject to decisions by Stack Exchange Inc. only. And when 99.99% of the users trust the company, why not?

**But going forward from here**: if Stack Exchange Inc. is **serious** about listening the community again, then a "moderator firing process" that doesn't include some form of **community** input is **not** going to regain the trust you lost.

I can see the *company* POV: the company paying for the servers specifies polices, such as the code of conduct. That affects their business, which in the end pays the servers. That drives the need to deal with conduct violations, especially when committed by moderators. But that doesn't dictate that Stack Exchange Inc. should be the **sole** party making such decisions in a unilateral way. And as said: we are at a point where we need **real** actions that make a **real** difference.

Thus my suggestion: step back and find ways to *incorporate* the community into this crucial policy/process!

Comment: It might "make sense" that company calls all the shots, but it is far from the only solution or even a proven superior concept. In the end such concept says the company doesn't trust its own community in any way, and wants to keep an asymmetric, even aristocratic, power structure in place. But [Co-determination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Co-determination) would be one way out or at least worth exploring?

Comment: @LаngLаngС Reworded the last sentence, maybe that helps.

Comment: Yup. Just to add: My POV is that especially things like the CoC should be "up for discussion" (as outright denied in theregister article). A community is "more inclusive" when it and all its members are included in the decision making fundamental policies as well. Agency, legitimacy and outcome can be better that way. As already promised: ["Meta Stack Exchange … ***It's built and run by you*** "](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tour)

Comment: Perhaps a middle ground could be that the _reinstatement_ process is voted by the community, similar to actual elections, but the _firing_ process is handled by the company themselves so they can act quickly if they feel the need to.

Comment: This. This is by far the most important thing to be taken into consideration here. Anyone claiming this cannot be done for "legal reasons" is mistaken because everything on this website is **already public**. Anything other than a private moderator chat is basically open for review anyway, and there's no reason to state that the chat cannot be public for the purposes of such inquiries. We need to be able to do this properly by having the community decide. Furthermore, by making the process public it prevents a rogue mod from lying and causing a community division.

Comment: Cont. (disclaimer: I do not believe Monica is lying. This a hypothetical.) suppose Monica is 100% lying and that what actually occurred is that she cursed out a CM in response to nothing worthy of that sort of attitude. Do we have any way to tell whether that would be true or not? No, we actually don't. However, the entire community (in meta at least) is split ***because we can't see the logs***. Either stack exchange is being secretive to protect themselves or a moderator is pulling us down a wild goose chase. We need to have the community *at least* provide input and review the evidence...

Answer (score 74):

**tl;dr: Does being removed as a moderator result in an *ineligibility* to stand for election? If so, does the ineligibility apply only on the site(s) where the moderator was actually removed/de-modded, or does it apply to *all* sites?**

How does the moderator restoration procedure relate to a former moderator getting elected or re-elected by a community? I asked this [a while back](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/334728/336163) and never got an official answer.

The moderator reinstatement process seems to indicate that a favorable result for the former moderator results in *immediate* restoration of their diamond, without any need for an election or even any community involvement at all. Is this intended to imply that the former moderator may *alternately* choose to seek restoration by being elected or re-elected by one of the Stack Exchange communities, or is it intended as the *sole* restoration process and/or a *prerequisite* for becoming an election candidate?

[This](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/336194/336163) answer asks specifically about a former moderator seeking election on the community that they formerly moderated, but there's also the possibility that such a person might seek election *elsewhere*. The Initiation section of the restoration process states:

> Previous moderators (PM) may request reinstatement through the /contact form on the site that they wish to be reinstated....

Thus, it isn't clear if this reinstatement procedure even *applies* to a moderator seeking election in another community. What happens in that case? For example, suppose I was dismissed as a moderator for cause from Shoes and Ships Stack Exchange. I contribute quietly for a sufficiently long period of time (e.g. at least a year, to allow any possible general site suspension-related bars to expire), eventually deciding to leave my old haunt alone and instead seek moderatorship on Sealing Wax.SE, which I have never moderated before. What happens in that case?

- Do I have to seek reinstatement on Shoes and Ships.SE before I can stand for election on Sealing Wax.SE?
- May I just go ahead and run, letting the community determine if I am worthy?
- Do I have to apply for "reinstatement" on Sealing Wax.SE despite the fact that I have never actually been a moderator there?
- Do I have to begin a "generic" reinstatement process that does not give me back my original diamond, but restores my ability to stand for election?

Comment: Those are some interesting example communities... :P

Comment: @V2Blast they are from Lewis Carroll. The entire mess is very *Wonderland* like.

Comment: @ColumbiasaysReinstateMonica, especially when you read Wonderland as a surreal horror story.

Comment: @ColumbiasaysReinstateMonica Rather than Lewis Carroll, I think Franz Kafka is closer to the mark.

Answer (score 72):

I once heard of a consulting project in the IT sector to get certain changes made on a bunch of computers.  One million dollars and one year later, there was a gigantic multi-page flow chart with an overwhelmingly complex administrative process for how the changes would be made, that no one ever read, and the changes never got made.

These processes read a lot like that.  You have a pretty diagram, and someone obviously put in a lot of work to write a process that *sounds* good.  They can show it to their boss, and obviously they are doing the assigned task of writing up a formal process.

Except that no moderators have been reinstated, and there are *giant, obvious, glaring* flaws in the processes presented.  (There are 43 answers already, most of them detailing specific flaws, so I don't feel the need to point out *all* the specific flaws in this answer.)

What I think is that **you are attempting to combine incompatible goals.**

You want to create a formal, transparent process for removal and reinstatement of a moderator that will be fair and equitable.

And you want to run Stack Exchange as a for-profit company, with people assigned to jobs using normal corporate reasons for giving positions.  Including the people assigned to approve or disapprove reinstatement proceedings.

These goals are not compatible.  You need to recognize that what you are *attempting* to do amounts to creation of a new system for justice, that *will* in fact be just and equitable and fair, and benefit the group as well as not harming the individuals to whom it is applied.

That's a tall order.

Ultimately, all the formal processes in the world won't help unless you recognize *who* you are attempting to restrain.  If the company is restraining itself, and the company has the power to remove that restraint "in case of emergency," then the system is fundamentally, *irreparably* broken.

That's not to say that you can't have justice.  You've actually done quite well for years.  Like with a benevolent monarch who rules well, there is no outcry for more formalized procedures because people *have* justice.  Conversely, when you have injustice, it doesn't matter what procedures you have in place to legitimize it and mislabel it as justice—people will still not be happy.

You can write up all the procedures you want, but at the end of the day it amounts to slapping a veneer of formality onto the arbitrary decision of a few CMs and thereby elevating that arbitrary decision to the righteous plateau of unquestionability.

I would prefer NO formal process at all, than to have a formal process that can be held up as an *excuse* for irresponsible or damaging actions.

**If you see the need to take action, then take responsibility for the actions you take, and don't shuffle off that responsibility onto "the process."**

That requires a high level of responsibility in a CM.  But really, that's what's required anyway, to make the whole show work.  Moderators and CMs show this level of responsibility all the time.  Except in the case of Monica.

There *already* was a process for moderator removal.  It was not followed.  So let's not fix what wasn't broken.  No process in the world can work if it is not followed, and attempting to "fix" it will just overcomplicate everything.

Comment: [Gilles' answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/336280/307622) covers similar points, such as how Jeff was a benevolent dictator that made the setup work, rather than the faceless corporation we have today.

Answer (score 71):

## How can we trust you to use this process going forward?

I presume that Monica's removal would not have happened under the emergency scenarios. That means the previous removal procedure was *at minimum* ignored. I personally believe that SE just completely forgot the old procedure existed. So how can we have faith that the next time you want to remove a mod you will actually use this process?

Comment: Maybe I’m misunderstanding, but I thought that the previous removal procedure was only for when use by moderators (and there were no procedures limiting SE’s actions)?  The introduction to [this policy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/157258/388335) says it is a "process for allowing a team of moderators to remove one of their own”. Am I looking at the wrong thing?

Comment: @divibisan For a long time it was the _only_ mod removal process (short of emergency magic ban hammer from SE for account compromise, etc) . Additionally "The process may also be initiated _by_ the community team at Stack Exchange...". I agree that by rule lawyering the new policy is more applicable to a retroactive application, but at the time in question there was an already existing, obviously applicable, totally ignored policy.

Answer (score 64):

> **Moderator Conduct Review Process:**
>
> From time to time, a moderator on one of our sites may violate their moderator agreement, or the company standards for behavior as documented in our Code of Conduct. Such behavior may eventually necessitate their removal from office, however both community expectations and our Code prescribe that, **in general and whenever possible, they first be warned and given an opportunity to correct their behavior.**

**1.** Does “*be warned and given an opportunity to correct their behavior*” also refer to Monica's case?
If it does, when can we look forward to seeing her readmitted?

There is nothing written in the two processes that suggest it cannot be applied retrospectively.

Answer (score 57):

The Reinstatement Process mentioned checking for annotations deeming reinstatement impossible.  I expected to see the criteria for determining and applying such annotations in the Review policies but didn't.  What is the criteria for such annotations?

Answer (score 51):

It looks to me like the removal process is still driven by a single CM, with the slight speed bump that they have to convince one other CM of their case (which is pretty easy to do, given that they're the sole participant in the discovery phase). The only fundamental difference I can discern between what's written and what was done to Monica is that there has to be a warning annotation (and without any description of how annotations are created/edited/challenged/etc. there's not really hard evidence that there's a difference there either).

In my opinion, a fundamental tenet of justice that's missing from this process is the ability of the accused to know the charges leveled against them and to see and address the relevant evidence. As long as all the evidence and all the annotations that go into this decision process remain opaque to the accused, there's no way for anyone outside SE, Inc. to differentiate this process from the arbitrary process used in the recent past.

Comment: There's a difference. Removal, except emergencies, requires going through the process at least twice. The first time, the process results in "CM2 will [warn the moderator] (along with suggestions for adjusting behavior), and annotate the account." The next time through process, "if there is an annotation that notes the moderator had previously been warned about the same issue", then the moderator will be removed. I would say that the wording should be adjusted such that the warning to the moderator must be "clear and unambiguous" and clarify that "do so" means warn the moderator.

Comment: As [Catija said](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336177/feedback-post-moderator-review-and-reinstatement-processes?cb=1#comment1112020_336236) in a comment to Monica's reply - there are no annotations on her account for the past 3 years. Go figure that one out!

Answer (score 48):

What will, if anything, change to the process of re-instating a PM when a senior company official (Think CEO, CFO, CTO, Director of [insert department here]) was involved in the original revoking of PM's moderation rights.

Will CM's be allowed to overturn this decision by senior company official's?

Comment: *Narrator: No.*

Comment: Given that the "senior company official" can remove the employment of a CM.........

Comment: @IanRingrose, exactly what fueled my question.

Comment: I guess that will be regarded by the CM as an "annotation that states reinstatement is deemed impossible".

Comment: The real solution would be that senior company official can't revoke a PM's mod rights, and that they are by default the person you appeal to when someone at the same level is unavailable. They shouldn't need to get involved other than to note that their subordinate booted someone and double check that the process was followed. They are a *supervisor* for the CM's not a super-CM, and they shouldn't EVER micromanage PERIOD. Even in an emergency situation, a CM can lock out the person. It should be the absolute last resort and only done when waiting even ten minutes might cause *legal* trouble.

Answer (score 46):

> 2. CM1 will look through account annotations for reasons for removal. Annotations weren't always a feature, so CM1 will also consult with the rest of the Community Management and Community Strategy (CST) teams for any extra context.
>
> > 1. If CM1 finds any annotation that states reinstatement is deemed impossible, the request is denied and the reasons for it will be stated back to PM. The process is concluded here.

There needs to be an investigation into the correctness of the annotation.  As it stands, it's possible to apply a permanent, unappealable veto to any reinstatement request for any reason or no reason at all.

Comment: This.  An annotation that precludes reinstatement should only be issued in extreme circumstances.  Therefore, any such annotation should be subject to a review process, to make sure that people with the power to make annotations don't abuse it.

Answer (score 43):

One question specifically about international sites.

> 2. CMs can recuse themselves if they feel they can't be impartial. CM1, CM2, and CM3 will be picked at random from remaining CM pool.
> 3. CM1 will review data and research concerns - look through account annotations, query the involved parties, etc. If there is a note to
>      check with the Community Strategy Team (CST), they'll do so: the CST
>      may have information relevant for next steps.

There is only one CM responsible for all international sites. So, even **if CM recuse himself when he feels he can't be impartial**, other CM's will learn about the situation from his point of view. For SOru it's especially important, because there is only one russian speaking CM in your team. Basically, the whole process in the case of disagreements between mod and this CM will be biased.

Any suggestions for this case?

Comment: This is perhaps an extreme case, but the concern is not specific to RUSO or even international sites; everything comes with a perspective, a filter. The rationale for having multiple - at minimum 2 - CMs involved is to reduce this distortion, but it cannot be entirely eliminated. The role of CM2 is particularly critical in this, akin to the original role of the devil's advocate: they must test the claim, ensure that it has merit. That may in some cases require drawing on additional resources to assert the veracity of statements made by CM1.

Comment: @Shog9 thanks! Looks good in theory. I hope we will never examine it on practice.

Answer (score 43):

In a perfect world, where the majority of us still retain some trust in Stack Exchange, this would work.

However, we're not presently in this world. That means that this will work out to be at best a paper tiger.

A real impartial process would include a company external arbitrator or panel of arbitrators and a public evidence phase akin to the arbitration committee that Wikipedia uses for these purposes.

If you're serious about earning back the trust you lost, the process needs to be completely decoupled from the interests of the company, and the company needs to agree to be bound by the decisions of the external arbitrator (s). Moderators serve their communities, and it should fall to members of these communities to assess the evidence and make a fair determination.

Answer (score 42):

> ### Moderator Action Review Process
>
> #### Proceedings
>
> 9. If the consensus was for removal, we will then revoke the privileges of the moderator to be removed, and also **remove the moderator's name from the election** and /users?tab=moderators **pages**.

Why?

I get the part about removing them from the moderators tab (because they are no longer a mod), but they *were* elected/appointed -- so why "rewrite history" by removing them from the election page?

Comment: The same reason a company tries to distance itself from a problem employee who's made the news, I guess. Bad publicity. Not wanting to associate themselves with "bad apples".

Comment: @Script47 But it wasn't the company the ones who elected the mod. It was the community. If anything, leaving the election page as-is shows that the company does not hesitate to intervene and "fix problems" caused by community decisions (like electing a mod that is not fit for the job); stock holders love that kind of things. It also serves as a reminder for the community itself to choose wiselier next time. Redacting election pages as if problematic mods were never elected in the first place rings an orwellian bell and there's no real need (IMHO) to do so.

Comment: You see presidents around the world being impeached all the time. What you don't see is people removing their names from history textbooks.

Comment: Having the name on the election page provides something to refer to when the question is inevitably asked "How did one person without a diamond close this question?" -- the election page is the evidence that they did once have the diamond.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_hole

Comment: @walen, they remove the badthinker because he who controls the present controls the future. He who controls the past controls the present.

Answer (score 41):

> This [reinstatement] process is available to all moderators, whether elected or appointed, regardless of whether they stepped down on their own or were removed from their position for any reason

Pro tempore moderators of beta sites currently lose their position when a site holds its first election after graduation. They would now be entitled to being reinstated at any time. Is this an oversight or a policy change?

Comment: This is exactly what I was wondering.  Obviously, policy has changed to some extent, since in the past, pro-tems were unable to request re-instatement.  I wonder if this "loophole" is permitted because the re-instatement process is more defined than before, and includes a full consent from the current moderator team.  No idea; just wondering.

Comment: If I would just step down a minute before the election result I would qualify for the process as written. :-)

Answer (score 41):

What is even the point of writing down this process? If SO doesn't follow it they will just say "Yeah we didn't follow the process, but we don't re-litigate the past".

SO has demonstrated clearly that the current guiding principle is to **stick with their decisions no matter what**. If process was followed or not, if actions were right or wrong, if people providing value on their sites like it or not - it doesn't matter. Clearly "stick to your decisions" is the guiding management principle, overruling all other concerns. At most some empty words with vague promises for the future will be announced.

So the party in power is not interested in fixing mistakes or modifying past decisions that turned out bad. Something is done and then that's that. If some process wasn't followed - well, bad luck, maybe next time. There is no indication this will change anytime soon.

So, what's the point in writing down rules? They can be ignored whenever convenient.

Answer (score 38):

Could we rename one or other of these policies? "Action Review" vs. "Conduct Review" doesn't make it particularly clear what the purpose of each policy is - the former is for mod teams to use in case of breakdowns, while the latter is for broader community concerns and for CoC/agreement violations.

Calling the former policy something along the lines of "Moderator Team Review Process" should serve to clarify that - it's not actions we're really reviewing, it's whether or not the *team* can continue to work together.

Answer (score 38):

I really don't get it.

> If **CM1 finds** any annotation that states reinstatement is deemed
>   impossible, **the request is denied** and the reasons for it will be
>   stated back to PM. The process is concluded here.

Moderator was elected by a community. It looks strange that one CM decide mod's fate.

And even this:

> Community Managers (CMs) can recuse themselves if they feel they can't
>   be impartial. CM1, CM2, and CM3 will be picked at random from
>   remaining CM pool

If there be any disagreements between mod and one CM, the rest, obviously, will be on the CM's side. How can we be sure of an impartial CM's attitude in this case?

Comment: Annotations are placed on an account by other CMs. You should split off your two questions into separate answers.

Answer (score 38):

This really does nothing to address any of the controversy that has occurred from recent events. Nor do these procedures address anything in terms of possible personal abuse of the system, or the disclosure of information to somebody who has been accused of something.

In short, so long as a couple of CMs agree, there is no *essential* information that's transparently available.

We only have SE's word that three impartial CMs will review any given reinstatement request. But the events over the recent month have done nothing to affirm trust in that word. And even if it were to be believed, there's nothing to prevent one or both of the CMs originally involved in a dismissal decision from being part of a reinstatement decision.

*Voluntary* recusal is unlikely in the case of anybody who wants to keep things as they are—or who doesn't want to be judged negatively due to a reversal of their own decision.

If good faith is to be believed, this might be the start of something reasonable; but if good faith is not to be believed, it's just a toothless justification to keep things as they are and rationalize it after the fact.

Prior to this, I would have hoped for some kind of transparent system of checks and balances. But rather than offering hope, these processes seem to be at best ambiguous in terms of what can and can't be done—and why.

In short, I see nothing here that is really a positive. Yes, something is now spelled out. But it's unclear, vague, and open to any number of interpretations.

Comment: If good faith were to be believed then this would be totally unnecessary. If good faith is not to be believed then this is totally useless.

Answer (score 34):

Aside from many of the points already raised, and without having gone over every last detail of the process:

I note that, in the case of an emergency removal, the reinstatement process is concluded at Discovery.4.1.2 which reads, emphasis original:

> If an Emergency Removal took place and it's since been explained, and no further action is needed, moderator access can be restored, and any appropriate security measures should be communicated. **The process is concluded here.**

Key word: "can".

*I fully understand that there may be times when moderator access needs to be revoked on short notice to prevent further immediate harm to a site or the network as a whole.* Such scenarios, I feel it goes without really saying, *should be exceedingly rare.* What looks like a compromised account certainly can be one example of such a scenario.

However, any emergency removal of moderator powers must **explicitly be with the full understanding and recognition by all parties involved that such removal of powers is strictly temporary and done *only* in order to prevent further *immediate* harm.**

The moderator who had their powers removed under this emergency authority should then *immediately* be contacted, presented with the evidence, and given the opportunity to explain what happened, **or** go through the full review process *as if* their moderator powers had not been removed in the first place (in other words, the review would have to find evidence requiring the moderator to be removed; it would not have to find evidence allowing the moderator to be reinstated). I realize that collecting the evidence in a reasonably presentable form could take a short while, but I can see no plausible reason why such a contact, including presenting the evidence, shouldn't be possible within, say, 24 hours.

**If, and only if, any of (a) communication, (b) further review of the events that prompted the emergency removal, or (c) the prolonged lack of a response, indicates both that the activity was actively malicious *and* on the part of the moderator themselves, should moderator access *not* be restored. In all other cases of emergency removals, *moderator access should be restored by default* once the situation has been resolved through mutual communication.**

This does not preclude the possibility of communicating appropriate security measures as part of, or as a precondition for, restoration of moderator access. It also does not, for example in cases of inappropriate behavior, preclude the possibility of communicating a *clear and specific* warning to the moderator.

As an example, nothing in this is to be taken as preventing such communications from concluding by saying something like: "Make sure you immediately change the password on your account to a secure one. We will be able to restore your diamond once we see that your password has been changed. If your account is used again in the future to vandalize content, as happened with the posts previously referenced, we will have to go through the Moderator Conduct Review Process and possibly permanently remove your moderator access."

Comment: I think (and hope) that "can" means "there is nothing opposing it, so it can be done now (and not earlier)". However ambiguity allows loophols and therefore this should be fixed.

Comment: @GDPR If we were operating in an environment of significant trust, I do believe that one word really wouldn't matter much at all. However, since for a large number of people, trust has been violated (and I think I even saw someone mentioning there existing *negative trust*, in other words, SE having to work on getting people to trust them just to get back to where people neither trust nor mistrust them), we're now operating in an environment where great specificity is required.

Comment: yes. That's what I mean. I'd hope that its the better meaning, but it could be the worse and should therefore be fixed.

Answer (score 33):

I have some concerns that if a former moderator who was removed for cause doesn't think they'll be able to get reinstated through the reinstatement process (or if they went through it and the outcome was to not reinstate them), they might try to work around that by simply attempting to go through the moderator election process again.

I have a question: if a moderator is removed for cause, are they still welcome to nominate themselves as a candidate in a later moderator election on the site?

Comment: Additionally: If a moderator simply stepped down, can they still enter an election again? (Not that it'd make sense, but is it possible?)

Comment: @Cerbrus - I can think of a few scenarios where that might make sense – most notably when the moderator steps down for personal reasons (entering medical school, birth of quintuplets, trip aboard the Greenpeace _Rainbow Warrior_, etc.), but then decides to rejoin the Exchange when life circumstances permit.

Comment: @J.R. In that case, the moderator can simply request their privileges back; they don't have to be elected again. It's always been the case that if a moderator resigns under good terms and remains under good standing, their privileges will be restored upon request; the new reinstatement procedure doesn't change that.

Comment: @Cerbrus If they don't need to. If a moderator steps down in good standing, they can ask for their diamond back and they will generally be reinstated.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog As written, this reinstatement process does change that. As written, a moderator who has resigned and asks for reinstatement must go through the entire reinstatement process, including review by CMs and the rest of the site moderators. It's quite possible for the PM to be denied reinstatement, as the process is currently written (e.g. CM1 and CM2 agree to deny, or if there's >=1 current moderator who "strongly objects to reinstatement"). Thus, asking if a moderator can step around the reinstatement process and be re-elected is something that should be clarified.

Comment: @Makyen We could always refuse if there were extenuating circumstances. Much of the reinstatement process is a formalization of the standard actions a CM would take before giving someone a mod position back... say to the rest of the CMs "oh, hey, X on Z.SE wants their diamond back, any concerns?"... check their recent history for annotations/suspensions... make sure they haven't been causing problems in their recent actions... ping the mods on the team to say "X is asking for their slot back, any concerns?" (assuming they weren't the ones telling us that X wanted it back)...

Comment: @Catija Can't they bypass all those processes by simply getting re-elected again?

Comment: @Catija I'm glad to hear, and not surprised, that there was in the past at least an informal review among the CMs of returning resigned moderators. Frankly, that seems prudent. I probably should have more accurately said that there's a change in the perception of what the process entails. OTOH, one thing I hadn't seen mentioned as being previously being done was that a currently active site moderator could, effectively, veto the reinstatement of a PM.

Comment: Sonic... maybe? But it’d require an election, which aren’t super predictable. I’m not sure it’s ever happened outside of pro-tems running after taking time off. @Makyen it’s not super common that a mod will return after time off so I’m not sure if we had such a thing or not. If someone on the mod team expressed concern for their safety, we’d certainly take that into account, though.

Comment: @Catija Say they actually end up winning the election. Will they get to become a moderator again as a result?

Answer (score 30):

## The intent is wrong.

You're basically trying to say you correctly followed a process which hadn't been published yet to remove a moderator for violating a code of conduct which hadn't been published yet either.

And I haven't even started talking about how it's debatable whether or not the code was actually violated, and how the code itself has received much criticism.

This policy is clearly just a formally written up way to defend SE's past actions, and the entire intent is just to try to convince people that SE didn't mess up in the first place.

There's only one way to fix up the whole scenario: reinstate the removed moderator, then write up a policy on removal of moderators, when you're in a position to be impartial and reasonable. After that, in all fairness, you can and should send this particular moderator's case through the scanner to see if there're appropriate grounds for removal, and take actions accordingly.

But when you're this invested in the policy looking a certain way, you can't hope for it to be appropriate.

Comment: Where did they say they followed this process?  This process didn't *exist* or was not publicly shared until a few days ago.

Comment: @Makoto https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/336193/636149 What SE did was similar enough to one of the clauses, though they didn't explicitly say it.

Comment: "SE did something similar enough" is not the same as "SE followed".  There are signs of what happened being similar - notably the whole "emergency removal" piece - but the *same* process was not followed, likely because **it didn't exist**.

Comment: "But when you're this invested in the policy looking a certain way, you can't hope for it to be appropriate".  This is on the nose.

Answer (score 26):

Execution.1 on removal:

> If an Emergency Removal took place, moderator access can't be restored.

Is this *permanent* (this user will never be a moderator again), or is it temporary (moderator access can't be restored at this stage)?

Comment: I guess it depends. If we see a mod selling user PII, for instance, it _probably_ will be permanent. If, on another example, we find ourselves that far down the process without being able to dismiss some other _less serious_ issues (say, going on an uncharacteristic post deleting spree), it could've been simply because the mod's account was hacked while they were on vacation, and they took 2 weeks to even notice it and our emails requesting clarity on the matter... at which point they'd prolly use the reinstatement process to get reinstated — and possibly get reinstated.

Answer (score 24):

So it used to be that diamond mods who decided to step down due to time reasons or whatnot could be reinstated just by asking.  (That's what I was told when I stepped down on RPG.SE.)  So that's no longer the case?  Why is there all this review stuff for cases other than "they were forcibly removed via one of these removal processes?"  So now if a diamond mod steps down for time reasons, the other mods vote whether they come back or not?  What problem is that solving?

I suggest the reinstatement process be automatic for elected moderators NOT removed forcibly, and you just go through all the shenanigans when there was an actual problem. (Obviously included "resigned while in the removal process" - just when they leave say "you're good to return automatically" or "see this process if you want to return".)

Comment: Based on @Catija's comments, this is sort of compatible with the existing flow: apparently it's been CM process to check in with the current mods even for fast-track reinstatement, but with active mod teams it's largely seamless. It does appear that the current flow would require a second CM, and the blackball voting process could inflict a 7 day delay even if one mod is out of contact and the others all approve. In practice, I imagine "they left on good terms and all reachable mods are 100% content" would suffice, but the doc could certainly support that better.

Answer (score 23):

> Community Managers (CMs) can recuse themselves if they feel they can't be impartial. CM1, CM2, and CM3 will be picked at random from remaining CM pool.

There aren't a lot of Community Managers. What if there are not three CM's remaining after some have recused themselves?

Comment: Waiting for the new one...

Comment: You get a segmentation fault.

Comment: Does CM mean the SE staff moderators, rather than the elected moderators?

Comment: @Raedwald Yes, Community Managers are SE employees, not volunteer moderators.

Answer (score 23):

### On: [What processes exist to issue formal warnings or remove moderators](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336173/what-processes-exist-to-issue-formal-warnings-or-remove-moderators)?

The process as written is protecting SE, and not the volunteers.

So, how can it be made better? This process needs to be public, transparent and **MUST** have [Audi alteram partem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audi_alteram_partem). Why?

### Public

SE Moderators are voted into office. They are leaders within their site. They are publicly visible as being one. Do not just jank then out of office without proof. Now, this does not mean that during the process all is laid bare, but you **must** afterwards! If the case is so clear and overwhelming, SE must be public on why they fired a moderator.

### Transparent

The dynamic between SE, moderator and users is such that SE holds all the power, but they cannot do without the latter. To maintain trust the party with the power **must** be transparent about the process of firing a moderator. Abuse of power (too) is easily done in the shadows.

### [Audi alteram partem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audi_alteram_partem)

You have created a process of removing (firing) a volunteer who has put in countless hours, without possibility to speak for themself? ARE YOU COMPLETELY GONE OF YOUR ROCKER!!! That way lies the realm of tyrants.

Comment: "The process as written is protecting SE, and not the volunteers." <-- this.  The entire set of processes are written without the accused having any formalized inputs / ability to defend themselves.  At no point in the discovery phase is there a place for the accused (or an advocate) given a formal place to make exculpatory or mitigating statements.  In Monica's case, she has stated from the get-go that this has been a case of misunderstanding / miscommunication.  Had she been able to talk to her accusers directly about the issue, perhaps this brouhaha would never have happened.

Comment: "SE must be public on why they fired a mod." isn't this one of the reasons everyone's up in arms right now, because SE made a very public statement about firing Monica?? I *strongly* disagree with this part; let mods leave with dignity. Giving "proof" - if they can even publicly share it - will only smear their name if you agree and create *(gestures at meta)* another one of these messes if you don't.

Comment: @EmC the problem that SE made with firing Monica is that they never told exactly why they did so. Being a mod is a public office, almost, so being fired from that should also be public. Now, stepping down is a different matter, but firing should be just as public a getting voted into that position!

Comment: If SE releases all "proof" they have against a mod, then the mod's reputation will be severely damaged in a very public way - even if the offenses happened in private, and even if people who reported offenses wanted that to be private. And then everyone on meta will proceed to bikeshed whether or not it was "bad enough" for SE to take action, whether that means raking the mod's name through the mud even more, or making a martyr out of them and vilifying anyone who spoke up about the mod or was hurt by the issue at hand. There is a reason companies don't publicly discuss employee firings.

Comment: And that's not to mention potential legal issues (like, what if they fire a mod because the mod was using PII to stalk people, and someone sued, and the lawyers require them to not comment on the case (this is a completely made up scenario, just to be very clear)). If SE doesn't say anything for only *some* cases, there's going to be even more rampant speculation than if it's a blanket "no comment" policy.

Comment: @EmC, those are valid points I did not think about. But doing the proceedings and keeping the results in private is asking for a whole lot of trust. And the change for abuse is just too high. Now, mod are also not employees, they are volunteers, so I do not know the legal (US) stuff for that. As for dragging peoples names through the mud, firing a mod, especially on SE, is a big deal. More so because they are voted into mod-hood. If they have done something wrong and it is a fire-able offence, I would like to know what. If they were employees, I'd think you'd not be wrong. But mods are not.

Comment: Everything is easier when the "bad apple" is clear for anyone paying attention. When you pick the best and wholesome apple of the stack and tell us "This is a Bad Apple", well, no, sorry, we don't trust you.

Answer (score 22):

Execution.1 on removal:

> the network account may be suspended for 30 days to prevent further harm while issue is being handled

Won't this disallow reinstatement and/or reelection for a year after the moderator has been removed in an "emergency"?

That seems unprecedented, especially considering the case of a compromised account that may be fixed easily by changing a password or an email.

Comment: IIRC that election restriction for recently suspended users can be circumvented with a message sent via /contact

Comment: There are special circumstances where a suspension may not be considered when running in elections. If the mod was determined to not be at fault, then this would fall into that circumstance.

Comment: Also this rule might be open to abuse/considered abuse ("silencing the mod").

Answer (score 20):

Moderator Conduct Review Process, Discovery Phase, 4.2:

> If CM1 determines a CoC or mod agreement violation occurred, they will contact the moderator about whom the complaint was raised and inform them of the ongoing process, prompting them for their perspective/context/reasoning, and add this to the documentation to be reviewed in the Confirmation Phase.

On first reading, this sounds like by the time CM1 contacts the accused mod, the CM would already have decided an infraction occurred. It suggests the idea of guilty until proven innocent. I don't think this is actually what is meant, so could you change the wording to something like:

> If CM1 suspects a CoC or mod agreement violation may have occurred, they will contact the moderator about whom the complaint was raised and inform them of the ongoing process, prompting them for their perspective/context/reasoning, and add this to the documentation to be reviewed in the Confirmation Phase.

The wording doesn't need to be like that, I'm sure it can be improved. It just should emphasize that no conclusions will be reached before hearing both sides of the story.

Comment: Hmmm kind of convoluted, isn't it? Like Pinocchio trying not to be caught in a lie... How about _"If CM1 determines a CoC or mod agreement violation **might have** occurred"_? Looks less confusing to me.

Comment: @walen yes, good point. Better now?

Comment: In Discovery#3 there's a bit about "query[ing] the involved parties," which means dialogue with the moderator _may_ have already occurred, which would have informed the CM's decision. The _intention_ of the step you highlight is to _assure_ that at that point the moderator will be contacted, _not as an option, but as a required step to proceed in the process_ (regardless of whether or not there were any previous contacts).

Comment: @terdon Yes, better. OT: isn't "might" always used for past events instead of "may"?

Comment: @JNat OK. But then it would be helpful to make that very clear. The main problem with this entire process is that it seems to require blind trust in the CM team handling it. Anything to suggest that other people will be involved needs to be very clear. You already have set up a frustratingly opaque process, so those few bits of it that might be less opaque deserve to be highlighted.

Comment: @walen no, you can use _may_ for past events when you're not sure whether or not something happened as you think. For example "*this may have been the case in the past*". Here, the _may_ is used to indicate possibility. It makes it even more hypothetical than _might_. At least that's the way I read it, anyway.

Comment: When we posted our original drafts in the mod Team, @terdon, y'all asked for many things we'd accounted for to be clarified, and they were — there are still many that need to be made explicit, clearly. We have a way more wordy document for ourselves, but in shortening it for sharing with mods and the community there are clearly bits in _intention_ that are missed :\

Comment: @JNat I get that, of course. It's just that few people will be reading this assuming _good_ intentions from the company and most will be reading it assuming bad ones, given the recent history. So clarifying the good seems really important. You don't want to give the impression that ya'll will be working under the assumption of guilty until proven innocent. I don't believe you will (at least, not the current batch of CMs, who knows about the future), but that's what it reads like.

Comment: The input is appreciated, @terdon: I'll try to get some bits clarified before the end of the day :)

Answer (score 19):

Is there a plan to communicate this out to all the existing previous moderators? I literally asked about this after being mostly away for months and happened to pick about the [best time ever](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/52226038#52226038) to ask about this in chat, that being *five minutes* before the policy was posted (go me, I guess). But had this happened any time in the last year/likely next months I would have missed it.

It also is a change from what I understood the process would be when I stepped back from being a moderator (the "process" then was "let us know if you want to come back!" or some equally vague variant :-).

Answer (score 18):

> **Moderator Conduct Review Process:**
>
> From time to time, a moderator on one of our sites **may violate their moderator agreement, or the company standards for behavior as documented in our Code of Conduct**. Such behavior may eventually necessitate their removal from office, however both community expectations and our Code prescribe that, in general and whenever possible, they first be warned and given an opportunity to correct their behavior.

1. When a moderator violates “their moderator agreement, or the company standards for behavior as documented in our Code of Conduct” does this mean the moderator is removed from all the sites they moderate? For example, if they violate the code on one site but also act as a moderator on five different sites, will that person lose moderator privileges on all six sites?

Comment: Aren't the moderator agreement and the CoC the same for all network sites? Honest question.

Comment: @walen To the best of my knowledge, they are the same across the network. Credentials: I was a mod on two sites in the network until a few weeks ago, and used to be a mod on a third site where I left voluntarily.

Answer (score 18):

What is the process for removing moderators prior to this process? Monica [says](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336526/stack-overflow-is-doing-me-ongoing-harm-its-time-to-fix-it?noredirect=1&lq=1) you didn't follow any of the processes in place at the time, so this new process seems like it's just a knee-jerk reaction to the fallout that's occurred from removing her. How do we know that this new process will be followed? In short, when someone at SO makes a mistake, it seems like it's swept under the rug without admission of any wrongdoing, in spite of the paper trail, and the 'processes' seem to be really more of what you'd call 'guidelines' than actual rules?

Trust needs to be established first before creating a new process. In the current environment, without closure of an ongoing issue where trust was violated, how can you expect the community to trust you with a new process?

Answer (score 18):

In the [process for reinstating a moderator](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/336175/232449), there is really no interaction/responsibility for the previous moderator.  The CMs simply review the case and decide up or down.

In [a comment on Monica's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336177/feedback-post-moderator-review-and-reinstatement-processes?page=1&tab=votes#comment1112083_336236), @Catija♦ stated that

> We would not have made this available to you [Monica] if you would be immediately vetoed. I know that's difficult to believe but I repeatedly confirmed that was the case last week because doing otherwise would have been cruel. The deck isn't stacked against you here. – Catija♦ Oct 22 at 13:00

This implies that if Monica went through the process, she would be reinstated.  My question is this: Monica has made it clear that she wants to be reinstated.  What is preventing you from internally going through the process (which does not require anything from Monica) and deciding to reinstate her?  If this has been already done and the decision was to turn her down, then your statement is incorrect and the deck is indeed stacked against her.

Comment: If they are (now, despite how they got here) going to be sticklers for process and say I didn't initiate it, they could instead say "here is the pre-approved outcome should you choose to initiate".  That's the only way to get transparency; there's none in the process itself.

Comment: The previous moderator must formally initiate the process, not just mention that they would like to be reinstated. When you have wronged someone, you don’t make it right by making them the guinea pig for a brand new process that would give other moderators a chance to deny them reinstatement or possibly require them to agree to certain conditions to get reinstated. Monica should be reinstated using the same process used to fire her. That is the only ethical path forward here. A real apology would be nice, but that is probably too much to ask at this point.

Answer (score 18):

What about cases where the moderator was removed for a reason that was obsoleted by a rule change? I'm thinking in particular of Monica's situation. I ask this [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/337626/343810) as well, but the new Code of Conduct appears to *explicitly* permit what she was asking to be allowed to do, so she's evidently not in violation of the new version of the policy. That being said, shouldn't she just be reinstated?

Comment: I don't understand why she'd need to go through a reinstatement process when the rule she was apparently fired over doesn't even apply anymore.

Answer (score 17):

Why was the number 30 days? Was this an arbitrary number? If you're considering bringing a moderator back why such a small snapshot?

Also on this, why is it that the community isn't involved if that's who elected the individuals in the first place. This sounds more like at that point that SE Inc is devaluing the voices that originally signed off on that moderator. Perhaps it's not the moderation team that has grievances, but the general community.

Comment: *(Duplicated from [the other question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/336175/164403)):* ***3. CM1 will pull community interactions involving PM for the past 30 days.*** This is far too short. I would suggest 90 days (last three months) or greater.

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't going to throw a specific date out there myself. However my thought is that if someone's looking to become a moderator again after being removed or stepping down, their *entire* time should be considered while not having the diamond.

Comment: You should split this into two answers ... As to the second point, I would hope that the remaining moderators would be aware that there may be a grievance between the previous moderator and the general community and ask for additional time to make outreaches to the community.

Comment: So... 30 days is already an almost crippling amount of data to sift through for, say, a SO mod, @FrédéricHamidi

Comment: @Shog9 I'm not arguing that it isn't likely a huge amount of data to go through. Especially if they're active in multiple exchanges. My only concern is 30 days is just a *small* snapshot of an individual.

Comment: Ok, so, we're not limiting ourselves to 30 days of history, @FrédéricHamidi. The 30-day check is intended to tell us what the mod has been up to *recently*, in case we haven't been paying attention.

Comment: @Shog9 I guess despite your checkup, why would you guys remove the community from the process? You certainly don't have to ask for yay/nays, but the community has no idea when this process is being done. I'd suggest at the very least give a discovery window where the community can voice their concerns about the person who's supposed to have their trust.

Answer (score 17):

What is the intent behind the reinstatement process?

If it is to catch a failure of the previous process (biased CM that refuses to recuse, wrong annotation...) why isn't there any way to address those failures in the reinstatement?

If it is for a previous moderator to argue that they have changed their behavior, why doesn't the discovery include finding evidence of a changing behavior?

Basically, in what case would a moderator be removed and then reinstated? I think it is not very clear what the purpose of that process exactly is.

Assuming the removal and reinstating procedure where crafted together, I think it's safe to assume the reinstatement process must follow a removal process. If so, should moderators removed before those processes where in place apply for *removal* before going through reinstatement?

Comment: It’s a general reinstatement process. Mods leave for a variety of reasons. Most step down or are removed for inactivity - neither of these groups are represented in the removal process, which is only relevant extremely infrequently. All three groups are eligible to be reinstated. Most requests for reinstatement will be from the first two groups, not from people removed with the removal process. For scale, I’d estimate that, annually, 50-100 mods will be in the first two groups and 0-2 will have been removed through one of the two removal processes.

Comment: @Catija Thanks! Given the current ambiance, I thought the reinstatement was designed as a way for mods to address what they think is an unfair removal. Is there any plan for that?

Comment: The same process is used for both. The outline of the process is general. There's definitely a place in the information gathering phase where talking with the moderator can happen to discuss their concerns. Some of the things you mention, like a biased CM who won't recuse, are addressed by requiring a two-step removal process - a warning followed by removal if the behavior continues - and having two CMs that must agree before any of the processes are carried out. A mod feels they were removed wrongfully particularly prior to these processes, they can apply for reinstatement and we will talk.

Answer (score 16):

Why do these processes minimize involvement of the rest of the mod team and of the communit(ies) they serve?

Mods are elected by their community and then serve as part of a mod team.

### Removal Process Issues

What's the difference between the two removal policies? It seems like they are 
a) emergency or other removal (mod team not involved)
b) other removal (mod team involved)

Suspension is possible, I don't see how "emergency removal" needs to be a thing at all.  How about "emergency suspension," and then the removal discussion can happen at a calmer pace and involve the rest of their diamond mod team.

It's also unclear the scope of the removal - one or all sites - we don't even suspend users on other sites for things they do on one site, why would a mod be removed from all sites for some beef with a given site?   I guess maybe removal process a) is for all sites and b) is just for that site?  (It should probably say that...) Or is a) "for cause" and b) "just because?"  It's not clear.

In general the removal process a is a giant mess, it's really just saying "CMs can bounce anyone they want" in a lot more words.  It says "well people should be given a chance" in the preamble but it's not part of the process.  Their fellow mods and communities are not consulted in any way. Seems like they could provide valuable context ("You're right, he has been pushing that line a lot"... "He's never done anything like that and maybe you are reading that a different way from how I'm reading it?"

In the end, we don't trust Sara for sure and the other CMs to some degree so this is just a fancy way of saying "we do what we want" currently.

Similarly, process b) doesn't seem to have any safeguards to verify there are substantive issues - just "2/3 of the mods don't want them there." Seems like it takes the place of our mod elections - what if the community wants a new direction, elects a new person, and the existing mods "just don't like that?"  I would think a CM should agree that there is a significant issue meriting possible removal to move forward with the 'tribunal' part of this process. I know we had (non-mod, but high rep user) disagreements on RPG.SE that generated complaints that when Shog9 looked into it he just told us "these are like old married couple disagreements, calm down" - and that was the right call.

### Reinstatement Process Issues

I raised separately the issue of mods who left not for cause.  But even for general reinstatement, why might the community not have a say (basically, re-elect them?)  What if they run for re-election anyway, if they feel like they got reinstatement rejected just because the other mods don't like them, not for any particularly good reason?  Communities often vote in people with different approaches to modding to try to make changes over time and such...  Current mods don't get a choice in that, the new person is elected whether they like them or not. Seems like maybe mod vote or popular vote might both be valid reinstatement options here.

Comment: `why would a mod be removed from all sites for some beef with a given site?` because Monica was demodded simultaneously from SIX sites, they had to find a way to shoehorn that in.

Comment: Which means, in theory, if a mod broke the CoC on one site, they should lose their privileges in all the sites they moderate on!

Comment: "Suspension is possible" - as I understand it, not really.. if they still have the diamond they can just un-suspend themselves, so you do need to remove it. "why would a mod be removed from all sites for some beef with a given site" - I think this does make sense though, we don't let users run in mod elections if they've been suspended anywhere on the network in the past year, so it'd be rather inconsistent to allow a user to be suspended on one site for violating CoC and yet keep mod powers (with access to PII!) on another.

Comment: That's not really a problem, it can be a "virtual suspension" (remove with the understanding it's for the time being) or, God forbid, they can write a couple lines of code making mods' suspension not self-removable.

Comment: .. Isn't that exactly what the emergency removal is doing? Removing mod status while the CMs figure out what's going on, and if it's not the mod's fault (e.g. they were hacked), they'll get access back.

Comment: The point of the emergency removal is that the mod’s account may be somehow compromised or they’re abusing access to PII or something else in that vein. Suspending them doesn’t prevent the damage that could be done in those situations. Only removal of the diamond removes the access.

Answer (score 16):

### The big problem is what happens when SE doesn't properly follow their own process.

The proposed processes are mostly fine.  I have one quibble (mentioned in a comment elsewhere): there should be more formalization of the accused being able to defend themselves / provide context, etc.  (This might be the intent of the Discovery, but it could stand to be more formalized and explicitly stated.)  Otherwise, I appreciate the work that has gone into creation and the opportunity to debate them here.

But the moderator reinstatement process assumes an amount of good faith coming from the Community Managers.  If the previous moderator has been removed by a failure to follow the appropriate processes, it is very understandable for them to feel that there is no way for them to get a fair shake.

I think that the big problem is what happens when the processes aren't followed.  [David Fullerton even admits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334551/an-apology-to-our-community-and-next-steps) that

```
We made a decision to act quickly... but in doing so skipped several critical parts of the process.
```

IANAL, but the quoted actions are not unlike a case of prosecutorial misconduct.  In such a case (in the US legal system), a higher authority might overturn the initial decision, possibly allowing a retrial, possibly not.  In any event the problem is simply that there is no higher authority within SE.  There has been a proposal for some sort of Community Ombudsman; this may have some technical challenges that make this proposal untenable.

My proposal:

> **Allow the moderators** (or some portion thereof) **to act as a court of higher appeal** - not to be able to relitigate, but simply **to
>   give an up-down vote on whether the process was completed
>   appropriately**.  To keep numbers down (and to prevent too much information
>   dissemination), whenever a moderator's privileges are removed, a call
>   could go out to other mods requesting volunteers for this task.  After
>   some number of mods have replied (or some amount of time has elapsed),
>   a small number (perhaps 5) are selected at random from the pool; these
>   mods then have a short amount of time (perhaps a day) to up or down vote the
>   process.  If the majority of this committee votes that *the process
>   was not followed* (not whether the finding was accurate), the decision
>   to remove the PM's privileges would be overturned.

Quis custodiet ipsos custodes?  The moderator reinstatement process as proposed is better than no process, but it still does not take into account whether the processes are being followed - which is frankly the heart of this whole mess.

I think that SE giving some amount of oversight of their decisions to the moderators will go a long way towards regaining the trust of that community.

Comment: Moderators on the accused's site(s), or moderators from anywhere on the network?  The former would afford more privacy if the issues involve moderator actions (as opposed to general conduct).

Comment: @MonicaCellio Since I am not a mod anywhere, so I don't really know the workings of the sites.  Any and all of the details of my proposal are fair game for further discussion.  It may be that the mods closest to the PM are too close (as in they're part of the complaints, or thought to be predjudiced for/against the PM).  Perhaps the mods on this council can be given a redacted version of events.  (E.g. replace all instances of the PM's name / username, etc with '[PM]'.)  It might even be best to redact all parties' ID's with code: [CM1]. [CM2], [aggrieved user 1]...

Answer (score 16):

From my very lowly position as a reviewer on 3 communities and virtually no rep here I see that SE management have apparently shot themselves in both feet.

Firstly they seem to have dismissed Monica without going through any recognisable fair process and then failed to provide any evidence to 
Monica or the community to justify their actions. If they had published evidence, a series of emails where they issued warnings and Monica unreasonably refused to obey,
then it would have shut this whole sad episode down almost immediately, but they have refused to do so on some sort of confidentiality grounds (which Monica
is prepared to waive). So the suspicion is that there is no such evidence exists and the dismissal was unjustified. Consequently many of the dezines of 
Moderator Mount Olympus have quit or gone on strike. My understanding is that the management are currently looking for further finance or investment in SE,
so the last thing they want is any controversy. 
Their subsequent apologies and post facto creating procedures have been met with almost universal condemnation as inadequate, thereby fuelling the fire.

Secondly, as far as I know, all the moderators, reviewers and contributors a purely volunteers. 
The entire existence of SE relies on our contributions and good will. If the management antagonise too many of us they won't have a viable SE to offer investors.

Comment: They now claim I actually violated the CoC.  (The "reason" mutated along the way.)  Actual CoC violations take place on-site and the only email was several days after I left TL, so the email isn't relevant to their claim.  There is very personal stuff in the email so I don't want to release that; if it were actually relevant I would take a closer look to see if it could be redacted.  I also still expect them to tell *me* what they think I did wrong before they publish it to the world.  This has not happened.

Comment: @MonicaCellio - Even if it's not relevant -- possibly it would be constructive to share it with redactions.  I don't know, of course.  In my special education advocacy experience, I've seen parents be given redacted copies of emails that had all but one fragment redacted, and the unredacted portion of the document ended up being a meaningless, completely useless piece of paper (sometimes multiple pieces of paper).

Comment: [They are going for an IPO](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zMfxd9y0cMY&t=15m57s).

Answer (score 12):

In the Moderator Action Review Process, it is stated:

> Once begun, the following steps must be followed, in order, to completion within a reasonable time frame. If this is not possible, all participants will be notified by us that the process has been discontinued and informed of the resolution (if any).

What resolutions are possible if the process cannot be completed in a "reasonable time frame"? That is, is this intended to establish a Statute of Limitations and/or a "Right to a speedy trial" principle (that is, the moderator automatically keeps their diamond if the company is unable to fully execute the process in a rapid and fair manner), or does it allow the company to decide to immediately suspend a moderator upon concluding that the steps cannot be reasonably followed? This could happen if important witnesses are away, if documents have been lost, or even if the moderator has fled and is making themselves unavailable in an attempt to stall the process.

Comment: Another case where this might happen: if the moderator resigns in the middle of the removal process.

Answer (score 12):

**What does an initiation request look like, and how does that change in the absence of a removal process?**

The current process has no detail on Initiation beyond "Previous moderators (PM) may request reinstatement through the /contact form on the site that they wish to be reinstated". In addition to grammatical cleanup (I suggest "...on the site for which they wish to be reinstated"), this provides no detail about the nature of the request. And yet the PM has no further role to play until being denied, reinstated, or sent to Execution #2.2.

But the PM's views are clearly relevant prior to that, since Execution #1 includes "Preconditions are to be communicated, along with any show of willingness to correct possibly problematic past behaviors from PM in their initial contact."

This raises several difficulties.

Assuming the PM was removed under the new removal process:

- The moderator team receives only one-way communication from the Initiation, which has no guidelines at all. If their decision hinges on specific questions for the PM, can that be communicated? (A simple example: if a PM made commitments and then vanished, the team might request reassurance that it was a one-off matter.)
- The mod team (or teams) receive only one-way, *unconfirmed* information about preconditions. If they would require some altered precondition to accept reinstatement, can that be passed back to the CMs? If the PM won't accept the CM conditions, why add a week of delay and involve an entire mod team? E#2.2 can happen before E#1, especially if the mod team has no input on preconditions.
- The PM seemingly has no input at all on preconditions except refusal of the entire process. ("A reply", "acknowledges and agrees" vs "responds negatively".) If the PM seeks even clarification of the conditions, much less change, does the process restart from Initiation and Discovery? If not, what happens if a mod team member objects to the clarified/altered condition? Is the PM even allowed to reapply on this basis - does "I don't understand phrase X" count as "relevant circumstances... that weren't considered"?

In particular, I suggest that E#2.2 happen before E#1, possibly with a loop back after mod team input, and explicitly allow two-way communication between CM and PM. This seems like common sense, but as @Shog9 artfully said recently, that's "a term we use for things that are obvious to us but not others". If this is a process meant for use when informal communication breaks down, it should be clear about formal communication channels.

If the PM was *not* removed under the new removal process, how does this work at all?

- Discovery #2 acknowledges that their file won't be annotated, but no other allowances are made. The PM's only input is at Initiation, before they receive *any* communication from CMs or mods, but per E#1 that request is expected to address the removal.
- As above, CMs are setting conditions and then involving one (or many?) mod teams before talking to the PM - but now the PM may not even have the same inciting incident in mind as the CMs and mods.
- The PM only receives information if the reinstatement is denied. If it's accepted, even with conditions, there's apparently no way to discover why the account was removed, whether it's annotated with other "strikes", or whether the initial removal is still considered a sound decision.

At risk of beating a dead horse, all of this started because a moderator was removed without any process. She's been publicly accused of violating the CoC, but has repeatedly asked what terms she violated and apparently received no answer, even privately.

I'm genuinely pleased that this process allows moderators to apply and be reinstated without admitting past fault (potentially even if there are preconditions). But it still requires those PMs to submit a single comment without knowing *why* the removal happened, and only offers information if the request is denied.

I would feel far better if "...and the reasons for it will be stated back to PM" applied even to successful reinstatements.

Comment: Most of the time, they literally just have to email us and say "Hi, I'd like to begin the reinstatement process. I was inactive two years ago and was removed. I was so busy with work I didn't even respond to the emails about being removed. Work's much more calm now and I'd like to have my position back." In cases like these, requiring communication can slow the process. These are the vast majority of reinstatement requests we get. Very little time is needed on active work and, with a responsive current mod team, can happen in a couple of hours.

Comment: For complicated cases, while it's not explicitly in the design, there are various opportunities for communication to get additional information, ask questions, communicate. We can look at adding these as optional points, I think At the bare minimum we should  probably respond to the ticket and indicate that we're starting work on the request. And, yes. I know we seem like the strong, silent types... at least right now. We've been struggling a bit with using our words.

Comment: Thanks very much, this is reassuring. While I hope to see communication explicitly mentioned as an option, it makes total sense not to require it, especially for simple approvals like you describe; even a general mention that it's encouraged as needed might suffice and avoid elaborate process. My thought was mostly to ensure that certain cases like "I veto unless..." be free of miscommunication, and to make the process more viable for mods who didn't go through the removal process.

Comment: And yes - I can certainly imagine why staff are being particularly deliberate with their words at the moment. From the user side, I'll just say that "we've heard this and we're doing concrete work on it" or "this took longer than planned, here's why and what's up" count for a lot. That goes for the recent CMT status update, a ticket response, or even your comments right here. Thanks for being aware of it.

Comment: @Catija a process needs to consider the complicated cases too, though, especially when a profound failure of process and fairness is what got us here in the first place.

Comment: @Catija Reinstatement in a few hours? Remember that every single CM has to be given a chance to recuse themselves. And what happens if CM1, picked randomly, is not reachable (say, on vacation)?

Answer (score 12):

## Replace the emergency action caveats with an explicit disclaimer that SE can at any time, for any reason remove a moderator without notice

We all know that SE is a private company and can do almost anything it wants within its realm. No one doubts this, and frankly I don't think it's a very interesting discussion point. You should include this disclaimer to quickly get this out of the way so that we don't get hung up on it as a talking point.

Value comes from the fact that SE does *not* want to exercise this power. SE wants to engage with the community in almost all circumstances (exceptions being account compromise, PII leaks, etc). By making this clear in a disclosure we can avoid a large chunk of fairly useless conversation. Instead we move straight into a discussion of how to value add to the community.

Comment: “SE is a private company and can do almost anything it wants” — This is true in the legal sense, but not in the moral sense. There is a social contract between the company and the community. In a nutshell, they build the technical aspects of the site and reap any profits, we provide the content and curation. This social contract is implicit and many people would fill in different details, but it exists nonetheless. One of the ambiguities is who provides the oversight. It was the company initially and that was fine because we trusted Jeff. It's no longer fine because we don't trust Sara.

Comment: @Gilles I totally agree, this is exactly what I'm saying. Let's move past the moral vs legal contracts and responsibilities. The legal side is just not interesting. Only the moral side is interesting. Any policies, procedures, discussions, or anything else should focus just on that moral side. Thats why I want to make sure the legal side is explicitly taken out of the picture asap.

Comment: Oh. This is not at all what I understand from your answer. You state “no one doubts this” and “this is [not] a very interesting discussion point”! I not only doubt this but disagree with it and I think it's an important and relevant discussion point.

Comment: @Gilles Perhaps I don't understand you then. I'm saying SE is a private company and can physically do almost anything (like ban a mod outright) irrespective of morals, community, or anything else. This makes no statement of right or wrong, just of physical and legal ability. Do you doubt that?

Comment: This would be an ugly disclaimer, but at least it would be telling the truth. (I'd rather have the ugly truth than a pretty pretense, so, as much as it pains me to admit it, I think this is a sensible idea. +1.)

Comment: @J.R. Yep. Thats exactly what I'm trying to do. Get the ugly out of the way fast so we can focus on the good.

Comment: @DavidGrinberg I'm reasonably confident about my physical ability to kill my neighbor if I so chose, but I wouldn't phrase this as “Gilles can kill hir neighbor if ze wants”.

Comment: @Gilles I said physically _and_ legally. Lets not sidetrack the discussion please.

Comment: Please check out the (pseudo-) answer by George Stocker about how this process stuff doesn't matter when you don't trust the owner of the process to stick to their word. I *guess* what David is saying is (of course) they don't have to; but I'm with Gilles -- if they want me here, I should be able to trust them. Call it a "social contract" if you like. Whether or not what they are doing is not illegal is completely beside the point (though of course they have to obey applicable legislation in the jurisdictions where they have operations. and yes, the bear does poop in the woods).

Answer (score 12):

**SE, stop everything and listen**

I believe this has come to a point where it's obvious that all remedial action taken by SE is not working. The new process feels rushed, it's a badly patched together justification for Monica's termination.

SE, you have a social contract with the community. Director of CMs, you have the responsibility to bridge your employer with us. You were supposed to work towards our growth and wellbeing.

Stack Overflow has become something bigger than what a private company can manage on its own. Your product is so deeply connected with your users, and it's time you stop for a moment and listen to them.

**Give the community an equal voice in the community affairs**

1. Community should have the same amount of veto rights as SE.
2. Moderator termination, not based on any security breach, should go through a vote process with equal amount of SE employees and voted moderators.
3. If veto power was exercised, and if there is opposition from other veto rights holders, the process steps into a "small council" where all veto rights holders must vote.
4. Full transcripts with minimal redaction of executive discussions regarding disciplinary actions must be made available within 24 hours following internal reviews.
5. If sufficient votes from the community, a new review process must take place within 7 working days.

SE, you can still salvage some trust from the community if you take actions now.

I am just going to point out [the case of Jesse Jackson and Ellen Pao](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellen_Pao#Exit_from_Reddit). Remember why the [Reddit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reddit) CEO had to step down? She failed to listen to her community and all subsequent actions taken by her administration led them further away from reason.

Comment: This is in some sense similar to my proposal, but giving "the community" powers is probably not legally tenable. That's why I think a Community Ombudsman with some personal responsibilities, agreements, and obligations would be more feasible.

Comment: Interesting thoughts you have shared, I haven't seen it from an Ombudsman perspective, my thoughts stem from the United Nations veto power but rather than just 5 countries holding veto power, perhaps an equal amount of SE reps and community appointed reps? Can the whole legality perspective go away if SE honour, in good faith, a social contract with the community? It has no legal obligations towards us but as a gesture of good will, SE will enforce this agreement.

Answer (score 11):

Sorry if this duplicates an existing proposal; haven't finished reading through them all (not the process documentation in any detail) ...

### Give the Community a Representative

In more or less direct response to [Monica's answer](/a/336236/169312) and several comments, I would like to propose a new role with **visibility into this process on the behalf of the community** but also a **mandate and role vaguely similar to, but distinct from, the moderator's.** I'd like to call this a **Community Ombudsman.**

Rather than attempt to articulate their mandate in any detail, let me just throw this out as a loose idea. The Ombudsman should

- Participate in reviewing and overseeing the work of the Community Managers -- not sure what sort of division of labor between the employer and the ombudsman is realistic (or legally acceptable!) but think of this vaguely like how unions have representatives in HR committees in many companies (at least here in Northern Europe).
- Be a stakeholder with *full insight* into site moderation across the network, but no access to moderators' enforcement tools.

  - I think it's important that this person is *not* an active moderator, but they need a very good insight into the work, and in particular the agreements and processes governing their activities (i.e. probably a former moderator?)
- Receive a full, detailed, written report of how Community Manager appeals were handled (not just moderator reinstatements -- any situation where there may be a conflict of interest between the community and the company).

(Frankly, this sounds almost like a part-time job, or at the very minimum a serious undertaking which should probably somehow be compensated. If that happens, I guess ideally the money should come from outside of Stack Overflow Inc.'s normal salary system with HR oversight etc. Perhaps there could be a grant from a foundation or some such?)

I can think of some people whom I'd like to see in this position, but probably so can you. In the present situation, we should probably be looking at moderators who stepped down or ceased their activity well before the current crisis erupted (which I guess is not a very large pool of candidates).

Comment: Being unfamiliar with the actual mod tools is a bit of a handicap here. Please feel free to fix any false assumptions or point out oversights or misunderstandings.

Comment: It's an interesting idea but... even if the company agreed, it'd be a difficult position to fill - they'd probably need to sign some sort of legal contract with SE, for one, since the complaints could include sensitive personal information (beyond what mods normally have access to, depending on the issue). And if they're paid, there's still a conflict of interest and you're really just hiring a new boss for the CMs.. A lot of former moderators leave because they can't commit the time/energy, too.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I think a mod who is familiar with similar agreements and constraints would need to fill this role, although I suppose you could take an outsider and train them like we train moderators. A current moderator who agrees to cease moderation and start to oversee the company's processes instead would be a useful arrangement in a different situation, but I don't know if that could fly in the current scenario.

Comment: Why not just onboard one or two mods from other sites at random to give "neutral" eyeballs on the process ?

Comment: @Tensibai I'm not saying we can't do that but I'll try to explain why I didn't propose that. Having a single named person or a very small set of persons limits exposure for possibly sensitive data and minimizes the requirements for additional paperwork related to possible NDAs etc. and of course means you can limit the amount of specialized training. Also, if the company thinks the community, the mods, and the meta crowd are the enemy, they probably want to be very selective about who they accept to even nominate.

Comment: (You could argue that making the process scalable and repeatable would be desirable, and so maybe we *should* make it easy to onboard new people; but that will increase the effort on the company's side significantly for a mechanism which is probably hard to convince them to try in the first place.)

Comment: I did mention mods from other site because they already accepted the moderator agreement and (until recent specific event) the TL rule of "not copy anything out of here", which should not require any more "paperwork". I don't think the company see mods or meta as ennemies, more (wrongly IMHO) as negligible opinion (or more bluntly: background noise)

Comment: @Tensibai So yes, as already discussed above, I think using an existing mod would be fine in normal circumstances; but these circumstances are not normal, and so I'm thinking retired or dormant would be safer (not a stakeholder in the current brouhaha). If this actually happens, hopefully things should return to normal before the *second* Community Ombudsman gets elected, and then the procedure might need a tweak or two; making currently active moderators eligible would then perhaps be feasible. But as of right now, moderators *are* stakeholders and the conflict of interest cannot be ignored.

Comment: Fair point, I disagree a bit that two mods from unrelated site would not recuse themselves if they feel too implied with the mod "judged" but your point stand.

Comment: The newly appointed Moderator Council seems to have a vaguely similar mandate. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/347104/introducing-the-moderator-council-and-its-first-pro-tempore-representatives?cb=1

Answer (score 9):

Thank you for posting these processes. However, in [What is the process for reinstating a moderator?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336175/what-is-the-process-for-reinstating-a-moderator), point #2 of the "Discovery Phase" states:

> 2. CM1 will look through account annotations for reasons for removal. Annotations weren't always a feature, so CM1 will also consult with the rest of the Community Management and Community Strategy (CST) teams for any extra context.
>
>    1. If CM1 finds any annotation that states reinstatement is deemed impossible, the request is denied and the reasons for it will be stated back to PM. **The process is concluded here.**
>    2. If CM1 (and the team) finds reinstatement is possible under the agreement that a reasonable and attainable precondition should and could be met (such as an agreement to discontinue a certain kind of behavior), this reason is documented.
>    3. If CM1 (and the team) finds reinstatement is possible and there isn't a need to establish a precondition, they'll just proceed.

Is there any particular reason why sub-point #1 has only the CM1 involved while sub-points 2 and 3 have "CM1 (and the team)"?  I believe the team should also be involved in sub-point #1 to help ensure not just one person determines a specific annotation is considered to be such that reinstatement is deemed impossible. Also, are there any specific guidelines as to what constitutes an annotation which makes it impossible to be reinstated?

Another issue in sub-point #1 is that it doesn't explicitly state anything about documenting which particular annotation, and why it's deemed important enough, for a PM to not be reinstated.  I believe this should also be documented, such as in cases where a PM asks again later to be reinstated so the previous reason can be reviewed and, for example, considered if it was reasonable and still applicable.

Answer (score 9):

Execution Phase, item 1:

> The team will have 7 days to say their piece.

So essentially anyone on the team can stall the process for 7 days for no reason?

So if a PM was unfairly fired from several sites, and wishes to reinstate PM's mod status, PM would have to go through the trouble of completing multiple contact forms, and would have to wait up to seven days?

Justice delayed is justice denied.

Comment: Also as noted in other answers, there's no guarantee that the CM who handles the reinstate process isn't the same CM who unfairly fired PM in the first place.

Comment: I read that as the PM dragging their heels. But if I'm correct then the wording needs adjusted to clarify that. The CM's shouldn't be dragging out the process just to use that as an excuse to invalidate it.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Is it clear in our wording that the "team" you're referring to there is the _moderator_ team PM is asking to be reinstated _into_? If so, I don't know that there's an easy way for us to shorten that 7 day window — we'd have to be able to coordinate with multiple mods (depending on the size of the team) to hear all their input, and not everyone is available at the same time, etc.

Comment: @JNat I'd say it's not entirely clear whether "current moderation team" includes CMs and other staff with diamonds. I'm also saying that the process should be expedited as much as possible if the firing was obviously unfair in the first place. For example if some day a CM decides to be a jerk and fires a mod for no reason, and the CM that processes the reinstate request finds this to be true. Would the process still be delayed by 7 days because another unrelated mod is on vacation?

Comment: I'll see how to clarify what "team" means in that context, then. As for the second bit of your comment: yes, the process would need to wait for a full 7 days if one mod's response is pending. Also, the Conduct Review Process prevents the "some day a CM decides to be a jerk and fires a mod for no reason" scenario you presented.

Comment: @JNat Just because a "process" prevents it, doesn't mean it won't happen. This is especially important when there's no way to appeal a Conduct Review decision.

Comment: @JNat, what are the technical measures you have implemented to prevent a single SE employee from demodding a random moderator? Without such measures, anyone can circumvent the process. If they are acting maliciously, they can even prevent the moderator from being reinstated according to the reinstatement process.

Comment: @JNat What will prevent the Conduct Review Process from being ignored like the previous [Moderator Action Review Process](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/157258/188225)?

Comment: I'm not sure I can predict what conditions would lead to this process being ignored, @AndrewPiliser, so I can't speak to what we could do to prevent _that_ :\ That being said, the process was designed with a lot of use-cases in mind, so that hopefully sends a strong signal of when it _should_ be used.

Comment: @JNat Thanks for the update!

Answer (score 9):

In the section **Proceedings**, of [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/336174/282094), it says:

> 2. At the designated time, a quorum must be present — this shall consist of ⅔rds (rounded up) of the moderators on the site (all those listed as active on the /users?tab=moderators page, whether or not currently active), excluding the moderator to be removed (example: for a team with three moderators, both of those not being considered for removal must be present).

Stack Overflow has [21 moderators](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators), so ⅔rds means more than 14.

Observations: It may be difficult to assemble that many people and hold a conversation involving almost 20 people. On some sites (with only a few moderators) one or more of the moderators haven't checked in for weeks. Rarely a site will only have a couple of moderators, maybe only one; whom is excluded from the total deemed necessary for quorum.

Answer/Suggestion: It is necessary to have at least 2 moderators, even if they must be drawn from other sites, and the moderator whose case is being decided shouldn't have to wait 2 weeks.

If the initial email receives insufficient replies after the first week then stand-ins should be contacted so that a minimum quorum of 2 moderators (**or** ⅔rds when there are 4 or more, assuming only one removal) can attempt to represent moderator's concerns (point of view).

That permits moderators to be represented at the hearing while not introducing an unwanted delay into the hearing of the affected moderator's case(s).

Reference: [Number Constituting a Quorum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quorum#Number_constituting_a_quorum):

> "Robert's Rules of Order Newly Revised [no relationship to me] states that the quorum set in an organization's bylaws "should approximate the largest number that can be depended on to attend any meeting except in very bad weather or other extremely unfavorable conditions."
>
> In the absence of such a provision, a quorum is an assembly whose membership can be determined is a majority of the entire membership. In the meetings of a convention, unless provided otherwise, a quorum is a majority of registered delegates, even if some have departed. In a mass meeting or in an organization in which the membership cannot be accurately determined, the quorum consists of those who attend the meeting.".

Answer (score 8):

Is the Moderator Conduct Review Process the only process by which Stack Exchange employees (especially those who are not CMs) may remove a moderator? I assume the answer is yes, and I think it can be made clearer to reassure the community that there will be no de-modding coming out of unexpected places.

The answer that details the process is already in the context of how the Community Management Team will move through the process, and the question didn't seem to be explicit about any involvement by non-CMs:

> This post lists two process by which formal complaints against moderators are handled by the Community Management Team.

This only states how the Community Management Team will handle them.

> The Moderator Conduct Review Process is a process by which complaints against a moderator's conduct can be raised.

The indefinite article suggests there may be other processes.

Comment: No, the agreement says that moderators can be removed at any time at the discretion of Stack Exchange with no warning. Technically, the company isn't obligated to follow any process. It's in the company's interest to have removals be perceived as fair though.

Comment: @ColleenV It looks to me that the best way to be perceived as fair would be starting to act fair instead of publishing non-binding documents stating they want to be fair. We do not need a flowchart to understand that the reasons for a removal should be clearly disclosed to the affected party, we would rather see SE actually doing it.

Comment: @Goyo you won’t get any argument from me on that front.

Answer (score 8):

I have some more questions:

- In the reinstatement process, can CMs 2 and 3 overrule CM1's decision not to continue? (after the first step)
- Is it possible to have a list of questions that guide the CM teams decision? This would be good for transparency and allowing others to somehow audit the decision.

I think these questions might be a good start:

- What harm does the moderator do to (a) the community and (b) the company?
- Can we assume bad intent? Why?
- Is the mean effective to solve the problems? Is it neccessary? (or is there a "nicer" one?)
- Is the decision going to harm the moderator team's ability to mod the site?

One more last idea, why don't you create a "Court of Appeal"/Community Court where these decisions can be made. There could be CMs and various community members in this court that make a majority decision in these cases. Something similiar is working on Wikipedia. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Arbitration_Committee)

Comment: CMs 2 and 3 can override CM1's decision, correct.

Answer (score 8):

Why was "Remove access immediately" chosen as a first resort over a less extreme alternate?
It also seems to me that the current workflow doesn't actually prevent the compromised account from continuing the bad behavior, they can just continue doing it without a diamond next to their name.

A quick brainstorm:

- A solution that should work for all accounts.

  - Disable login.
  - Send an email to allow reactivation.
- If an account has multiple authentication methods.

  - Disable the compromised login.
  - Inform the user.
- A potential solution that only works for SE accounts.

  - Reset the password of the account.
  - Kick all user sessions from the server.

Comment: "they can just continue doing it without a diamond". See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336177/feedback-post-moderator-review-and-reinstatement-processes?page=2&tab=votes#comment1111671_336226

Answer (score 8):

> ## Execution Phase
>
> 1. If an Emergency Removal took place, moderator access can't be restored. At CM2's discretion, the network account may be suspended for 30 days to prevent further harm while issue is being handled. CM2 will communicate their findings to the moderator, and annotate their account. **The process is concluded here.**

Unless I've misread the comments and clarifications on some of the other answers, Emergency Removal could be used for anything from an active security breach to acting out of character.

What happens if CM1 misreads the situation and overreacts when *stumbling* upon the initial problem, and initiates an Emergency Removal on the mod; the process concludes finding a violation did occur, but it wasn't what CM1 initially thought it was was, and in retrospect the Emergency Removal wasn't warranted?

On a first offense, if the Emergency Removal had not occurred, the mod would get a warning, but since the Emergency Removal did take place, now they can't be restored.

If you are looking for a fair process, the punishment should be determined by the mod's actions, not by CM1's reaction.

Answer (score 7):

In **Moderator Conduct Review Process**, in the Discovery phase, section 4.2.1. Current words:

```
moderator access can be restored
```

Please replace "can" with "will".

Answer (score 6):

I have two concerns about the removal and reinstatement policies. The first is that SE maintains complete control over the process and the second is the lack of transparency in the processes.

I think removal should require agreement between a CM (i.e., an SE employee) and a site moderator (i.e., an elected/pro-term appointed moderator from the community that is not an SE employee) that the moderator in question should be removed. For the reinstatement process, I think blocking reinstatement should require agreement between a CM and a site moderator that the moderator in question should not be reinstated. The moderators to be involved in these processes could either be the non-employee moderators at MSE, randomly chosen from moderators across the network with more than N years of moderating experience, solicited from moderators in the TL on a first-come basis or something like that or really anything that gives community members a seat at the table.

In the removal process, this means CM2 and CM3 would be replaced by moderators. SE essentially gets two shots to convince a moderator that the moderator in question needs to be removed. In the reinstatement process, CM2 would be replaced by a moderator. If CM1 and the moderator acting as CM2 both want to prevent reinstatement, the process is concluded and the request is denied. If the CM1 wants to prevent reinstatement, but the moderator acting as CM2 does not, the process goes directly to the execution phase to be decided by the current mods.

In regards to transparency, I believe both processes should be private and only involve the individuals directly relevant. That said, I think it would be helpful, and not much work, to keep moderators aware that the processes are being used and working.

In the reinstatement process immediately after CM 1 is assigned I think a message should be posted in TL stating that a reinstatement request has been received from USERNAME at SITENAME. I then think weekly updates should be posted in TL stating where in the reinstatement process the request is. Finally, when the process is concluded a post in TL should be given stating which action ended the process (i.e., previous reasons, recent behavior, irreconcilable differences, precondition rejected, non-response, reinstatement).

For the removal process, just knowing that it is being used would be helpful. In the Emergency Removal Process (ERP) I think step 3.5 should be to post in TL that a moderator has been temporarily removed under the ERP. In the Regular Investigation Process (RIP) step 2.5 should be to post in TL that a concern has been raised about a moderator and that the RIP has been initiated. In both cases, once the initial notification has been given, weekly updates stating where in the process the investigation is should be made in TL. Finally, when the process is concluded a post in TL should be given stating which action ended the process.

Finally, I think yearly (quarterly if this happens a lot) summaries should be posted about how often the processes were used and what the outcomes were. This should be done publicly on either MSE or on a blog post as well as in the TL.

Comment: I like including moderators, but I don't think people should be able to volunteer for specific cases (too much risk of advocacy), and I am concerned that in some cases what's needed is an on-site moderator, not a random one.  If a moderator was removed for reasons that are not public beyond the site, involving arbitrary other moderators increases the "splash zone", so to speak, from those actions.  Even if a removal is initiated by SE rather than users, the model from the original removal process seems sound to me.  If SE thinks a whole site has gone bad, that's a different problem.

Comment: @MonicaCellio I would really like to see moderators be involved, but I am not sure how they should be selected. The splash zone is not something I had even considered, but I would like to think that moderators can be trusted to be discrete.

Comment: I've seen cases that reached CMs but should have been (and were) resolved on-site; no need to embarrass the mod involved more broadly.  Moderators should be discrete, but also bear in mind that moderators on one site are often users on another, so you'd probably need to find mods with no involvement on the site in question to avoid that awkwardness.  It's going to feel weird to, in the future, need to send a mod message to a mod who sat in judgement over you, right?

Comment: @MonicaCellio the moderator would only be involved in the removal if CM1 found grounds for removal and then any vote for removal from a moderator standing in for either CM2 or CM3 results in removal. This also minimizes the splash zone since it only goes forward if CM1 thinks there is a case.

Comment: Oh, I missed the sequencing there.  That does make it better, yes.  We still need to avoid conflicts of interest, whether from volunteers with opinions or users of the site, but that's probably manageable.

Comment: @MonicaCellio none of this really matters because what is clear is that SE is not going to give up their total control of the removal process or their ability to block a reinstatement and they are going to keep everything hidden.

Comment: Unfortunately, yes.  Which is why going through it is dubious even if one was removed with due process, let alone the case where that didn't happen.

Answer (score 6):

In watching this for nearly month now, I'm convinced that a few factors will lead to this being a defining element of the future of online communities and moderators/moderation:

- that this has continued to be a massive corporate screw-up
- the high profile and respect the StackExchange community had up to this point
- the unassailable reputation and image of the related mod
- the conviction of those involved
- the legal and media dimensions of the situation's evolution

One of the most ideal outcomes would be a fully public-sphere 'IRL' legal case and ruling.  This would

- [break the (5th? 6th?) wall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourth_wall) between online and real-life,
- set valuable precedents, and
- be hard to neatly control with divisive bipartisan political-media

For those reasons, I expect that each involved could find themselves allied with unexpected interest-groups.

Answer (score 5):

Why two processes for removal of a moderator?

The 'Moderator Conduct Review Process' boils down to "Act first, then go through reinstation process".

If the request comes from a user/Stack Exchange employee or a moderator, the process is not the same. Why?

The starting point is the same, a mail to contact@stackexchange.com, depending on whom wrote the mail the moderator case will be evaluated with other moderators from the site or just by CMs...

That makes no sense, whomever the originating complain comes from the process should be identical.

The specific case of "issue causing immediate harm (security issue like a moderator's account appearing to be compromised, or moderator agreement violation as described above)." should just add a diamond removal immediately before proceeding to the rest of the process.

Answer (score 4):

Reinstatement process, Discovery phase, step 2.3:

> If CM1 (and the team) finds reinstatement is possible and there isn't a need to establish a precondition, they'll just proceed.

Does this mean "Proceed to reinstate" or "Proceed to the next phase"?

Comment: Based on the flowchart it seems to be: "Proceed to the next phase"

Comment: To the next phase, correct.

Answer (score 4):

I have identified a potential optimisation to the process:

`Execution phase 1.1` gives any existing <s>CM</s> moderator veto rights to reinstatement. If this veto step is carried out at the start of the process (during the CM selection/recusement of `Discovery Phase 1`) then the entire discovery phase can be skipped.

> **Execution Phase 1.1**
>
> If this consultation results in an unfavorable
> outcome (at least one mod in the current team strongly objects to
> reinstatement), the request is denied and the reasons for it will be
> stated back to PM. The process is concluded here.

Or maybe this veto right should be looked at as it seems to render a lot of the process superfluous.

Comment: The text you quoted is about objections from current mods on that site, not about CMs... It's the current site mods that have "veto rights", not CMs.

Comment: @V2Blast Thank you, I thought they were the same thing. That clears up some of my confusion. Although the point remains that they could do that step first and save a bunch of the CM's time.

Comment: Ah. Yeah, the CMs are the actual company employees, as opposed to the elected diamond moderators specific to each site on the network (e.g. Cooking.SE).

Answer (score 4):

Just a few quick remarks. I apologize if they overlap with other answers. Given that there are so many of them, it's difficult to keep the overview.

- This is too much red tape (bureaucratic). Consider simplifying the whole process.
- One way of simplifying would be to just state contracts and leave the implementation details to either be developed ad-hoc or for internal documents.
- One contract that seems to be missing would be the right of the accused (in case of a removal) to get a detailed explanation of the accusations, the evidence and the reasoning from the "judgement team" in written form. I would appreciate if that could be added.
- Instead of doing all that complicated CM1, CM2, CM3 ping-pong behavior, why not just say that always three CMs will meet and a majority of them decides. That's similar to how  the close votes review process works. That might simplify some parts of the process.

Answer (score 4):

Please include some more specific details about handling moderators who stepped down voluntarily and then wish to take up their positions again.

There was a recent case (which I do not wish to link to) wherein a moderator was semi-inactive for several years on two rather popular science sites. Apparently he would quietly handle a couple of flags or perform some other moderation-related activity which was completely invisible to the community (and did not leave any traces like comments in his recent activity page) every now and then. But there were absolutely no visible contributions from the last three years, and very few for several years before that. He played a huge role in setting up the site's policies when the sites were new, which is evident from the fact that he was the author of almost all canonical FAQ posts in about 2012. But a couple of years later, his participation suddenly shut down, and he did not mention any reason on meta or chat.

There was no evidence or reason to suspect that he was misusing his powers, and there was no reason to believe that he would return in the future and misuse the mod tools. Still, a high-rep contributor on one of the communities who had joined after the moderator had gone inactive said that he/she was somewhat concerned by the fact that someone with whom he/she had never interacted was a moderator. Concerns were raised regarding whether it is logical to have Moderator For Life positions, and some users claimed they would rather see a continuous stream of contributions or messages of some form from each moderator, just so that they can be reassured that no moderator's views had changed drastically from the position which got him/her elected.

A meta post was made asking whether the community would like this inactive-ish moderator to remain in his position. A month later, the moderator chimed in, explained how circumstances had changed in the real world and left him without the time to participate on SE, and resigned on both sites. This action was positively received and community members, moderators, and members of the SE community team thanked the moderator for his contributions.

I feel that in such cases, the community team needs to take a lot of care while re-instating the moderator. Over five years, the site's dynamics, rules, and values can change significantly, and the moderator needs to be made aware of that. While I do not believe that they should have to go through the whole process of re-election, I think that the moderator reinstatement process post should clearly state that the case of stepping down, particularly upon non-aggressive requests, is not considered trivial.

Answer (score 3):

Why is there no input from the community in the mod removal process (when there have been complaints, this does not apply to the emergency removal)? As I see it the communitie(s) that a moderator manages will have the clearest view about whether or not a moderator crossed a boundary. And they will be the people that know the moderator in question the best, as they probably deal with them on a more frequent basis. Which will help in deciding if it is a persistent problem or a having-a-bad-monday-morning one off issue. (I'm not saying that in a one off case no action should be taken here.)

There are a lot of different stack exchange sites, and each of them are unique and different. Because of this each site will have their own "unofficial" rules on top of the global CoC. A question that may be rude to ask on siteA may be completely acceptable on siteB, and vice versa. We can not expect CM's to know the ins and outs of every community, and know every moderator by heart. As there are just too many of them.

I know this issue is probably less obvious on big sites like StackOverflow that has a larger amount of mods, but on sites with only a handful (or fewer) mods I think *just* a CM's view may be insufficient, and a "Community vote" should be cast (may be as a "supplementary" vote instead of a binding one).

I also think this would help counter the defense of "The cm's reviewing me were biased", as it would be a vote cast by the entire community.

As mentioned in the comments, this may not be feasible due to privacy and confidential information, so my guess would be that the community gets to know the type of complaint. E.g "complaints about discriminating" or "Issues unbased suspensions", maybe providing additional information from the taken minutes, if this is needed.

Comment: I guess SE would say that in the interest of privacy the community can't be involved but I agree with you. There needs to be *much more* transparency.

Comment: @Script47 The privacy aspect is a good point. I suppose the community would only get to know the generic type of issue raised, and get the information about the minutes that the post itself stated *can* be released if the mods wish to do so.

Comment: A redacted version so to speak, that'd work.

Answer (score 2):

What ways can moderators, and users, protect their accounts to reduce chances of their accounts being compromised?

As far as I know 2FA isn't possible with Stack Exchange.

---

Given that there's a chance at "CM 2 agrees with CM 1's conclusion" that a compromised account could be nuked from moderator-ship. I don't want to leave my account vulnerable and find out first hand what would happen to my account if it were compromised and committed CoC violations.

Comment: While I don't believe 2FA is directly supported, certainly nothing prevents you from using, e.g., a dedicated e-mail address for SE login purposes only (I do that) to reduce the possibility of the login e-mail address being discovered; and have a very long password (mine is random and on the order of 60 characters; I don't even know myself exactly how long it is). More generally, this feels like a good question for [security.se].

Comment: @aCVn I already have pretty good password policies, like yourself. Your comment seems to say the onus is on me to not get hacked, not on Stack Exchange for implementing security measures.

Comment: @aCVn I'm guessing probably 64 characters; that seems about right for password storage.

Comment: I would say it's a shared responsibility. Stack Exchange is in a position to implement support, but it's up to users to use that support appropriately. I would hope that anyone who ends up being a moderator are able to take steps to secure their account against unauthorized access; lack of specific 2FA support on the platform certainly isn't an excuse not to do as well as one reasonably can.

Comment: @JL2210 [NIST SP800-63B](https://pages.nist.gov/800-63-3/sp800-63b.html) § 5.1.1.2 recommends allowing passwords ("memorized secrets" in NIST-speak) to be at least 64 characters long, so my standard passwords are slightly shorter. At some point there's a point of diminishing returns; a randomly generated alphanumeric password 60 characters long corresponds to log2(62^60) ~ 357 bits. There is no appreciable qualitative difference between 357 bits and, say, the 381 bits of a similar 64-character password; in both cases, it's difficult enough to crack that https://xkcd.com/792/ applies in spades.

Comment: You can use a separate OAuth provider for login, e.g. Google, who supports 2FA.

Comment: @Peilonrayz if someone bypassed the login itself or illegally accessed the user database, then that is indeed on stack exchange to implement better security. If on the other hand you use the email Peilonrayz@peilonrayz.com with the password "abcd1234" and a user guessed that password and logged in as you, then that is definitely your fault for using an incredibly bad password. Not to claim that in either case the hacker isn't ultimately at fault for any problems they maliciously cause. Neither you nor se can control the actions of a hacker in an account they don't own.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck You've added nothing to the discussion that a CVn didn't.

Answer (score 2):

**It is Time to be Incredibly Blunt Because You're Either Tuning Out the Community or Blind to the Truth of the Matter**

(Please don't take anything I say as an attack. It isn't intended to be. I'm only observing what I see going on here.)

There is external context to why people are upset with the new policies. A person was removed for what people believe was a cross between either rash stupidity.trigger finger on the part of a moderator or on the more extreme case outright malice. Of course I'm referring to Monica. They got de-modded for something about a pronoun discussion gone south. Certainly not what I'd expect to be the source of a massive community upset, but I digress. I'm going to describe the issue in a slightly different issue as a timeline of events. This is the perspective of the community as I've observed mind you. If one day it were revealed that Monica were pulling wool over all our eyes, obviously this timeline would be wrong. However, perception is worth far more than the truth when you are dealing with politics and keeping a community happy (spoiler: **they *really* aren't happy**).

1. Monica expressed dislike towards some new policy regarding pronouns.
2. A fellow moderator or community manager or someone decided they felt this was Monica expressing prejudice feelings towards LGBT and other groups desiring the new policy.
3. They requested she be removed under the grounds that people like her are simply not welcome.
4. The request got expedited and she was demodded without any chance for appeal or community input.
5. The people at stack exchange in an attempt to cover up the situation refused to provide her any information.
6. The people at stack exchange either in error or in an attempt to cover up the situation spoke to the media and gave false statements that were degrading to her image.
7. stack exchange creates new policies for removing moderators that may or may not help in future circumstances.

This is more or less what I pieced together. I'm going to now tell a fictional timeline of the B & O Railroad Company. I got that from Monopoly in case that spot on the board is named after an actual railroad. This is a fictional story.

1. Foreman on the railroad wants to be able to get more tracks built in an expedited timeline.
2. Foreman decides to contact a government official to try and get permits approved faster.
3. Government official states that it can't go any faster due to various red tape and policies.
4. Foreman bribes government official to bypass any need for inspections.
5. Company is eventually charged with corruption.
6. Company attempts to write inflammatory articles to try and discredit the government official.
7. Company is legally forced to add more anti-corruption practices and to have a monthly inspection to prevent and discourage future bribery.

Now, while obviously one situation involves way worse problems and could potentially get people killed, if we only consider the question of which situation I would be more likely to believe could have a repeat offense, I would sadly have to say stack exchange. This is of course assuming the community isn't horribly misinformed (if we are, then provide the proof that corrects that belief).

Why is this?

**Because bribery and other forms of unethical business practices can result in criminal charges and major fines, and a government will actively prevent that business from doing any further repeat offenses.**

In other words, I don't necessarily trust that foreman to not *want* to bribe someone. I trust that he was arrested and thrown in jail and that anyone thinking of doing the same will be prevented by the routine inspections.

Basically, I would find a previously corrupt and weeded-out railroad more trustworthy and safer to interact with than the stack exchange following this incident. I am very glad that I am not a moderator, nor would I ever desire to be following this.

How does this relate to stack exchange?

You have no oversight. You did something comparably *unethical* (though obviously not even remotely as egregious) or made a mistake that at the very least harmed *trust*. Nothing prevents you from repeating the same incident. There are no consequences. We can't stop you. Clearly if this was a massive mistake, you can't seem to stop yourselves either. Policies are nothing more than things you can show off to the new guy being hired and say "hey, this is what you do in your job" if you have no means by which to *punish* people for not following the polices. Us being upset is clearly not an example as many comments in this question indicate that every angry person leaving the site would have little to no impact in the grand scheme of things.

Without consequences that force you as a company to be accountable for such actions n a truly meaningful way, there is no way that any policy will ever work. It is a pacifier, and we are not infants. We do not need to be treated as such.

---

**With all of that out of the way, what can you do to improve?**

First off I propose 3 "stages" of how to remove moderators:

stage 1. Full Transparency:

All evidence and all claims made against the moderator should be released publicly. The discussion itself should also be public. If an issue of revealing personal information comes up, *and the person does not wish to divulge that information*, then the information can be censored. Ideally the reporting member or staff member should fill out a formal complaint. If that complaint is deemed worthy enough to be heard, then a formal report should be posted to a meta post (locked from being editable) and possibly locked from being commented on and a basic summary should be provided of the post. Upvotes and downvotes could also be turned off. It can be completely locked to external interference. Just make it public so people can't randomly make up claims. kthx.

This step should never be skipped, ever, period. Even in the case of an emergency, a full and comprehensive report should be posted explained exactly what happened. If it is a legal issue and must wait until after the user is demodded, do so. But be specific. If a hack was performed or a bot went rogue or a user was a pervert stalking children, give details of what hack was performed or what bot broke down or mild details on the nature of the stalking. I respect that a child being stalked obviously makes disclosure more difficult. Granted, in the case of a child predator, I expect the moderator in question to be going to jail, in which case their mod status being revoked via a bypass of the policy is whatever. To be honest, I'd expect that to be a situation of permanent network ban without appeal. No matter what, give as many details as legally possible (including direct links to specific instances of the behavior and/or chat logs) to avoid confusion either from the community or the moderator. This will make a lot more sense when I get to stage 3.

stage 2. Moderator Defense:

Following the creation of such a meta post, there should be a period of at least a week whereby the moderator is expected to answer questions and bring any other people into the conversation they wish to bring in. Furthermore, it should be expected that the moderator provide an answer post to the meta post stating precisely why they believe they should not be demodded (or that they concede and wish to step down). This should be done properly and taking the person's schedule into account. If the person has a vacation and they won't be online, then that's a reasonable thing to take into account. Assume reasonable good faith. If it will be an extended period before they can be online to discuss it, then a temporary demod would be done just to prevent lying mods from getting out of having to undergo a formal hearing. In other words, don't allow blatant abuse of the system, but try to be cordial.

stage 3. Community Vote:

No matter what the case a community vote should be taken to allow the moderator to effectively be "impeached". The vote requirement could be based on the number of people voting. I don't know if a simple > 50% majority would work. I don't know what the turnout for such a vote would be. Even if the moderator has to be removed for legal reasons, a vote should still be held.

**The only time ever period whatsoever that stages 2 and 3 should be violated is if every moderator that the sub site unanimously agree to demod the person, AND the user will be given a permanent stack exchange network ban following the demod.**

In other words it should not be *emergency* behavior that triggers a bypass of stage 2 and 3. It should be *criminal* behavior. If the behavior could actually result in the person being sued by stack exchange or going to prison for cyber crimes, then obviously the community has no say. Arguably not even stack exchange has a say. You can't prevent the government from effectively demodding someone by proxy through the method of sending them to prison.

**What are the consequences?**

There have to be some. Otherwise abuse can and will inevitably occur. It is the nature of human beings. A system has to be designed such that any one malicious or foolish person cannot cause damage in a large manner. It is why the United states has a Bill of Rights containing seemingly innocuous and obvious things we would never question and why monarchies have tended to fall out of style in the modern world.

The community managers are employees, right? I propose that the first offense of not following the policy be met with a formal write-up to go on their personnel record. After a second time do whatever you do whenever someone violates a policy twice such as the policy of not mouthing off to your boss. Treat that policy as an actual important thing and not just a general guideline for the purposes of organizing chaos. Failure to follow that policy will in every occasion result in the community being upset and angry.

I close with the reminder that every time you violate the policy and I notice, I will remember that story of the B & O Railroad Foreman and how it is performing better at avoiding repeat offenses.

Comment: Just occurred to me that I never mentioned reinstatement. For those under the old policy, it would be the same process just with the moderator first requesting that a hearing be scheduled and then a CM fielding the request. For those under the new system; however, if you were impeached by the community then you're only reinstated by entering into the next election. No need to block you from a new election. If you change your ways and the community reelects, then that would be perfectly fine in my opinion. I'd add it up there, but I don't feel like editing that monolith right now.