# List (both numbered and bulleted) CSS appears to be broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, meta

The CSS for lists across the network appears to be broken. Specifically, the following used to exist, but no longer does:

```css
ol {
    list-style-type: decimal;
}
ul {
    list-style-type: disc;
}
ul, ol {
    margin-left: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}
ul, ol, li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

This causes ordered lists:

1. thing 1
2. thing 2
3. thing 3

and unordered lists:

- thing 1
- thing 2
- thing 3

To be rendered incorrectly.

Image for posterity:

> [image]

Comment: Weird.  Is this a new bug, or has it always been like this?

Comment: @RobertHarvey I just noticed it ~10 minutes ago

Comment: Can't whatever CSS change caused this simply be rolled back for now? @RobertHarvey: Not always, it's very new.

Comment: Repro'd on Software Engineering.

Comment: Yep, it's a 'new feature' - Posts that *were* displaying correctly are now not.

Comment: Repro'd on Stack Overflow.  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/390970/102937

Comment: SE is aware; they're looking into it.

Comment: Fix is building out now

Comment: @DeanWard Appears to work now. Thanks for [tag:status-completed]-ing it!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Apologies for this, a bunch of CSS was removed because it was supposed to be dead. Turns out it wasn't; we've put back the things that were removed and things are back to normality.