# Linked section does not recognize URLs in comments when left by a moderator ♦

Tags: bug, status-deferred, linked-questions

The "Linked" posts section on the right does not recognize short links when left by a moderator.

An example from Aviation.SE is [Why is the air inside airliners so dry (low humidity)?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/71163):

The shared URLs in the comments:

`https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/17294` and
`https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/1979`

[image: only one post is there]

... are not showing under Linked on the right; only one post is there that is linked in [an answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/71167) in long format.

---

**Example 2:** a post linked [in short format in a comment on this post](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/73314/why-would-an-airliner-make-a-90-course-change#comment191620_73314), doesn't populate the linked section, nor the linked section of [the post it links to](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/12762/14897) (there should be now 2 not 1).

**Example 3:** [here](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/74235/14897).

► All of them are left by a moderator.

Update: As @Makyen has pointed out, it turns out the mod was using a script that omits `https:`. I've linked the mod here and they've edited some of those comments (so some of the examples here are no longer valid, and it's an issue indeed with protocol-relative links).

Comment: Similar to: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291236/282094 and not in: [Recent feature changes to Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/59445/282094).

Comment: @Rob: Your two short-links are showing here. Is MSE not affected?

Comment: ymb1, MSE is version:  rev 2019.10.31.35305, and Aviation.SE is version:  rev 2019.10.31.35305 (lower right corner) so both sites *ought to* have exactly the same software (and same bugs). Some fiddling with the code is [mentioned here] `meta.stackexchange.com/a/337289/282094`. Test: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/337284 - can't confirm here on MSE.

Comment: This is status by design. The moderator used protocol-relative links in the examples you provided (comment source from SE API: [1](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions-by-ids#order=desc&sort=activity&ids=73314&filter=!7qBwspMQR7dwM7FmoblpVmV6iAfWL\)RB\(O&site=aviation&run=true), [2](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions-by-ids#order=desc&sort=activity&ids=74235&filter=!7qBwspMQR7dwM7FmoblpVmV6iAfWL\)RB\(O&site=aviation&run=true)). [It was decided that protocol-relative links would not be linked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/315223/271271).

Comment: @Makyen: But when I leave short links they *do* populate the linked section, such comment in example 3.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Protocol-relative and relative URLs should be considered "Linked"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291236)

Comment: You used a fully qualified URL (i.e. including `https:`): `https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/16350/14897`. The moderator used protocol-relative links: `//aviation.stackexchange.com/q/12762` and `//aviation.stackexchange.com/q/48622` in your two examples.

Comment: @Makyen: I see!

Comment: @AdamLear: Thanks for the review, but see Makyen's comment. It now makes sense. If it is still status-by-design, feel free to close as dupe, if not, thanks for reconsidering.

Comment: @AdamLear As should be clear from the feature request I linked above, I feel that protocol-relative links should be considered "linked". It doesn't make sense to me to not have them as "linked", unless the system didn't permit users to enter such links, which isn't the case. That such links aren't considered "linked" isn't discoverable by users and is contrary to user expectations. Basically, my POV on it is: If the Markdown results in users being able to click on something and go to a post using only SE systems (i.e. no non-SE link shorterners), then the post should be considered "linked".

Comment: @Makyen I think I agree. It's fairly low priority since protocol-relative links are fairly rare, but if/when we have a chance to look into this further, it'd be worth fixing IMO.

Comment: @Makyen I feel like there should be an explicit, intentional bypass to allow linking to things without them showing in the "Linked" bar. I see some applications where that may be useful. Wikipedia has an [explicit template](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:NoBackLink) one can use for that purpose, to stop a page from appearing in backlink lists.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog In theory, I don't have a problem with some explicit syntax to prevent the post being added to the "linked" list. However, I don't think that it should be a side-effect of using a protocol-relative link. Thus, requesting such a syntax would be a feature request.