# What's the reason for a deleted question without any notification to delete its answer?

Tags: discussion, notifications, deleted-questions, deleted-answers, deleted-posts

I answered a question, but after two days the question was deleted, so its answers deleted after also without any notification to me.

I found my deleted answer in `Deleted Recent Answers` list, then I found the deleted its question.

**I expected it notify to me!**

Also, what's the reason for deleting a question by the owner?
I have spent a time and effort into answering that!

---

This is the deleted [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53304831/printing-only-the-starting-position-and-final-position-in-ros/53329107#53329107) that I'm complaining about it.

Comment: As to why that user decided to delete their question, we can't tell you that. But note that it's only possible for the OP to delete their own question if it has no answers or only one answer with no upvotes.

Comment: @jonrsharpe This answer works, maybe it's a special question and there are not many observations and upvotes, but I think it should be that if after spent a time there were no responses with upvotes then it could be to removable, and was not removable after two days.

Comment: What's "OP" mean?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/146513/248731